# Is a generic question and self-answer, and instructions to close anything close, acceptable?

Tags: discussion

I recently came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/reference-why-does-the-php-or-other-server-side-code-in-my-javascript-not-wor) when I came across a question that was closed as a duplicate.  The closed question's problem, and solution, are in fact answered in the linked question.  However, question and answer itself seems "wrong".  The OP of the linked question didn't ask about a problem he had, but rather a generic problem that others have.  He then answered and accepted his question, labeled it as reference, and instructed other SO users to close any similar questions.

**Issues**

I understand closing questions as duplicate, and I understand the reasoning behind it.  It seems "wrong" to me in this instance in the fact that the OP asked a generic question, gave an answer, and instructed others to close anything similar, which shuts down the chance for other users to earn rep on questions that are similar but not quite a duplicate.  Virtually blocking out users from earning rep removes a strong incentive to answer any questions at all.

At this point, SO has covered virtually every major topic.  It seems to me that if a question/answer/instruction set up like this is acceptable, why not shut off SO questions?  Any question that isn't close to a duplicate by now is too specific.

Sorry for the rant, the linked question just bugs me.  It seems that all the people that started when SO was young have a corner on any and all rep, and by shutting down avenues to earn rep on one-off questions SO discourages users from answering questions.

Comment: I wouldn't call this a rant. The tone is very neutral, which is very much un-rant-like. Also, didn't downvote. Also keep in mind that [voting on Meta is kind of complicated](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254108/456814).

Comment: Thanks, @Cupcake.  Wish the down-votes would explain why.

Comment: Reference questions are absolutely required in some tags like php, this has been widely discussed. As to closing quesions as duplicates, OP can recommend this, and everybody else can decide for themselves if and when it is applicable - don't see anything wrong with that. As to closing things that are not an exact duplicate, this is a grey area, but has to be decided on a per-question basis anyways. Re downvotes: on meta, they are also used to indicate disagreement.

Comment: The question you linked to is tagged [tag:php] and [tag:javascript]. Those are classic beginner tags, and very popular, so they arguably get some of [main]'s worst-quality questions. I can see how the contributors to those tags would want to create canonical answers to use as duplicate-close targets, [given the volume](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/topusers) of [duplicate-questions](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/topusers) that they must get.

Comment: `which shuts down the chance for other users to earn rep on questions that are similar but not quite a duplicate` You really think it's a good idea to allow hundreds of "Why doesn't PHP work in my Javascript" questions just for the rep it'll provide those answerers? For me that's a non-factor. See http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/

Comment: @l4mpi Nearly every programming tag and concept has something close though, so why bother allowing questions?  SO is a q&a site, not a reference site.  If people need a reference, there's always the manual.  People come here because they couldn't find answers in references elsewhere (optimistically assuming they actually looked).

Comment: @MatthewJohnson so your biggest argument against the linked question is the OP has cornered the market on rep for questions of this type by creating a general reference question?  Is there any other issues with it?

Comment: @MatthewJohnson People *should* come here because they couldn't find answers elsewhere.  In reality, many people don't do sufficient research before asking their question.  In such cases the solution is to inform them that they didn't do sufficient research, not try to farm rep answering the same duplicate questions over and over.

Comment: @DavidRobinson You're right that the duplicated questions should be closed, and we don't want to answer the same question over and over, but every question on SO has a near duplicate by now.  Why not shut off new questions and start editing and improving the existing Q&A's?

Comment: There are still interesting questions to be asked, they're just mostly drowned in a sea of debugging requests and beginner confusion. But if a question has been asked 10k times before (I think java NPE questions are closer to the 100k mark), it's effectively worthless and should be closed as a duplicate. As far as owning rep goes, if that is your main concern you should reevaluate your priorities...

Comment: @l4mpi Not just my rep, or the rep that I earn, but all users that answer questions.  Rep *is* a driving force behind answering questions for many, myself included.  Shutting down rep provides a disincentive to answer questions at all.  If nobody answers, SO doesn't seem that helpful.

Comment: @MatthewJohnson regarding reference questions and answers, sometimes the official documentation reference is unclear and confusing. [The official Git documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/) is notorious for this. In such cases, questions and answers that clarify and expand upon the official documentation can be really helpful.

Comment: @MatthewJohnson: Pointing to [the reference question you cite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/why-does-php-or-other-server-side-code-in-my-javascript-not-work) is much more helpful to the asker than writing a new answer would be. If we reward answerers for writing unhelpful answers, we get more unhelpful answers. (I guess your claim is that by bribing answers with the ability to farm rep on duplicates, we increase the odds they answer other, useful questions as well, but I don't really see that happening)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not exactly important that one be asking a question that one actually has, but rather a practical problem that *someone* may have.  Whether you know the answer to the question or not doesn't really matter, from the site's perspective.

It's important to realize that SO is here to create a repository of knowledge; high quality questions and answers that the entire programming community can benefit from finding.  For this to happen the question should be a problem that someone else is going to come across in the future.  If a question isn't a practical problem, and no one else will come across that problem in the future, then it isn't beneficial to post it.

The gamification of the site, in the form of rep, is not an end in itself.  SO is not a game that just so happens to occasionally help someone.  It's a site designed to create quality articles of knowledge and the gamification is simply a means to accomplish that end.

Creating a single reference question, with a high quality answer, rather than hundreds of slight modifications of the exact same problem with marginal quality answers, is *much* more helpful at accomplishing the site's *actual* goal.  When the gamification of the site hampers the site's true goals, it if *failing* in its purpose.

Of course, SO *hasn't* covered every topic on the subject of programming.  There are always new questions that haven't been covered before.  Yes, there is less uncovered topics every time an original question is asked.  That's *a good thing*.  It means the knowledge repository is better, and programmers are more likely to be able to find solutions to their problem *without ever needing to ask a question* in the future.  That's *amazing*.

Answer (score 2):

You know, a lot of old questions have outdated answers, or short answers that could be elaborated and improved, so it's not like "everything has already been answered 100% in the best way possible". There's still plenty of room for improvement around saturated tags, you just have to work a little harder to find where those improvements can be made.

See also: [How does a new user get started on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252234/456814).