# Refurbishing Downvotes

Tags: discussion

### Some Background

My proposal/idea is not really about how downvotes work on a technical level, or about increasing or decreasing the number of downvotes on the site, or about downvote (un)fairness. All of those have multitudinous dedicated discussions already. I'm thinking more about the way users perceive downvotes, and how that affects how they use and, to a greater extent, how they react to downvotes.

I've only been an `SO/MSO` user for under two weeks now, and I have already seen several new questions about *random* downvotes, *instant* downvotes, and/or *unfair* downvotes, as well as a long history of similar questions that were asked before I got here. If you've been active on `MSO` at all in the past weeks, I'm sure you know what I'm talking about.

### The Problem

The problem is that newer users especially, but also many not-so-new users (the `SO` veterans generally have a good grasp on the usages of downvoting, as far as I can tell), see downvotes as negative feedback, as if this were some sort of social media site. To a lot of people, **`upvote` and `downvote`** translate directly to **`thumbs up` and `thumbs down`**. What a downvote *should* - and in the minds of more experienced users, *does* - signify is, **'this post could use improvement'**.

But it doesn't really look like that, does it? I mean, an *up arrow* and a *down arrow* have a limited range of things they can stand for in this kind of setting. In an ideal world, new users would read FAQs, look at tooltips, browse for answers before they ask questions, and so on, but that just is not the case. Unfortunately, you can't say, "Well, the resources are there, the new users just aren't looking at them" and pretend you have a functional system when the new users *never look at them*. Also unfortunately, there's no way to force new users to read a manual before starting on the site. There are very few people who enjoy reading FAQs and/or manuals, and in this day and age, people are becoming more and more used to information being presented to them in more visual ways. Take a look at [Google Chrome's welcome page](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/welcome.html) for an example of what I mean.

### The Idea

Rather than having an `upvote` button, which means that **'someone finds this post useful and well-done'**, it could just be an `I find this useful and well-done` button. Maybe the symbol could be a checkmark, a heart, a star, a thumbs-up, a plus, etc. Then, instead of a `downvote` button, there could be a `This post could use improvement` button. The icon for that could be a wrench, or a hammer, or a pencil, or something like that.

The idea is just to make it clear to anybody who uses the site that *that is what those buttons mean*. That way, new users will be less-likely to straight-up complain about downvotes, and maybe they'll ask for more specific feedback if their post gets the `Could use improvement` vote. Heck, I might be going waaaay out of line here, but maybe users could have the ability to vote with *both* options, as if to say **'This post is useful, but it could use some improvement'**.

Note that I have absolutely no expectation that this will get implemented. This is not a feature request, just an idea intended to provoke thought and discussion.

**EDIT:** After only a few comments, several gaping holes in this whole concept were revealed that I don't have an immediate solution for which doesn't involve revamping the entire rep system, which I have no intention of suggesting. The point I attempted to make was that many users seem to misinterpret the significance of the up and down arrows and the number that comes with them. If those symbols were presented in a way that made it more clear to everyone - new users especially - what they actually mean, some of the hassle of "teaching" people how to properly downvote could be avoided.

### Feedback?

As always, I am interested to hear what you all think, especially you veteran users who have been around for a while.

Thanks for reading! I know that was really long (believe me, I know -__-), but I hope it was worth it. Peace!

**EDIT:** As I wrote this, I found [this post by Cupcake](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254108/downvotes-on-meta-are-confusing-do-they-really-mean-poor-post-quality-or-jus) that is somewhat similar, although his is in respect to `MSO` specifically.

Comment: It's not the buttons that people have a problem with though. It is the -3 next to their post, and the evaporating reputation.

Comment: Or we could just [do this](http://i.imgur.com/xUZvysg.png).

Comment: Remember that meta votes are not the same as non-meta votes.

Comment: @Martin Perhaps I didn't phrase that correctly, but they wouldn't see a "-3",they would see a "3 people think this post could use improvement", not in so many words.

Comment: @Qix I'm not sure how you think what I'm saying is similar to turning SO into a social media site. I believe I stated the opposite, in fact.

Comment: @Qix yes, I realize that. Like I said, this isn't a feature request. I think it's a valid idea. According to the votes, people don't agree, but I still think so.

Comment: This reminds me of teachers using Blue pen instead of Red pen to mark assignments, as Red was 'deemed' to be too upsetting to the students. I think the students would eventually find Blue to be upsetting too.

Comment: Get rid of all the disclaimers in this post, and just give us your idea and arguments. If you have to apologize for something you're presenting to strangers, you shouldn't have presented it in the first place.

Comment: @Josh Is that any better?

Comment: @dilbert That's actually not quite the same, though I agree it is somewhat similar. Red is a color that often evokes feelings of anger and danger. It's not *entirely* about how the red ink is presented in that case, it's about color theory and how humans react to different colors in general. So, people won't eventually react to blue grades the same way, because just seeing blue on graded papers is not enough to change the way humans react to blue.

Comment: Somewhat... Everything but the second clause of the last sentence of the first paragraph under "The Idea" could go, too.

Comment: @Josh Well, I edited it a bit more, but I'm happy with it as it is now. Thanks for your help. I would value your feedback on the topic as opposed to the writing itself.

Comment: My feedback on your idea is that a) the system works quite well in the current form; b) people are very familiar with like/dislike, voting up/voting down, and counts of positive/negative scores; and c) having only a "couple weeks now" of being an SO/MSO user is far too soon for you to be suggesting this radical a change in the overall site without **hard evidence** that the current system is flawed‑‑get some experience here so you're much more familiar with the site, the way it functions, and the types of questions and answers that are here over a longer span, and your opinion will change.

Comment: related: [On large communities decaying over time, being nice or mean, and Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256084/839601)

Answer (score 15):

People are already familiar with the concepts of like/dislike, approve/disapprove, plus/minus - it's a universal concept that requires no extra learning or training. They don't need a new fuzzy-and-nice-and-won't-hurt-people's-feelings system.

Really. Seriously.

Stack Overflow is not a social networking site where people are poked and warm fuzzies abound. It's a site where (at least) semi professionalism is encouraged. As a result you earn positive or negative reputation - that's in tune with the way the real world works. Ideally that earned/accumulated reputation should be useable as a metric to gauge the credibility of the answer or the author.

Changing a couple of icons and the tooltip explanations will not remove negativity. Reputation will still be won and lost (unless you are proposing to get rid of the reputation system). Haters will still be hatin'. It's also hard to judge the worthiness of a post that has 3 hearts and 2 hammers.

If you are looking to prompt people into editing or improving their posts then there is already a comment mechanism for that, along with the ability for users with sufficient reputation to execute the edits themselves (or suggest it if they don't have the numbers).

Comment: I didn't say that the arrows themselves were hurting peoples' feelings. People misinterpret what the arrows and the numbers that go with them mean. I'm just thinking that changing how that information is conveyed visually could help people actually get it, *before* they get railed by some annoyed higher-rep users when they ask about it on MSO.

Comment: Also, the idea was that the arrows don't just mean approve/disapprove. They mean more than that, and it is precisely peoples' familiarity with `the concepts of like/dislike, approve/disapprove, plus/minus` that makes new users misunderstand what is really going on when their posts get downvoted.

Answer (score 4):

As a new SO user, I've also been wondering this - personally, I find the down votes quite off-putting unless they're accompanied by a short explanation or link to what could be improved. Otherwise, I suspect people just disappear.

It'd be interesting to see some data about the votes someone's initial few questions get and their subsequent activity levels - Is there a correlation between a user's initial question being down voted and them leaving the site? How does the subsequent activity change if the question is put on hold or marked as a duplicate? This would give some insight into the usefulness of the messages in the boxes that appear when that happens.

Comment: i agree with you, i think that explanation for the down vote would very helpful for people to improve there answers.

Comment: Downvoting answers below 0 discourages people from answering at all, or encourages putting answers in comments where they can only be upvoted.

Answer (score -5):

I think another problem with the upvote/downvote is that people can do it without being forced to make a comment stating why. If someone asks a question  and gets 3 downvotes, they should have 3 comments below the question. If you get an answer with an upvote, you can no longer delete your question. So it will remain as a -3 question, with an answer deemed useful or good, and the questioner may have no idea what 3 people didn't like about it and cannot edit it to conform to the opinions of the downvoters.

Answers are different in that you can't lose the ability to delete them.

Comment: You can't delete an accepted answer. Enforcing downvote comments has been done to death, you'd just get 3 nonsense comments such as "why the downvote?" x 3

Comment: @RobertLongson "Why the downvote" is a comment you get under the current scheme, not one you would get if you forced someone to make a comment on why they were downvoting. Bur regardless, If they say "this question stinks" or something else meaningless, their comment can be flagged. I think forcing someone to comment would make them be less cavalier with their downvotes. You wouldn't see as many negative rated questions with accepted answers as you do now.

Comment: Why the downvote comes from **posters** currently, in your new scheme all **downvoters** would comment with "why the downvote?" I'm not sure why you think making moderators remove thousands of meaningless comments is a good use of their time.

Comment: It isn't really important, but I have to ask - why would a downvoter comment "why the downvote?"

Comment: To suggest that they are not a downvoter and thereby avoid the risk of revenge downvotes.

Comment: The canonical question for this is *[Encouraging people to explain downvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135)* (cross-site).