# Am I being disrespectful if I address people by their names?

Tags: discussion

Okay. So, quite a few times, I've been addressed as **Sir** by OPs, whom I've answered. Very few.

I usually comment them back with:

> Please don't call me sir! I'm not that old, just call me by my name.

I'm not native speaker of English and the language in which I speak, we have some sort of rules for addressing elder ones. That is, I can't just call anyone *very* elder to me by their name here (India). It is considered disrespectful.

Now, I usually address people with their first names, without adding *Sir* or *Madam*.

Given my age, am I being disrespectful here? If so, what should I do instead?

Comment: Interestingly, this just popped up on ELU: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/172871/what-is-the-best-way-of-conveying-respect-to-elders-in-english

Comment: @Mat very interesting indeed and what a coincidence.

Comment: Amit, indeed, that was a typo. (If I may call you Amit, Sir, I mean no disrespect :-) )

Comment: Hey, at least Mat didn't say "pooped". (Isn't English fun?)

Comment: I'll admit - it does feel surreal addressing people twice my age by their names without using honorifics like Mr. Ms. or Mdm. (as these words are called).

Comment: I personally hate to be addressed as Sir or Mr. Surname, but that's just me. It always makes me chuckle whenever I work out in South Korea, the guys I work with in the factories always address me as Mr. Pete. I've asked them countless times to drop the Mr. and just call me Pete, but they just won't do it.

Comment: "Should I call you 'Sir'?" "No, I am just Joki."

Comment: `Given my age` - I think in some ways this is the point. Your age isn't really relevant, nor the difference in age between two users, all users are "just" users. SO is a level playing field in that regard.

Comment: @Jongware, ah!, that's my surname. My name is Amit

Comment: As an older male, born and raised in the US Midwest, in face-to-face conversations I'm always a bit startled to be called "sir", except perhaps when dealing with a salesperson.  When someone, eg, says "Excuse me, sir" (vs simply "Excuse me") while passing in a narrow hall, it carries a subtle implication that I'm old and feeble and in need of special treatment as a result.

Comment: Amit, for the record **DO NOT** bother CORRECTING someone if THEY address you as Sir.  Just leave it.  Currently (2014), a good safe identifier to use on this site (for example) is something like "friend" or sometimes "man" or possibly "buddy".  (That's if you don't simply use their SO nickname - which is probably best.) So, "Cheers, buddy".  Thank mans, that's great.  Cheers man, thanks for that.  So buddy, how would I add that?  How would I add that man? Etc. ("Dude" sounds a bit silly, presently; in 50 years it will probably sound like "man" or "buddy" currently.)

Comment: @Joe sure buddy!

Comment: In South Louisiana all of the 'elders' are addressed with their honorifics + first name when allowed @TheBlueDog. Even in the office I am referred to as 'Mr. Jay' by younger members of this staff and it is always funny to me as we are peers.

Comment: In Texas: I've always used honorifics for strangers (e.g., "excuse me, sir", or "Miss?  I have a question...").  It's common to hear them used in any kind of customer service scenario, too.  I don't them much in interpersonal relationships, though, even for people much older than me (and I don't think it's expected).

Comment: @JoeBlow [Seemed relevant.](http://youtu.be/g6IQ5RuVnd0)

Comment: @JoeBlow Man or dude is not really being respectful if the person is a woman, especially in a tech environment where the culture is not always accepting of women in the same way as men.

Comment: @JoeBlow I'm not your buddy, friend. Anyway people calling me "sir", especially when they need my help, strikes me as being forcefully humble in order to get you to like them.

Comment: @HotLicks: The company I work for is based in Minneapolis, as a Brit I'm quite surprised by the over-use (?) of Sir and Ma'am, something you certainly don't hear very often in this country. Minnesotans come across (to me at least) as some of the politest people I have ever met - of course, that could just be the 'Minnesota Nice'.

Comment: @TheBlueDog -- You've obviously never gone ice fishing with them.;)  (Yeah, Minnesotans are generally (though with a lot of exceptions) "nice" and polite.  I wouldn't say they use "sir" or "ma'am" any more than in the rest of the US, but then what's it like for a fish to swim in water?)

Comment: The moment i saw the heading,I knew OP must be Indian ;) . P.S- I'm Indian too!!

Comment: This is the Internet and people often don't use their real names or even their true gender or age. Refer to anyone here as you see fit. Take my SO name for example "Squonk" - a squonk is a mythical creature that is so ugly it spends its life crying whenever it sees itself in a mirror. Trust me I don't do that and the 'nickname' Squonk is one I was given a number of years ago for reasons I won't explain. Refer to me any way you like - I don't care. Just use @Squonk at the start of any comment you make in response to any comment I make. That is the way of SO - don't assume  anything else.

Comment: AD7six's comment is right on... if you're in the United States. The trick is that Stack Overflow is global.

Comment: I see this all over the place and assume its just someone from a different culture (like you), where this is normal. Unless I'm in a position of authority (which no one except maybe the mods are on SO) I wouldn't expect the honorific, and in a online community I would never expect the honorific. I highly doubt you'll offend anyone by using their screen name (or the a portion of it, when appropriate).

Comment: Ekh, so some don't like it? ( ._.)...I used 'Sir' often, but really, I just used it because I respected them so much for the helps they gave, so I used the most respectable form that I know to address people (But English isn't my native language, so I could be very wrong). I never thought some would really mind it. But really, I think they did it not because they thought you're older, but because they respected you who has helped them ...well at least that's in my case when I call someone 'Sir'.

Comment: I prefer to be addressed as *The Supreme Shiny and Polished Great Knob of the Holy Door, Superior to Mankind in All Ways*, but you know, anything goes

Comment: @AmitJoki - Sir...err, I mean Amit, are you really 15 years old ? Man you must be a genius. When did you start programming and what do you eat ? :)

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev yeah! I'm 15 but not genius as you call. There are many out there who are more clever than me!

Comment: @AmitJoki I think if someone say sir to you it's just a sign of respect. So I would recommend to just ignore it, if you don't like it.

Answer (score 156, accepted):

The rules of address (which do indeed vary from one culture to the next) apply only when you don't have any other rules to follow. If you've never met someone, you just know that their name is "Barack Obama", it would be proper in almost all cultures to address them as "Mr. Obama" or "Sir" or some other honorific, symbolizing respect. In this example, it is obvious he is due respect, since he's in a position of power. Many (though not all cultures) require that that same level of respect be shown to people who are significantly older than you. They might be dumb as a brick, but you're still expected to show them respect in how you address them.

Right, so all of that to say stuff we already know. The important part is this: none of these rules apply anymore when you and the other person have agreed on a form of address.

If I meet Mr. Obama, and he says, "Please call me Barack," it would be *inappropriate* for me to continue calling him "Mr. Obama". Maybe not *rude*, but certainly a social [*faux pas*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faux_pas). He asked me to do something different—he overrode the traditional rules of etiquette—and I should respect his request.

How is this relevant to Stack Overflow? Well, we all choose a user name to be displayed next to our posts. In choosing that user name, we are saying that this is how we want to be addressed on Stack Overflow. It is therefore *appropriate* to address me as Cody, even if you might call me Mr. Gray if you met me in person. If I wanted to be addressed differently on Stack Overflow, I would need to choose a different user name.

Besides, since we don't actually require users to use their real names as their display names, any other rule can get rather silly. Do I say Mr. psubsee2003? Not with a straight face I don't.

Comment: @Amit, FWIW `Not with a straight face I don't` is idiomatic, and `I don't with a straight face` doesn't sound as correct. English is not my native language, but it should arguably be rolled back IMHO.

Comment: @Amit, you can call me Fred :p

Comment: This is now the top Google result for "Not with a straight face I don't."

Comment: I agree with most of this answer, but: "It is therefore appropriate to address me as Cody, even if you might call me Mr. Gray if you met me in person." -- I disagree. It is fine that it is acceptable to you, but if the only thing I know about you is that you choose Cody Gray to be your name here, I will call you Cody Gray, *not* Cody. It would not surprise me at all to see people here who use their full name as their user name, yet do object to being referred to by their first name only. Especially if their first name is not what they're usually called.

Comment: @hvd, there are other problems, such as some cultures putting their last names before their first names in full user names, and some of us subsequently addressing them by last name only, which can be the right thing to do, or can be rude without a honorary suffix (Japanese culture), or can be considered as pompous from a stranger (French culture). There is no perfect solution, everyone usually shrugs it out and moves on AFAICT.

Comment: In a RTL system @hvd's first initial is b amirite?!?!

Comment: @BoltClock Just put `This is what <span dir="rtl">hvd</span> looks like as RTL.` in an HTML page and try it. :)

Comment: Aditionally to what's polite, I got to say that there will always be exceptions for what people prefer being called, I for one use my real name here and prefer being called by my first name and am neutral to my full name, but I don't like my last name at all (Mr. Miedl *shudders*). In fact I would have changed my name to how it was years ago, if it weren't for my little (half) brother who shares the name. People got different preferences.

Comment: So if I want to be called `Sir`, then I should register the name `Sir`?

Comment: To add a slight humorous note, am I the only one who thinks of a certain book when seeing "Mr. Gray"?

Comment: @user1111929: Ah, an Oscar Wilde fan, I see.

Comment: @user1111929 I know it from the movie, yes :)

Comment: @Yakk: yes, although I think this answer (and for that matter the site as a whole presuming this answer is accurate) is based on an assumption that it's not appropriate for anyone on SO to demand to be addressed by a title/honorific. You could put "Sir" as your username and I could name my child "Duke" (although the proper style "Your Grace" might be harder to get past the registrar). Then use of those names wouldn't be *as a title* even though spelled the same.

Comment: @zx81: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_nwq6835ry8#t=4m44s

Comment: That's so ratchet! @boltclock

Comment: There's a difference between "name" and "handle".  Addressing people by @handle is fine; addressing people by their name, especially if picking out just the first name from the handle, may not be.

Comment: @hvd Well, no, you should use "CodyGray" on StackOverflow/StackExchange.  "@CodyGray" will ping the user and create a notification, "@Cody Gray" will not.  So for consistency, don't use the space.

Comment: I think it's time to change my SO name to Galactic President Superstar McAwesomeville. :-p

Comment: @izkata Using `@cod` will ping me. So will `@cody`. I don't really see the point in using the full name, it just adds unnecessary noise to comments. Similarly, I would ping the dude who commented after you as `@galactic`. The `@` comments serve a strictly utilitarian function, nothing to do with formal address. Where it matters is if, for example, I write an answer that borrows heavily from one of your contributions, and I say "With the help of Izkata's answer, I have figured out a way..." If you do that, please put a space between my first and last names. Like I've done.

Comment: And who says that Mrs. psubsee2003 isn't more appropriate..

Comment: @BoltClock If this is the top Google result in just 1 Hr 15 mins, I am wondering how quickly Google has indexed (not that I have deep knowledge of Google's indexing, just an observation).

Comment: @Parag Google indexes Stack Exchange sites *extremely* quickly. They have exactly what Google wants: high-quality content that is updated very often.

Answer (score 52):

I'll also point out that it's not necessarily correct that Sir would be appropriate for a specific poster. You really do not know the genders of posters and I, at least, at a a certain point get aggravated with having to point out that I'm not a Sir. Really "hey you" is better .. but in general I would use the screen name.

Comment: Yup, I agree putting gender in the equation makes using appropriate formal language difficult enough not to recommend it in the first place.

Comment: This! My gender does not matter, but by calling me 'Sir' you're making it a Thing.

Answer (score 34):

If someone responds to my Post or Answer or comment, they are spending their time trying to help me.

If they incorrectly guess gender, age, or title, I don't mention it.

If they misspell my name, I don't mention it.

I am thankful for the assistance I receive.

Comment: This is not normally true, in my experience. I'm called "sir" most often by someone I've helped, or am trying to.

Comment: @Ben  I agree with you completely........I would also call you "Sir" as a demonstration of respect and *because of your username,* I assume you are male.

Comment: If a user can't spell my name given that it is on display, I'm worried about their ability to program — spelling accurately for things like function and variable names is crucial.

Comment: If someone were to respond to my question addressing me as 'Sir' then I would consider the title to be sarcastic and rather hostile (though the generated username is not really conducive to honorifics).

Comment: @user3334690  I, on the other hand, would not take offense even if I was addressed as *"Madam"*

Comment: I meant that there are situations where honorifics can be offensive and that the lack of conference of tone through text is a good example

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: well, ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6141836/questions-about-catching-unix-signals#comment7133053_6143173

Comment: @ninjalj: Ooops; normally, a single name gets spell-checked for you automatically in a comment, but the second name doesn't. _I apologize for misspelling your name/handle._ I admit to being human and fallible (and to sometimes having worries about my ability to program, too).

Comment: I would never, in this context, consider an honorific rude. I do, however, generally see it as a sign of being a non-native speaker. (Although I realize this might not be 100% correct.) I know that other cultures are much more strict in using the honorific so I accept being called "sir", even if it is more formal than _I perceive_ the situation to be.

Answer (score 33):

I would like to point out that your retort: `Don't call me sir!` is not very polite, the way I read it.  The person addressing you this way didn't mean to offend you in any way and therefore does not deserve such rebuke.

If this issue is so important to you (for any reason) then you should express your *preferences* in a softer way.  Something like: "I prefer / would like to be addressed as ... / by my first name, etc.

Your real name, age, social position are irrelevant here.  All it matters that you keep this site cordial and to the point. You can change you own user id to "Your Highness"  if you like to.

So the bottom line is:  address others the way you are comfortable with, let others do the same, and do not obsess about it.

Comment: Indeed, the correct response would actually be, _Please don't call me Sir, I work for a living._

Comment: Really (about the presidents thing)?  I saw G W Bush, when he was president, rebuke a journalist for addressing him as "Sir" instead of as "Mr President".  Of course, I think he was just trying to evade the journalist's question, but that's another issue entirely.

Comment: ah! I add `Please` actually. Edited my question. I forgot "along the lines of"

Comment: *Mr. PM 77-1 was my father! Call me Crash.*

Answer (score 24):

To me (an American), the internet is such a casual place, that formal forms of address often actually come off as out of place, at a minimum, or condescending, at the worst, so I dislike the usage.

However, using a formal form of address with people you do not know is very common in many cultures, so you have to accept that no matter what you do, it will be impossible to control it given the multi-cultural reach of Stack Overflow.

Personally, I get it a lot on Meta, and I just ignore it.

Answer (score 19):

You should address people by their nickname, regardless of what it is. Use `@username` style, SO has intellisense, which will help you avoid typing. In cases when it's obvious to whom you are replying, using a pronoun `You` is okay. I consider this culture neutral, it does not matter whether OP is male or female, different age, religion etc. If you are referring to a 3rd person in a conversation, such as discussing OP's affairs with an answerer, `their/theirs` is appropriate. The above is my personal code of conduct on SO, not based on any guidelines or anything.

Having said that, be prepared to be addressed any way, people coming from a different culture or education may not know these rules (or any rules, in fact). Ignore disrespect (if you feel one), and just assume they replied politely. If it helps, try to rephrase their words as if you were a moderator, and assume this is exactly what they said. In the end, what was said does not matter, as long the problem has been solved (i.e. a question answered in this case).

Comment: That's pretty much what I do. I mostly don't use a name at all if it's obvious who is being addressed, or @username otherwise. I'm extra careful about the gender when referencing the poster. Often I will refer to the person who posted the questions as "the original poster" in conversation. Or "they/their", as you're suggesting.

Comment: _"Ignore disrespect (if you feel one), and just assume they replied politely. If it helps, try to rephrase their words as if you were a moderator, and assume this is exactly what they said. In the end, what was said does not matter, as long the problem has been solved (i.e. a question answered in this case)."_ I still think following this approach to the letter is a terrible idea. How does someone know that they're going around grossly offending or disrespecting people if their recipients don't _tell them_? What is their incentive to stop? If you have been dissed you have a right to say so.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: There are some people who consistently don't understand, regardless of how you say it. They may interpret your note as offense, or an attempt to be smart, or something like that, luring you into conversation you'd wish you never had. The above quote is my personal "universal" approach to keep your everyday life happy, including non-StackOverflow issues.

Answer (score 5):

Your answer-backs are off topic, they should be flagged and removed.

Stack Overflow is for answering programming questions, not for empty chatter on someone's hurt feelings.

Comment: Well, if that's the case most highly upvoted *comments* are jokes and mostly irrelevant to the topic. Perhaps its time to be a human than just a robot trying to answer and make SO more humane. Come out of off-topics, dupes, what have you tried etc...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23832096/php-mysqli-query-function#comment36669484_23832096

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22931976/mysql-php-performace/23195736#comment36293676_23195736

Comment: see the above links? They are off-topics as well.

Comment: @Amit Joki: You must not have seen this: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256003/on-large-communities-decaying-over-time-being-nice-or-mean-and-stack-overflow/256084#256084

Comment: and this answer should be flagged as "This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether."

Comment: @BoltClock ugh, sorry for the late reply, only saw your comment now.. The title of the question is making me not to see it :)

Answer (score 4):

The fact is in text you are often writing to a group, and it is objective and not directed at a person.

If it is not then it is implied that you are talking to the only other person in the conversation. In which case suddenly slipping their name in is in effect attempting to get their attention.

The implication is either

1. They are not paying attention
2. You are directly addressing them in a formal way making it abundantly clear it is them and only them you are addressing.

So yes, very often it is a tool of a writer to somehow diminish the target of his text.

For example, in a work email it would be strange to suddenly refer to the person by name in any place apart from at the very start unless you are setting tasks for several people - if this is not the case, you are singling out.

It is a very powerful passive aggressive tool.

Answer (score 3):

On the Internet (of old, not so much with Webcams nowadays) everyone is (for the most part) equal. That does not imply that you can speak (type) to children like they are your 'pub friends', etc.

If you are writing someone at their 'Home Email Address' or 'Work Email Address' then you would write them as though you were writing a letter (on paper, snail mail) but you would omit your and their physical address from the top (though your physical address might appear in "a signature" (an addition at the bottom of your mail, not to be confused with "your signature").

That implies that the first line of your email would be "Dear Sir" or Dear Madam". That is a safe option for your first time emailing someone at their personal/business email address.

OTOH

When writing in a Forum it is fine to call people "@Amit" or "Amit", the 'at' Symbol being used when addressing multiple people with a single reply. If there were a few people with the same name (which strangely is a rare occurrence for me) then you might want to use the last Initial or quote a few words that they said followed by three dots "..." .

Forums are an open area where all are equal (but in most (not all) Forums you need to be mindful that children may read what you type). You also need to avoid racial jokes or political statements (unless the Forum is devoted to discussing a 'trouble', disagreement' or "War" in a particular part of the World). Read the Forum Rules and get a sense of the discussions before posting.

To call someone in a Forum Sir or Madam (and especially to be incorrect in your choice) may not be polite as it immediately attempts to imply a great difference between you and them, to distance the addressor from the addressee (and to leave them wondering the purpose). If you knew they are the Oracle of Delphi that may be OK but otherwise it likely is not.

I do not address you "Hey Buddy from such and such a Country" because that would be rude.

It shows no effort to acknowledge your name (that you are a person) and implies that your Country has something to do with the conversation -- a point you made in your question by saying which Country you came from and that "we have some sort of rules" in your Country).

It is not the life-task of every Forum poster to know every Rule in every Country (especially when you call them "we have some sort of rules" (some sort ?), you can not expect everyone to know these Rules if even you do not know them).

So the Forums are less formal, and that IS "polite". Too formal and you distance yourself from the person. See how this sounds:

- @Amit: You make a good point, but there are some I so not agree with.
- Mr. Joki: You make a good point, but there are some I so not agree
  with.

See how the second sentence distances me from you and says you are wrong, while the first sentence merely says that I do not disagree with all that you have said. Perhaps a subtle difference but it would be less subtle if the second sentence were worded differently, made to sound rude.

Use of "Buddy", "Sir", or anything else that is, as-is or inverted, (IE: calling you "Buddy" or "Sir" when I am arguing (rudely) with you), certain to mean the inverse and intended as an insult or condescending.

If someone writes "Mr. Joki" it is still technically correct to do that and not polite to say they are wrong, nor wrong for you to ask that they address you by your first name. I hope that is not confusing.

Titles that are EARNED, EG: "Dr." should certainly not be left off when using their full name but could be left off when using only their first name (in a Forum setting).

OTOH, to refer to you third party, to say "that Mr. Joki guy" said this, or does that, is likely an attempt to call out your actions and present them as unacceptable to others. I would be seen as a means to distance myself from you.

To some it up:

- It is not impolite to use their first name, if someone here had the name "MadCrashEr Devil" to call him "Mr. Devil" would be confusing and maybe not polite -- it depends on the intent and context of the discussion (the purpose of the writer, which is not always clear).
- If you shorten or lengthen a name (calling you @A, or Mr. Joki) then you need to be careful (IF you want to be polite) that you do not go on to attack the person or their views in the rest of your sentence.
- To refer to you as "Mr. Joki" is likely not an insult, I'm not sure why the person did it in a Forum. On the Internet we are equals and trying to distance yourself is only correct when someone chimes in with hate, nonsense, SPAM, constant wrong info, etc.
- To ask that people call you "Amit" is not your attempt to offend us, you should not have to ask (on the Internet, in person conversations have different Rules). If the person was trying to imply that you are "Mr. Jokey" that is rude; examine the Post and see if that is what they meant. It would be an attempt to demean you and impugn your credibility.

So unless you are in a Forum that is specific to a particular Country and/or the Language used is not English then 'English Language Rules' apply. Same as for "Air Traffic Control" or any of the "Computer Programming Languages". Insistance that everyone follow the Customs of the Country of the person whom the addressor is addressing will not go over well.

When I go to a foreign language Forum and try to post a short thank-you for some useful info I read using Google-Translate (the reverse (writing) is never appreciated in a Forum) I try to ensure that I keep it short (one post, one line) and avoid a lenthgy discussion that may not translate well. I want to make certain I am thanking and not demanding or insulting.

I hope that is clearer than mud. It is quite complicated. Avoiding a differ from the norm and ensuring your comments are polite (here, and in most but not all Forums) is probably your best bet.

Lurk (long if you need to) and read (twice if you need to) to get a feel for it.

If you direct us to the Post to which you refer we (native English speakers) might be able to infer the intent of the person from their comment. They may be a small child and call everyone Sir or Madam by default, assuming everyone else is older, and you should take no offense from their comment.

On the Internet we are all equal. There is no age, race, gender, physical ability or physical disability. Still, despite being equal, you need to be mindful of our differences too. Avoid anything that could be taken the wrong way; like calling you "Sir" or "Mr. Joki" while all the other writers do not, particularly when expressing disagreement or correcting you.

Answer (score 3):

In the U.S., the cultural norm is now very informal, where in most situations use of first names is appropriate (e.g., even at large companies with many thousands of employees, it is usual and expected for low-level staff to address senior managers by first name).  Technical culture has adopted the same social norms.  The Internet as a whole has to some extent also adopted this.

Hence, in SO (and elsewhere on SE), addressing people by their handle is the norm and is not rude.

Answer (score -1):

Here we choose our user name, we are saying that this is how we want to be addressed on Stack Overflow.

Stack Overflow user name is like **code name** for programmer.  Like James bond has 007.. I have **Mr.32**

So i am Mr.32....No one is going to call me just "Sir 32" or "32"

Comment: \*changes SO handle to "Sir"\*