# How to automatically see "show X more comments" without clicking (here on Stackexchange)?

Tags: discussion, user-interface

Just discovered SE and am loving it.
Is there a way to automatically see "show X more comments" without clicking each "show X more comments" link each time?
I have gone through my account settings but am not seeing anything that controls this page / additional comment behaviour.
My goal is to be able to save the page with all of the comments fully expanded so I do not miss anything as I am using this amazing resource to learn.
How can I always have all of the comments automatically expanded out?
   Thanks in advance, 
                  Gette

Comment: I think it's by design. The system shows relevant (upvoted) comments. But the answers are more important than comments, they never get hidden, so I think the idea is to encourage users to post answers and use the comments only to ask for clearifications

Comment: [Related](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268400/is-there-a-get-query-string-to-expand-all-comments-by-default).