# Why should people use Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

**Observations:**

There are a large number of quite simple questions that people come across as hurdles to progressing their understanding, and these can be answered without too much effort (for someone who has already overcome that particular hurdle) - people do, and often there are several alternative solutions, culminating in an agreed good solution - or remaining distinct as opinions.

**Problem:**

Abuse directed to those who answer 'homework' questions. (To clarify: A homework question is often deemed one so simple it must have been asked by someone learning the ropes, either through an institution, or self-taught using free online problems to challenge themselves.)

I have no issue answering these questions, I found it useful when I taught myself to try to find good solutions to problems I either came up with, or found online with minimal support. But why has it become acceptable in any society, let alone a knowledge sharing society for an individual to impose their opinion on others using their accumulated power to have negative impact on someone else?

I appreciate many learning institutions interpret finding an answer online cheating - and within that learning institution they most likely have the resources available to provide the style of teaching that they want. However that's not the only way to learn, and not the only way to come up with simple questions, so how can we (as a community) take responsibility for the decisions of an individual who chooses to subvert an external system?

Additionally how can we ensure that those individuals who do not have the support of any recognized learning institute, can continue to learn and use the site in a positive, and meaningful manner, without being abused based purely on their experience?

(I appreciate that there are several key questions within this, but I felt they were sufficiently connected to be contained in one larger post.)

**Explanation of how this post is different to others mentioned:** Please read above, if you are still unsure, there are further details in the comments.

Comment: Related topics - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251758/why-is-stack-overflow-so-negative-of-late, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252506/question-quality-is-dropping-on-stack-overflow, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256003/on-large-communities-decaying-over-time-being-nice-or-mean-and-stack-overflow, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions. Those are quite long threads, but they will put you more closely into the context.

Comment: One question - do you see the goal of Stack Exchange (and by extension Stack Overflow), as a place to educate people? Or as a place for getting answers? Or as a repository of good quality Q&A?

Comment: @EugenePodskal - So this is merely a recent development?

Comment: @Oded - Personally I feel it can be used to educate yourself, but shouldn't be a community responsibility to provide education. Equally getting answers is key, as is the ability to discuss those answers. As I mentioned in my post, I see it as primarily a knowledge sharing site, where people with knowledge are able (should they choose) to provided it to those without.

Comment: Well, I doubt that you have already read those posts, haven't you? And I am quite a new user, so am not the best one to answer, but as I understand some problems more or less existed from the beginning. Also, change the title, because it doesn't correlate with overall gist of the question.

Comment: "Abuse" is rarely based on experience - it's on asking a bad question. In my experience, if you *care* about asking a good question, you can do so even on topics where you have little to no experience. As for homework questions - what do you make of ones which are simply a copy and paste of an assignment, with no sign of any effort at all? Do you really think *those* should be answered?

Comment: I never saw a question being closed because it was homework. I saw questions being closed because OP couldn't express a specific problem, did no research at all, simply pasted an assignment, etc, etc, etc. Nothing on SO says you can't ask about homework, but any questions should be specific, on topic, and useful to a greater community, which these types of questions often are not. The same holds true for similar "simple" questions.

Comment: @Jon Skeet - I feel that there is still capacity for different answers to be given, and an interesting discussion to come from it. If you find a question interesting, and would be equally interested in how your perceived solution to it would compare to the solutions provided by other people, then you should be entitled to answer it. The question itself is a seperate consideration, if it is appropriate, interesting, and/or relevant, then kept, else flagged for the appropriate reason, and subsequently removed.

Comment: @GuyFlavell if you think SO is for "interesting discussion", then you're wrong. SO is intended as a high-quality knowledge base of factual answers, not as a discussion forum. If a question leads to discussion, chances are it should not have been asked in the first place. If the main focus of a question is a discussion, it should definitely not be asked on SO. It might be "interesting", but that does not correlate with usefulness.

Comment: Most "homework" questions are simple - and the site, being as mature as it is, already has answers to those questions. As a community, I think that ensuring there is ONE question and multiple answers rather than multiple questions (asking the same thing) all with one answer is a much better scenario. Downvotes on these type answers are generally empassioned users cranky that folks don't make the effort to search first. I often vote to close, but rarely downvote. Having said that, I don't disagree with their downvotes. Make the effort, then we will too.

Comment: @l4mpi I find high quality solutions to problems interesting, it is one of the main reasons I got into programming. :) Discussion about why one solution is a higher quality than another is inevitable when people approach the problem from different angles. And tends to lead to a convergence of answers towards a better solution, or an acceptance that it is down to opinion.

Comment: @Fluffeh your problem here seems to be with duplicated questions, which there is already a facility in place to resolve as you pointed out, flagging the question as duplicate tends to work well. You yourself point out that multiple answers is fine, so how could someone criticise an answer in this case?

Comment: @GuyFlavell: But the purpose of SO is *not* discussion. That may be a side-effect of some questions, but if the only obvious benefit of a question *is* discussion, then I'd argue it's unsuitable for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Fluffeh In my opinion there is nothing wrong with simple questions - they should be either deduplicated or answered if there are not duplicates. [Another or nonstandard title](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/) is not a reason on its own to punish users. But the problem is with unclear questions ("I have a problem...") and those where simple search by title in Google brings an answer. They really qualify as "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful", that should be downvoted.

Comment: If I see a question that has been asked already (with good answers) I feel no remose in stricking it with my golden hammer. What I am saying is that I want all the answers under ONE question, so folks searching hit one place and find all the discussion and solutions. What I meant is that most of the questions with answers being "punished" are likely duplicates. Overzealous downvotes? Perhaps. Do they come with close (duplicate) votes? Quite likely. I think they aim to educate answer posters to perhaps cast a dupe vote rather than spam an answer for the who-knows-which time.

Comment: @JonSkeet - I'd agree. The discussion should always be a result of a difference in answers, not the question. And when this is not the case, the question can be flagged, and the OP given a chance to provide the relevant information to make the question suitable.

Comment: And that's exactly what happens - people vote to close the question as inappropriate for SO, and if enough people vote, it will be closed. The OP still has a chance to edit it and it can potentially get reopened. In other words, the system is already working as intended in my view.

Comment: @Fluffeh Blanket downvoting answers that may be relevent to multiple similar questions seems counter-productive, I would suggest merging the answers if/when a post is marked as duplicate would meet your requirements more accurately.

Comment: It's not a bad proposal - but even so, I would really prefer folks to run a few searches. The point of the downvotes on answers isn't to punish the question being asked. It is to stop folks rep-spamming answers to simple questions that should be closed as dupes in the first place. It is about educating the folks posting the answers to the way thhe community would like itself to work :) Just my thoughts anyhow.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, I agree - for flagging an inappropriate question. However this doesn't cover the topic of downvoting, or critical in comments because an individual believes the question was asked with the wrong motive. Or equivalent actions taken on answers to the question.

Comment: @Fluffeh - My understanding was that a person lost the rep they had received if a question was deleted, or more accurately if an answer was deleted. If their answer was moved onto another question, it no longer exists as an accepted answer and they would lose any rep they had gained. I don't see how downvoting to counteract someone elses rep gain is really an appropriate use of power. Rep is merely a counter which can be considered to give weight to any answer, comment, or argument they make. It is not a score, SO is not a game, people shouldn't try to win.

Comment: @gnat Either you are suggesting that all simple questions posted on SO are off-topic, or you are referencing a seperate issue.

Comment: @GuyFlavell: Do you think it's inappropriate to downvote a homework where the OP has put in no effort, and it's fundamentally off-topic too? That's a bad question and should be discouraged, IMO - and it's fine to criticise the question in comments to explain why they shouldn't have posted it.

Comment: Of course StackOverflow is a "game" to get rep and is full of cheats so much so that there is software trying to detect "sock puppets". Of course a few get through anyway.

When one very high rep poster posts an answer "no" and gets enormous up-rep for it, it rings lots of bells to me.

But no the clique that run this site do nothing.

Comment: @JonSkeet - Flagging a question (afaik) automatically downvotes it. I would agree it is always helpful to identify what was missing, or should be added, or fundementally what the justification for flagging it was. But equally how can you fundementally differentiate between a 'homework' question as set by a teacher, and a 'beginner' question as conceived by someone completely new, or defined online as part of a challenge to newbies? - The fact one of those is considered off-topic, does not hold merit, if(triangle) return offTopic; does not equate fairly to if(shape) return offTopic;... squares?

Comment: @CashCow you will find that there are always people who become enamoured with those they deem important, significant, an idol, etc. This is not restricted to popular media, so it is difficult to police it. ;) (this is unrelated to the topic originally posted - I'm sure you can make a seperate question for this.)

Comment: @GuyFlavell: If by "flagging" you mean "voting to close", then no, that doesn't downvote automatically. Note that *real* flagging is for things like spam or offensive material, and is much rarer. And if you really think we can't differentiate between homework and a genuine interest question, you haven't seen some of the homework questions I have... most of which are now deleted, of course, so I can't show you them...

Comment: @JonSkeet Surely once it's closed that is the end of it anyway - no need to downvote in the meantime. If it's just to punish people - the UK abolished negative reinforcement during rehabilitation at a prison, yet the international online community sees it as fair way to treat strangers. Just because YouTube does it, doesn't mean we can't aspire to a better approach.

Comment: @GuyFlavell: If you're arguing that downvotes should be abolished entirely, that's a whole different argument - and one where I'm pretty sure your opinion will be in the minority. Your position seems to be continually shifting though - in particular, it seems a fair way away from your original question now, which is along the lines of "I think homework questions are fine".

Comment: Downvotes are not a judgement on the person, nor are they negative reinforcement. They're a signal to **readers** that the post is not good and they might want to skip it.

Comment: @JonSkeet No, I was still debating question 1, where I ask why we accept people punishing answers to questions on the principle it goes against their opinion on what should be done. We've merely been discussing the most common example of this that I've seen. But my position holds for all questions, not just homework questions.

Comment: @Wooble - In which case they should have no bearing on the user, and merely have an impact on that post. :) I do like your concept tho.

Comment: In that case, I suggest you update your question along the lines of "I don't think people should be discouraged from posting questions that others consider bad/off-topic" - a position I strongly disagree with.

Comment: @JonSkeet I dont see how you can jump from not punishing valid answers, to allowing any questions. Perhaps it is a logical step I am not familliar with - would you mind clarifying?

Comment: Ah, so all the talk about downvoting (and closing of) *questions* has been irrelevant, and you're only interested in the downvoting of *answers*? It's been very confusing trying to follow your position, to be honest.

Comment: @JonSkeet Whilst the topic did diverge from the main points slightly, I was mostly responding to questions made of my opinion, my position has not changed from that in the main question above.

Comment: I fail to see why you can't just restrict yourself to answering *non*-homework questions. (And no, "simple" != "homework".) If you want to answer for the sake of learning about a topic yourself, you don't really need to post the answer in order to learn...

Comment: @JonSkeet Please include the concrete criteria you use to classify homework questions. Please also ensure that it could under no circumstances provide false-positives, or false negatives. Without this you are suggesting ignoring questions that may be preventing people from learning how to program. If you can I shall happily concede your point, and encourage everyone to use your criteria, in fact I would even suggest it could be used to automatically close/delete questions, or prevent them frrom being opened in the first place.

Comment: Pretending that everything is that black and white doesn't help anybody. Not everyone is going to the same conclusion, although there are some questions which I'd be astonished if anyone disagreed with, both in terms of "this is clearly a bad homework question" and conversely "this is clearly a good, non-homework question". If you never want to be downvoted for answering bad questions, you just need to be conservative about it. I don't personally downvote answers on homework questions, but I do downvote the questions themselves, and vote to close and delete them - so answers on those questions

Comment: I am yet to actually hear a counter opinion and reasoning on this discussion. It seems to be the default "counter argument" is: "No, you're wrong. What about ...?". Can we actually progress beyond this and someone give me an opposing opinion, with the reasoning they hold it?

Comment: I added an explanation as it asked. :) it was my first and only edit to the question. I have no intention of changing the original question, so that people will be able to follow the progression of a reasoned argument, and hopefully appreciate whatever conclusion it comes to.

Comment: I just noticed @JonK posted an interesting comment in relation to the third part on an answer below: *"There was a relevant meta thread not too long ago about a question that was possibly someone asking a question that could be perceived to be a "how to write malware" question - but someone else pointed out that we don't know what the intention was, they could just be a security researcher just getting started in the field. We do seem to have an "guilty until proven innocent" attitude here at the moment."*

Comment: @GuyFlavell It would be much easier to just ask a new question, make it less broad, state problem, show examples, provide your opinion and some constructive ideas. It is just like on main site, but everything is much more personal and global at the same time. And again, have your read  meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251758/…, meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252506/…, meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256003/…, meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/…? There are already a lot of existing discussions on SO voting and closing culture, so it will be difficult to start new ignoring old ones.

Comment: I downvoted your question without reading it or a single comment because your opening sentence is nauseatingly snobbish. If you actually have something important to say, I would suggest you remove it.

Comment: @minitech yet amusingly you chose to validate it. :)

Comment: @GuyFlavell: That’s the absolute stupidest kind of non-argument. BLAHBLAHBLAH ANGRY RAVINGS ABOUT PEOPLE P.S. IF YOU DISAGREE WITH ME YOU’RE JUST PROVING MY POINT!!!!1!

Comment: @minitech You didn't disagree with me. :) you merely downvoted because you felt like it without actually considering the question as a whole.. :) Surely not reading the argument is the worst start, and then not disagreeing is the worst way to continue. :) - But as amusing as this conversation is, it is in fact completely off-topic. Someone should let a mod know...

Comment: I *merely downvoted because I felt like it*. :) What a shocker. :) I should probably stop doing things because I feel like doing them. :) I’m glad you find my comments so amusing. :) However, I disagree that they’re off-topic. :) They’re pretty pointedly about your question. :) In case it wasn’t crystal clear from the start, I disagree pretty strongly with you. :) And I also find you rude and condescending. :) Anyways, to bring this back on track, you can take my suggestion or you can not take my suggestion. :) I would suggest you take my suggestion for the reasons mentioned. :)

Comment: @minitech I've read through your comments and found the opinions you offer are *'your opening sentence is nauseatingly snobbish'*, *'They’re pretty pointedly about your question'* and *'And I also find you rude and condescending'*. I'm afraid I don't agree with your second opinion, but do appreciate that Meta a place where emotional voting is appropriate, and your first opinion is a fair one. The third is merely a personal jibe and as such not one I am in a position to refute - I'm sure many agree with you, which is unfortunate as I'm just trying to maintain a balanced and fair approach.

Comment: @GuyFlavell: I can believe that, but that’s the tone you were giving off with the smiley faces. So maybe avoid those in discussion. I appreciate your edit, for what it’s worth.

Answer (score 3):

**The real answer is that the content and form of questions should be evaluated, not the perceived motive of the asker.**  It should be fine on this site to ask basic questions, whether they look like homework or not.  Having said that, voting is at each individual's discretion, so those who feel "above" homework-looking questions can vote as they choose, even if it gives a negative view of the site.

Comment: It does seem that is the case, however I am attempting to broach the topic of if people are abusing their capacity to down vote in an attempt to enforce their opinion on what people should and shouldn't respond to. Equally when comments hold no relevence to the question or answer, and are just complaints that an answer was posted, is this appropriate use of power. And who decides at what point this stops and any question on a language with publically available source becomes a "why not figure it out yourself" response...

Comment: There was a relevant meta thread not too long ago about a question that was *possibly* someone asking a question that could be perceived to be a "how to write malware" question - but someone else pointed out that we don't know what the intention was, they could just be a security researcher just getting started in the field. We do seem to have an "guilty until proven innocent" attitude here at the moment.

Comment: I don't believe it's right to help someone violate someone else's copyright; your answer, taken in that context, I don't agree with.  Homework, which is what this answer was originally written in the context of, I mostly agree on; however when it is applied to a broader scope, I don't.

Answer (score -10):

In general, what makes Stack Overflow an essential site to me as a developer is my ability to get answers to the problems that fox me as a developer.

These could be:

- The "gotcha" in some known API that doesn't do what you'd expect it to do. I remember back in my MFC programming days there were loads of them, and back then it was codeguru.com that would often provide a solution to the problem.
- Within a relatively unfamiliar development environment, finding out if there is already a library function for something I would like to do so I don't need to reinvent wheels.

For "development environment" that doesn't just mean writing programming code, it can also mean related issues like using git or svn source control systems.

That I can often already find the question asked means I get the answer I need right away. When I don't, I can ask the question and will hope to get an answer relatively soon. If it's "does a library function exist to do .." the answer is often no, as I have found.