# I am nervous about ever asking a question again, what should I do?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Yesterday I asked this question:

[Why would Xcode 6.3 beta debugger show that Swift NSData has a byte count of 190 but no properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29448953/nsurlconnection-sendasynchronousrequest-xcode-6-2-got-data-but-6-3-beta-does)

I did it badly and was criticised, which was entirely fair. I was an idiot. By the end of the process it felt like a big, pointless mess, and so I deleted the post as it seemed likely that that was going to happen anyway, and I don't want to cludge up the site with unhelpful copy. However, I found out that deleting one's own questions can get one banned, and I really need Stack Overflow at the moment. So I undeleted it and made some edits, according to the "good question" guidelines. That said, I don't know if I **did** make good edits; I now expect someone else to say I did not, and ban me. So now even asking **this** meta question is making me nervous.

In summary: I now feel like I can formulate questions well, but someone else might just disagree and I would get banned, so what should I do? And I think the original post is useless and should go, but I cannot delete it myself, so what should I do about that?

Comment: This is a perfectly reasonable question to ask on meta, but since it applies to just Stack Overflow, I migrated it to Meta Stack Overflow where you can get some help from the SO community specifically. Good luck. :)

Comment: I don't see a problem with the question...and at least you've got the wherewithal to address the quality of your questions.  I wouldn't exactly worry from *just* this one, but I'd encourage you to go back on some of your older questions and fix 'em up a bit more.

Comment: I will do that, thanks Makoto. Not right now though, am a bit busy. Somebody else sees a problem with the question though, got voted down again. I imagine I will be banned soon.

Comment: The fact that you get that nervous feeling puts you ahead of oh so many other SO users!

Comment: It never hurts to read http://stackoverflow.com/help and to look at existing questions—those that have survived long enough to be put into shape and are considered good according to the votes, but not so old that they go back to the website's beginnings. For instance you don't need to sign your comments, and you only need to see a couple of comments written by others to understand why.

Comment: Your SO question is in the process of being closed as "unclear what you are asking", FYI. Not by me, but I suspect by a few other Meta.SO users who spotted the question.

Comment: In the comments you felt attacked. This was not the intention as far as I can tell. Power users see lots of problematic questions each day. That's why they/we comment extremely succinctly. We assume and require that you take comments for their content and don't lay emotional value into them. Although this can lead to misinterpretations it kind of doubles text size and effort to insert all the usual social fluff. We comment to help you when we see that your behavior is getting in the way of receiving help.

Comment: Keep in mind that deleting a single question will not get you banned (you'll get multiple warnings and rate limits before being completely banned anyway) and you can easily counter the ban with other positive contributions like answers.

Comment: Always remember this solitary, irrefutable fact: all of this is anonymous, so who really gives a shit. No one's coming to your house, no one's calling you out at work, it's the Internet. Just ask better questions and if you mess up again, big effing deal.

Comment: @Yatrix Probably I'm old school (or another school), but I will never agree with a sentiment of "it's just the internet, behave as you please" or "Who cares, you're anonymous". This is not an alternate reality. Online or offline, anonymous or not - it matters just the same. I'll agree that it's no a big deal though, regardless of connectivity.

Comment: @Mackan If you can point out where I said it's okay to behave as you please, please do. I said to not worry if you make a mistake. People shouldn't avoid the site if they make a couple of mistakes nor should they feel bad about it. I don't care what school you come from, if you disagree with that, you're wrong.

Comment: I know what you mean, I can never bring myself to leave a comment.

Comment: Hello. As four days have passed since the last comment I feel ready to respond

Firstly, thank you

Comment: @matt I see now that "power users" simple use curt language to save time, thanks & understood.

Comment: @Makato I have been editing older questions, thanks.

Comment: @SantaClaus I will try to stop worrying about wasting other people's time, although it will be hard.

Comment: And to everyone else: thank you too. I hope not to create such a large & unnecessary storm again, that was all a bit much.

Comment: A question for StackOverflow moderators: when a person asks a question on meta, getting 126 upvotes, what's the chance of that person being banned from the site? :-) (don't mention the smiley too much, there's some serious in my question!)

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Given that I sort of led the charge in comments on your question, I feel a particular obligation to post an answer.

As it currently stands, I still think your question is in bad shape and could use some repair.  I'll come back to this at the end of this post, but first, I want to address some of the initial problems with your question.

---

First and foremost, you need to be as specific and as crystal clear as possible.  There are multiple reasons for this.

1. Being as clear as possible helps potential answerers understand the exact issue.  This helps them formulate the most helpful answer.
2. Don't include unnecessary details.  In this specific question, you're asking about an issue with Xcode 6.3, but you include as much information about Xcode 6.2 in your answer.  Importantly, in its original form, your question didn't even make it clear which results (6.3 or 6.2) you expected to be correct.
3. Don't overrely on pictures.  I like pictures.  I use them often in my answers, and on occassion, I've even asked people to include them in their question.  Sometimes a picture is worth a thousand words.  But it's important that you explain your problem as best you can in plain-text for several reasons (primary among these being search results).

But being as clear as possible needs some elaboration.  It took me several back and forth comments before you were eventually encouraged to do some more research to narrow the problem down more specifically.  Without these details, your question is unclear and unanswerable.  If you had these details from the beginning, your question may still be unanswerable (it's probably an Xcode bug--6.3 is beta after all), but it would have been far more clear and far more focused.

A good rule of thumb?  Don't post your problem as soon as you run into it.  Ever since I adopted a personal rule of 72 hours between encountering a problem and posting a question to Stack Overflow, I've pretty much only asked questions which were well-received.  If you've put 72 hours of research/sleeping on it/shower-brain-storming into the question, it should be pretty hard for it to be a bad question.

---

Now, as for your current question in its current form...

Here's the problem, it's not to the point and not specific enough.  At this point you've done enough research to narrow the problem down to something very, very specific.  If you were to write the question from scratch right now, it'd probably be a pretty good question.  But instead, you've just tried to tack those details down at the bottom of what started off as a very bad question with no where near enough detail.

I recommend rewriting your question from scratch.

What's the core problem?  **Xcode debugger does not show `NSData` properties**

Now then... what's the most minimal example to recreate this error?  Give me the *simplest* example of code that reproduces this error.  Set up your own test project.  If you convert a string to an `NSData` object using `dataWithEncoding:`, does the debugger still have a problem?

So a good question has 3 properties.

1. A very clear problem statement
2. A very clear description of the actual results and what the expected results should be
3. The **shortest** and **simplest** code snippet that will reproduce the error that potential answerers can copy into their IDE to try duplicating the problem.

Comment: shower-brainstorm...stop before you are completely dissolved....

Comment: nhgrif, thank you. You don't have any obligation, really, so the fact that you have taken so much time and effort here embarrasses me. I will stop making a fuss and, as you suggest, rewrite my quesiton from scratch after some time has passed. I am sorry for taking up so much of your time.

Comment: @TheMotherofJosephBeuys We really want good questions, and sometimes comments aren't enough to fully get the message across about what the expectations for a question are, nor how to fix a specific question (we only have a few hundred characters). That someone took the time to write this means that they believe that it can serve some good (or that nhgrif *really* likes the sound of keys clicking) - that you can write a better questions once you understand how best to utilize the Q&A site format. That you asked, got an in-depth answer, and are going to fix your question is *wonderful*.

Comment: I agree that one should be as clear as possible, but you have to be a bit careful because some pedants on SO sometimes see this as asking people to write code for you.  Similarly asking for links or literature on a topic.  So here is a tip - when you are being very very specific, make sure you include what you have tried so far and why it didn't work.  This seems to convince the pedants that you are not lazy, but say, just an idiot :)  I do this, and I prefer to be perceived as an idiot who needs help, than a lazy guy who doesn't deserve it.

Comment: @samthebest I think this is covered by my list at the bottom of the answer?

Comment: Thinking about the **most concise way** of formulating a question has helped me many times. As I'm writing a question I normally realize I don't really know what I want, so I go research some more. In this way I end up with a question that is specific, answerable, gets me what I need, and hopefully is helpful to others down the road.

Comment: @TheMother: there is no need to be embarrassed, and as other users point out, it is an excellent start that you care about the quality of your questions. I am not familiar with iOS development, but I'd say your first version was better than a good number of the questions I see every day (mostly the php tag).

Comment: @TheMotherofJosephBeuys More than the question, I found your _ad hominem_ accusation of "getting [passive-]aggressive nhgrif"egregiously inappropriate. nhgrif was _teaching_ you something important and valuable. If you can't accept that possibility, _that_ would be a reason for not asking questions on  Stack Overflow. Plus: it's crowd-sourcing. The crowd isn't always "right", but it's what we've got. If you can't take the heat, stay out of the kitchen. But now I think you _can_ take the heat. :)

Comment: @digitgopher Moreover, a lot of times, when trying to make your question more concise, you'll end up answering your question and have no need to post a question at all.  This is a good way of preventing yourself from posting a duplicate.

Comment: @TheMotherofJosephBeuys Don't worry about our time. All of us have devoted our time to make this site a better place, and helping new users such as you is by no means a waste :)

Comment: Re *"The shortest and simplest code snippet that will reproduce the error"*: [some sites have even formalised it in form of a canonical meta post](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228).

Answer (score 18):

My history is a poor mess of badly-asked questions.

I've been question-banned 3 times, and all times I was very lucky to get out of ban. The first time I bountied two of my questions (which got them a couple of upvotes, lifting me out of my ban), and the second time HoverCraft Full Of Eels very kindly gave me an upvote specifically to unban me. The third time I simply got an upvote on one of my downvoted questions, pulling me from the ban.

As long as you start to learn how to ask questions, you don't have too much worry from one or even two bad questions. If you've got 5+ 0-voted posts and more than 2 downvotes, that is the time you should start to worry, and you should start trying to improve your questions.

For example, I was about to get banned on GameDev. I then asked a single question which got 15 upvotes, removing any possibility of a ban.

As long as you are improving your questions, and your future questions are getting upvotes, then there is no need to start worrying. You will simply start getting lifted out of your ban.

If you do get question banned, I recommend you bounty one of your already-upvoted questions. That way, hopefully more people will see it, upvote it, and lift  you out of your ban. Personally, I would give you an upvote to unban you - Simply because you asked this question and are willing to try to improve.

I just checked your profile, and you are at *least* 2 downvoted posts away from a ban.

In the end - Stop worrying! You've nothing to fear, especially if you're so willing to improve that you made a post like this on meta.

Comment: And to add to this, for users like the OP who don't have enough rep to offer a bounty, you can go edit your old questions. Editing an old question bumps it and you can get an upvote that way if the revised version is good. Revising your old posts is a good thing to do periodically even if you don't have a ban. (Just don't go on a big spree and flood the front page.) http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/244864

Comment: @Radiodef Yes, but he/she should only edit questions that are upvoted, or thinks is good and are 0-voted. Stackoverflow discourages people from editing bad questions because unless it can be edited into a good question, it will simply attract more downvotes - Even if the person is trying to make it better.

Comment: @Radiodef: And also, *those edits should count*. It's fine that gives you an extra chance at getting a stray vote, but please treat it as a side-effect of making them the best they could be. You really don't want someone to wonder why those three words had to be change... yet again.

Comment: There's a couple of items of advice here I am not sure I agree with. Firstly, offering a bounty in order to lift oneself out of a ban is not specifically disallowed, but it doesn't feel in tune with the site's guidelines: bounties are specifically to get more eyeballs on a problem that is not resolved, or to reward an existing answer that deserves it. A much better way to get out of a ban is to add some high quality answers that improve the site's measure of your relationship with the community (your rep score).

Comment: My second disagreement is that no-one can tell for sure how far away a given user is from a ban, since the algorithm that determines this is not published. What gives you the impression the OP would need at least two downvotes to be banned?

Comment: @halfer I've had a lot of experience with being question banned on a lot of occasions, and I now have a fairly good idea of what it takes. I do not wish to get into an argument of opinions.

Comment: OK, well, I guess if the OP is still reading, at least I've pointed out that no-one (save the SE developers) can tell for sure. This is particularly the case since you cannot see what deleted questions, if any, a particular poster has.

Comment: The OP is still reading.

Answer (score 13):

*Caveat: this position may be viewed as controversial, and may even reflect an old way of viewing Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange that is no longer in meta favor.*

---

As a generalization - many users ask far too many questions. The rule of thumb proposed suggesting a 72-hour minimum wait between running into a problem and posting a question about it should serve in most cases to accomplish the effect of *my* rule of thumb, "find the answer to the problem before posting a question."

That probably sounds backwards. After all, what's the point of a Q&A site if you never ask questions? But Stack Overflow specifically, as well as many other Stack Exchange sites, have **so** many questions already posted that it's shockingly unlikely you'll come upon one that hasn't been at least partially asked already. And if it hasn't been answered here, the WWW is a big place; it has probably been answered somewhere.

In all my years on Stack Overflow, programming full-time for all of them, I have asked a total of two questions. One of them I could have answered myself, but I didn't want to put in the time. The other one I did answer myself and posted an answer along with the question.

Aside: The advice about not asking questions to get an answer to an active problem was actually given to me by Jon Skeet. It turned out to be good advice which has served me well.

Comment: Completely agree.  I used SO for years without even having an account.  I still have yet to ask a question, I've always been able to piece together what I need from one or more answers to existing questions. It really is hard to find a question that hasn't been asked already in some shape or form.

Comment: Fascinating to see that people held this opinion - and were positively regarded for it - over 6 years ago. Today I almost feel guilty for seeing things this way.

Comment: I still hold that opinion, fwiw.

Answer (score 3):

When I first started posting on Stack Overflow as I began to code, I felt a bit judged and it rubbed me the wrong way. But after a while, I realized the judgment was not towards my ignorance or being a newbie, but rather how the question came about and was documented. If you do not do basic research, make the question too vague/specific, or solicit subjective answers with questions that are not 100% technical in nature, it does not fit with the content vision of Stack Exchange.

Of course, some high-rep users are phenomenal while others mean well. Regardless, sometimes I really do want to seek out opinions and get people to weigh in on subjective programming matters. I would highly recommend putting those kinds of questions at [CodeRanch](http://www.coderanch.com/forums). I've found many people there are equally as smart as those on SO, but are much less formal and welcoming to newbies.

Comment: Reddit is quite good for beginner programmers too - really bad questions might get downvotes, but otherwise everything is on-topic. However, there is virtually no moderation, so users can pretty much be as abusive and unpleasant as they like (I imagine it varies by room, but that's my experience of it). There is also no mechanism to deal with a persistent level of help vampirism.

Comment: Both of these problems are solved in the Stack Exchange model. I've no experience with CodeRanch - what is their approach for dealing with these problems? If they also take the unmoderated approach, I would be surprised if it attracted as many subject experts as SE does.

Comment: I have not had any drama over at CodeRanch so I cannot really say. Their policy is "be nice" and they advertise the moderator policies. I would guess the moderators are more likely to go after trolls and nonconstructive posts than badly-formed questions. Their quality control is not as strict as SO, but I find people there to be very helpful when I have a question that does not fit on SO.

Comment: Heh, we have a ["be nice"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256003/on-large-communities-decaying-over-time-being-nice-or-mean-and-stack-overflow) policy too. Most of the occasions where someone accuses another of not-niceness, it is a result of a succinct response to a new user from a well-worn experienced user, who sees tens of dreadful questions every day (as seems to have been the case for the OP here).

Comment: haha fair enough. I have a difficult time comparing SO to CodeRanch. Apples and oranges. They both have different missions and stated purpose. SO is definitely more structured, strictly objective, and professional (hence why I go here 90% of the time) while CodeRanch tries to be lax, chill, and informal.

Comment: @ThomasN. there are many different communities around which coders gather for one reason or another. They each serve particular facets of what is desired for a given question. Sometimes this may be "finding the answer without asking again" which is what SO tries to focus on. Others are "talk about things with other coders" which forums tend to do better (it is often hard to dig out the answer to a question that you found on a forum). Asking the question appropriate to a given community is a learned skill - and it may be easier at a forum with a more lax / conversational feel to it.

Comment: Perhaps CodeRanch has not yet been hit by what is the equivalent of [Eternal September](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternal_September)(?).

Answer (score 3):

> However, I found out that deleting one's own questions can get one banned, and I really need Stack Overflow at the moment.

I think it's important to point out that asking too many bad questions or deleting them can get you *question banned*. What that means is that you won't be able to ask questions anymore, but you will still be able to browse SO as usual, you won't get banned from that.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is the wrong approach to be scared to ask questions. After all, the purpose of comments is to ask the OP for clarification, if nothing else.

The comments gave you some motivation to improve your answer, which [IMVHO](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/IMHO) is a good thing. Even if takes a dozen comments to elaborate the question to a point where it is understandable and answerable, there are at least three good things about the process:

1. It is more likely that *you* will get an answer to your question and that the question and its answers are more useful to everybody else.
2. People who read the question and the comments will learn from that how a good question should look like by means of a practical example.
3. The process of improving your question will teach you how to do it better next time, which results in better questions and (hopefully) more meaningful answers, which benefits everybody.

Of course it is an awkward process, and it prevents the commenters from doing the intended "work", but the people actually learning from their mistakes make it a rewarding one.

As a practical advise, I'd suggest reading [ESR's](http://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond) excellent essay *[How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)*. While I *try* to fulfill the requirements listed there, but [I tend to fail](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1296707/markus-w-mahlberg?tab=questions). Since I got no downvotes so far, you might want to have a look, anyway.

So, as a bottom line: Don't see downvotes or comments as something negative, but as a chance to improve your question and the chance to get your problem solved.