# User posted and deleted hateful answer

Tags: discussion, status-completed, meta, deleted-answers

A user just posted and deleted a very hateful answer to [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289398/i-am-nervous-about-ever-asking-a-question-again-what-should-i-do) within a span of 10 seconds. I saw the answer 6 seconds after it was posted, and immediately flagged it as hateful, but it had already been deleted.

I know that 10k+ users can see deleted answers, but I'm not sure if they can see ones that were deleted by the poster so soon after creation. If they can't, I may have been the only one to see that answer.

Based on the content of the answer, I'm not comfortable with simply not saying anything. I noted the display name, image, and reputation of the user when I tried to flag the answer, so I was able to quickly identify the user responsible. What should I do?

Comment: I can see it, and you have done the right thing.

Comment: Hate? Meh, sounds more like a completely failed attempt at a joke. Either way, flagging was the right thing to do.

Comment: Anyway, it's already handled: "This account is temporarily suspended for rule violations. The suspension period ends in 7 days." Whether that post was the final straw leading to that? I doubt it.

Comment: And thank you to whichever admin handled it.

Comment: I really want to see this answer...

Comment: Just out of curiosity, I can see the post got deleted by OP, then got undeleted by a diamond mod, then again deleted. I just don't get the reason behind the _undelete_ part. Anybody?

Comment: Probably so it could be deleted as spam/offensive, which means the content doesn't show up directly even to 10K users, they have to go to the revision history to see it. ("This answer was marked as spam or offensive and is therefore not shown - you can see the revision history for details.")

Answer (score 23, accepted):

10k+ users can see that post, there is no exception for self-deletions here.

That is indeed not a nice post, but they also deleted it immediately. It could have been a (badly misjudged) attempt at humour.

You can flag the *question* and in the *other* flag alert the moderators to that answer if you are really concerned here.