# Afraid of asking a question, fears -1's

Tags: discussion

So right now, I am very afraid of asking questions on Stack Overflow.

Over these past years I have seen some posted questions that are not so "to the point" and people just shoot them with -1's. And the thing is those questions looks perfectly fine to me and i don't get it.

Being a guy that just don't like -1's, what am I going to do when I have weakly defined general software related question?

I kinda prefer not to ask any questions at all, which resulted in me not asking anything in almost a year or so..

I have a question right now, sitting on the question creation page, uncommited to SO because of this, just video and path to repo, and I kinda sit here, thinking "omg, am I gonna lose points!".

Here is that question for SO:

> I have been making a circular control and i am doing fine, except that the graphics appears from upper left corner when i do the render first time.
>
> The whole thing is subclassed `UIControl`, with custom `CALayer` which do rendering of circle.
>
> Check the [video](http://www.4shared.com/video/-SpPyzrdba/control.html), i dont know how else to describe this.
>
> If you watch carefully, you'll notice that rendering of circle somehow doesnt start centered. It skews itself from the upper left corner.
>
> Just in case here is the link to the bitbucket [repo](https://MartinBergerDX@bitbucket.org/MartinBergerDX/circularcontrol.git) of this control.

Comment: How about you edit this question to include the question you are thinking about asking on SO? Then we could give feedback here where it is "safe" since you can't lose rep here.

Comment: Well, if your SO question you've got typed up is anything like this one, _please_ be sure that the word "I" is properly capitalized, and not just "i" every time you use it. It's not a huge thing, but every little bit helps. (And I had to re-read your question a few times because it was a minor distraction to me.)

Comment: Well, here's a checklist: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: *"what am i going to do when i have weakly defined general software related question?"* that's not what SO is for. It is for specific programming problems. Also, would you prefer to get shot with a -1 and have your question answered and learn from your mistake so you can move on with your life or not get -1 imaginary points and wonder for the rest of your life what the answer is?

Comment: If you have a "weakly defined" question of any sort, you probably haven't done enough research yet. SO is for *specific questions*. If you have a "general software question" of any sort, SO isn't the site for it (SO is for *programming* and programmers tools (IDEs, compilers, version control systems, etc.) questions, not "general software").

Comment: @Roombatron5000 added the original question.

Comment: @Kendra Come on Kendra, are you serious? :)

Comment: @MartinBerger Come on Martin, are _you_ serious? :/ For people with disabilities, for example, that can be Kind Of A Thing. Which is what I assumed (no basis, just jumped to that conclusion) when I read that comment. #justsayin

Comment: @satyrwilder Well, yes i am. English language is not my native language, i learned it from movies and comic books. It make no difference when i read and write `i` or `I`, and how can i possibly know what difficulties does it makes to people with disabilities? And i dont understand you really, what did you assume?

Comment: If you are afraid of any of your questions not being adequate enough, feel free to drop me an email (check my profile description) with your question to ask me if it's good enough or not, or ask for possible improvements.

Comment: @Joehot200 okay, i will. I would do that right now if i havent posted that question a minute before. You have my thanks.

Comment: "If you want to see my code, visit this link. If you want to see what it's doing, visit that link." Yeah, that's a -1.  Create a www.sscce.org that repros your issue as simply as possible. Include only relevant code in your question. Include images that show your goal and what's actually happening. That's a +1.

Answer (score 15):

This question is pretty much a duplicate of [I am nervous about ever asking a question again, what should I do?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289398/i-am-nervous-about-ever-asking-a-question-again-what-should-i-do/289404#289404). I said it there, and I'll say it here: Don't worry about -1's. They are there to learn from, not to panic about.

If you don't want -1's, make sure that:

- Your question isn't an exact duplicate of another one. Or if it is, that the other one does not have an adequate answer. It is also acceptable to ask different questions that have the same answer.
- Your question gets to the point. Don't bore people with a wall of text, but also give enough description to describe your problem. Pictures very often help with this, for example, you could draw a diagram of your expected behavior, and your current behavior.
- Don't give unnecessary details. If your issue is to do with your square being a circle instead, we don't care about your code that is playing sound.

Sometimes, [you just get lucky](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/96945/what-is-better-lots-of-small-tcp-packets-or-one-long-one). However, it emphasizes how a long question is not completely necessary - Rather, your question should be **as short as possible** while also **including all relevant details**.

If you do get some -1's, ask yourself, "why did they give this to me"? Remember that [even only just adequate questions can sometimes get upvotes](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/98615/jbullet-how-can-i-make-my-object-float-on-the-water), and that really, only a bad question is going to get downvotes.

As further example, take [this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/93360/how-can-i-get-good-enough-collision-for-entities). It is too broad, the picture is completely not relevant, and it simply drones on with lots of text.

Regarding your example question:

> I have been making a circular control and i am doing fine, except that the graphics appears from upper left corner when i do the render first time.

I've got no idea what circular control might be. But that's possibly just my ignorance.

> The whole thing is subclassed UIControl, with custom CALayer which do rendering of circle.

As I said - I am no expert in whatever you are talking about! However, this does seem like unnecessary information. I may be wrong.

> Check the video, i dont know how else to describe this.

The question should be useful without an external video. Personally, I often view StackOverflow on my phone's 2G network, and do not have the connection speed to view videos. Include your videos as a bonus, but do not get the entire question to rely on them!

> If you watch carefully, you'll notice that rendering of circle somehow doesnt start centered. It skews itself from the upper left corner.

So what is the expected behavior? I'm possibly being unobservant, but I cannot work out what is wrong with your animation - Make it more clear what the **expected** behavior is!

> Just in case here is the link to the bitbucket repo of this control:

Don't include all the code - Just include the code relevant to the positioning. This way, people will more quickly be able to de-bug your question. Also, as I said before, do not allow your question to rely on external links.

Comment: Good answer, although I'm tempted to give you a -1 for still using a 2G network...

Comment: I dont think that it is possible correctly describe the issue without video and SO has no support for videos. I was unable to take a screenshot of the rendering. What i am talking about here is an custom user interface control for iOS. Something like a slider, just circular.

Comment: @MartinBerger But I still feel like your issue has not been described. It might be clear to an expert, but you should ask yourself, if you are going to show this question to your mum, would she have at least *some* idea about what you were asking? I once made the mistake of not doing this and I got my question closed for being a duplicate of a question which was *clearly* unrelated - But only if you knew something about a certain technique in a certain library in a certain language would you understand the difference. The point is, your question needs to be clear. And it isn't.

Comment: @Joehot200 You wrote a question and worded it as an expert and that question was deleted because other members of community took it mistaken with something else?

Comment: @MartinBerger Not deleted, just closed. Someone with the power (I won't go around accusing people here) for binding votes marked my question as a duplicate. My question was about making an object face a certain direction on a single axis, versus the other question of making an object always face the camera. By the time I had got the binding vote overturned, my question was far from the top (so it doesn't get any exposure), and it had several downvotes due to it being a "duplicate". It simply emphasizes the point that you need to make your question clear to EVERYONE. Not just the experts.

Comment: @Joehot200 Ok, got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Before posting a question, make sure you have done this:

- Isolated the problem in form that it can be easily reproduced. This will help you to explain other people about the problem you're trying to solve.
- Did some research on the topic. This will also help you to spot any possible duplicate Q/A in the site or if the issue has been solved anywhere (internet is big).
- Made proof of concepts with the results obtained but still have the issue.

Apart from the suggestions stated in [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), I suggest you provide the following info is in the question:

- What you have to do.
- Provide any effort (code, configuration, etc) you've done to solve the issue. (this is easier if you have isolated the problem)
- Technologies involved to you question.
- Avoid slang, smileys and rubberish(rubbish + gibberish) in the content.
- If you're working with code, the provide any code in form of [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Last but not least, **don't worry about the downvotes**. If you get downvotes, you can ask for help to edit the question and improve it, eventually it will be upvoted (or people that downvoted may undo the vote). But basically, any rep here is just unicorn points, and they should not affect your emotional state.