# How to feel like a member of the community?

Tags: discussion

Firstly, I want to sincerely apologize if you were a victim of my offenses and hostility yesterday. For what it's worth -- that's not what I meant to do, but I can see now I was wrong. I take responsibility for that if meta will silently nod that downvoting can get out of control sometimes. ;) Ok don't break out into applause -- no a silent nod is fine :D

I would like to make Stack Overflow more of a home to me. I would love to answer questions and provide value. I don't often ask questions, but when I do, I spend days researching until I cannot go any further, so as not to be needy or lazy. I scratch many potential questions in the process and that helps me organize my thoughts too. My goal is not for people do my job. I love my job :D

I take great pride in my content, and I would love to still improve, although some leniency would be nice. ;) Actually, to be honest, I'd rather take discipline over leniency, but I haven't figured out how to make the perfect question yet. I'd like for to reach others and make researching a good experience. I am looking for ways to improve myself as a member and productively. My ideas so far include coming to meta for each question and asking to help improve them where I get stuck. I got some great advice yesterday, but I already poked the bee-hive so it was too late. I want to start over.

For veterans or anybody who has had their share of experiences overcoming social situations and gaining wisdom with social skills from the site, can you think of any advice that you'd like to share?

...aside from long-winded questions -- I'm working on that.

Thank you.

And I still need some help with a programming challenge, but some more research and testing related to the topic might help first. I'm excited because it's a good topic about a particular theory. If I do come to a solution, I still want to post the question and write an answer on what I found.

Join me in relaxing and being glad you live in a sophisticated technological world.

Comment: Start by stepping back and clearing your head. Next: stop assuming votes equate bullying. Next: start looking at the big picture and the mission of this site, where we are trying to build a repository of useful content for future visitors (not just the asker, and this incidentally makes *answerers* the most important type of user). Next: ask yourself how to maintain standards with that goal in mind with thousands upon thousands of new posts every single day.

Comment: The best piece of advice I can think of is "just move on, and don't take negative votes personally". My very first ever Meta question got -7 as well, I had no idea why and it didn't feel nice and I argued with people about it. Eventually I posted the next one (it was a feature idea that was nice in theory, but in hindsight not very viable), then the next one... the feeling of "belonging" (to the extent that it comes up in a place that is mostly about technical questions and how to best deal with them, and has very very little personal interaction!) comes automatically eventually.

Comment: Once you start grasping the overall goal of Stack Overflow and the wider context in which people operate to achieve that goal, everything else starts to make more sense. Context matters when you interact with a community.

Comment: I once wrote [something](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/20140812110219-142144287-why-stack-overflow-is-part-of-my-daily-routine) on my LinkedIn, maybe it can give you an idea.

Comment: Recommended reading over on the central Meta: [How do I participate in Meta and not die trying?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/44188)

Comment: I took your advice about stepping back and I appreciate that, Martijn. I like the mission of the site and completely agree with it. I'd even like to see a hierarchical wiki of theory, and maybe even one day we'll have an introspective OS that is built specifically to visualize it at run-time :D

Comment: I'm not sure than wanting to make stackoverflow your home is a really fair goal.. I used this site as non-registered user for years without needs to answer / ask anything. What makes me sign in was a bad python answer upvoted, I maid my account, got enough point to downvote - it wasn't against the guy, just code. I think if you just want upvotes or being loved here, you are at the wrong place. You could have great time and meet cool guys, but I'm not sure it's this point of SO. don't force it, take skills and it will come naturally.

Comment: I agree with @Arount - it's great that you want to feel like you belong here, I think that's a trait that will always benefit the community, to make it a better place for themselves and others. However, making it a goal to be liked here based off of votes isn't how it should work. I personally feel like reputation don't matter and if I could choose to hide how much reputation a user has (including myself) I would. I'd rather be 'liked' based off my positive contributions to the community and my dashingly good looks. (I may have lied about my looks)

Comment: related: [On large communities decaying over time, being nice or mean, and Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256084/839601) "Stack Overflow is not a large community..."

Comment: You're still handling this all too personally. There's no need for apologies and smiley faces. It's right there in [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour): "Ask questions, get answers, no distractions. [...] no chit chat". Just provide good content, and you belong. That's what it's all about, the end.

Comment: I agree now. I think the topic was put on hold for that reason. But, still good to apologize to the human beings behind the screens ;) principles apply to real life too!

Answer (score 15):

> For veterans or anybody who has had their share of experiences overcoming social situations and gaining wisdom with social skills from the site, can you think of any advice that you'd like to share?

I've never been what I'd call a socially inept person but something I've learned from Stack Exchange is to keep things brief, to the point and clear. It doesn't matter if it's posting a question on Stack Overflow or calling a shop to ask a question - make sure things are clear in your own mind before asking and don't assume anyone else is interested in fluff you might like to add.

Downvotes normally aren't anything personal, whenever I've had one 99% of the time when I sit back calmly I can see why I might have got one, and probably 90% of the time I can think of a way to improve whatever I posted.

Answer (score 14):

As for any community on the internet: don't assume you know everything from the start. Read in carefully, see what it's about, how it works, what the rules are.

Once you've familiarized yourself with the tone and way of working, you can carefully start posting. If you receive criticism (downvotes, comments), you may assume you've done something wrong or you may have broken some rule, but don't start flaming or panicking. You just entered, it's not your site. Just relax and figure out how to improve. Eventually you'll absorb the way of communicating and become a full part of the community.

This doesn't count for Stack Overflow alone. It's good practice for any online community, and will probably work offline too. (I wouldn't know, I don't communicate IRL ;) )