# How does Meta Stack Overflow work?

Tags: support, faq, meta

I've read in [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) that…

> Meta Stack Overflow is the part of the site where users discuss the
>   workings and policies of Stack Overflow rather than discussing
>   programming itself. It is separated from the main Q&A to reduce noise
>   there while providing a legitimate space for people to ask how and why
>   this site works the way it does. Meta is for...
>
> - ...**Stack Overflow users to communicate with each other** about Stack Overflow (asking questions about how the websites work, or about
>     policies and community decisions)
> - ...**Stack Overflow users to communicate with Stack Overflow the company** (posting bugs, suggesting improvements, or proposing new
>     features), and
> - ...**Stack Overflow the company to communicate with the communit**y (soliciting feedback on new ideas or features, or discussing policies
>     that affect the whole network)

…but that doesn't answer all of my questions.

Meta Stack Overflow appears to have different rules and user behavior from the "regular" Stack Overflow site.  How is it different?

Individual questions answered below:

- [Do I have an account here? What happens to my reputation and badges?](/a/272450)
- [What do votes mean on Meta? Why was my well-written post downvoted?](/a/259918)
- [When should posts on Meta be set to community wiki?](/a/259918)
- [Why are there posts closed as "exact duplicates" when they're not *exact* duplicates?](/a/259918)
- [Should I do anything before posting on Meta?](/a/259920)
- [What are required tags? Why do I have to include them?](/a/259919)
- [What is special about the red tags? Why can't I add or remove them from a question's tags?](/a/259970)

[Return to FAQ index](/q/251225)

Comment: Commenters: This is a *FAQ post*, which means that it'll be referenced a lot. Do not clutter the comments with chatter. Please, no thank you's, no 'meta is full of hate', etc. etc. Use comments to discuss how to improve the posts only.

Answer (score 51):

### Search first

Before you post, please use the search function. It's extremely likely that what you are going to ask has been asked/discussed *many* times before. It's probably a good idea to search [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) as well -- it contains lots of relevant material.

### Don't complain if you're treated a bit rough for posting a duplicate question

You *were* told to search first, weren't you?

### Bring your sense of humor

Meta Stack Overflow can seem to be harsh at first, but it's actually far from it. Just be polite and don't act in a trollish manner. Everyone here is here to help you.

Comment: "...and if you're about to propose that commenting be required with downvotes, here's a list of online programming puzzle sites that would be a more constructive use of your time: ..."

Comment: Not everyone has a sense of humour. Are those should be explicitly excluded? Search does not always finds what you want, so how exactly is it justified being treated "rough"? I think that the whole tone of this particular answer is not as friendly as we could manage.

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh: It's as friendly as it needs to be. Molly-coddling and hand-holding not required.

Answer (score 37):

### Voting

Like on Stack Overflow, Meta Stack Overflow allows members to vote on questions and answers. For most posts, votes reflect the perceived usefulness: well-written, well-reasoned, well-researched posts tend to get more attention and more upvotes. Highly-voted and frequently-linked posts may become part of the [community-curated FAQ](/questions/tagged/faq) or codified as part of the site’s [Help](/helpcenter) pages.

*Unlike* the normal Stack Overflow site, Meta Stack Overflow invites the community to discuss, debate and propose changes to the way the community itself behaves, as well as how the software itself works.

**On posts tagged** [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)**, voting indicates agreement or disagreement** with the proposed change in addition to usual reasons based on the quality or usefulness of the post itself. Also, on [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) posts, votes may be used to indicate agreement/disagreement with the author's standpoint.

To promote free discussion, votes have no effect on your reputation. Instead, your reputation is copied from the main site, once every hour. You can still earn badges here, separate from the main site, however.

### Closing as "duplicate"

Normally, voting to close as an exact duplicate of another post means just that: the post to be closed is an *exact* duplicate or a subset of another question. On Meta sites, however, it's not unusual for a question to be closed as a duplicate of another post that merely covers the same topic, especially if the second post is a [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) entry. This helps people find/learn about the sites' policies, which is a significant part of Meta's mission.

Comment: How to interpret a downvote on a `discussion` and `support` tags on meta? They're quite controversial and when you're genuinely asking for *support* what does voting represent? - not enough research or just someone thinking, "ehh I already know so I'll downvote" which is the impression I sometimes get.

Comment: @mehow: "Lacks research effort" usually fits that.

Comment: `On posts tagged feature-request, voting indicates agreement or disagreement`.... this is not always the case.  It is simply an additional reason for voting not the only reason

Comment: See also [Downvotes on Meta are confusing: do they *really* mean poor-post quality, or just disagreement?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254108/456814).

Answer (score 29):

### Accounts, reputation, and badges

When you have an account on Stack Overflow, you have an account on Meta, too. If your main account has a reputation of 5 or more, you get to participate here on Meta.

Voting here does not cost or earn you reputation; your Meta reputation is simply a copy of your Stack Overflow reputation (synchronised once every hour). This means that downvotes on your posts do not subtract from your reputation, and upvotes do not add to it. This site is meant for downvoting and upvoting to happen more freely.

You can still earn badges separately here; no badges are copied from Stack Overflow and you earn badges here independently based on your participation.

Note: The above reputation considerations are not true on [Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) which has its own reputation count and where votes affect reputation.

Answer (score 26):

### Required Tags

When asking a question on Meta Stack Overflow, you must include one of the following required tags. This helps classify questions according to the type of response needed.

#### [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

You've found an erroneous or unexpected behaviour in the system that needs to be fixed. Your question should include what you did to discover the bug, the steps required to reproduce the problem, the given system output, and the expected system output. If necessary to document or explain the issue, include a screenshot in your post. Liberal use of [freehand circles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/) is strongly encouraged.

#### [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)

You want to solicit opinions or best-practices on a particular topic, with the goal of reaching community consensus.

#### [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

You have an idea for a new feature to be added to the Stack Overflow engine. Your question should contain the details of your proposal, along with a justification that the new feature is needed.

#### [support](/questions/tagged/support)

You need help with the use of one of the network sites' features.

Answer (score 20):

### Moderator-only Tags

These tags can only be applied and removed by [diamond moderators](/help/site-moderators) or SE staff members. They appear in red, not the usual gray, and confer a degree of official status.

#### [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads)

Indicates that a post is an official poll for community ad selection.

#### [faq](/questions/tagged/faq)

Indicates that a question is a part of [the official Stack Overflow FAQ](/q/251225).

#### [featured](/questions/tagged/featured)

Marks a question for important meta discussions. A question with this tag can be seen on the main site, in a special sidebar, in the questions list, and when viewing individual questions.

#### [product-discovery](/questions/tagged/product-discovery)

Indicates that the post shares product or configuration change concepts during the Discovery phase. Open to receiving feedback from the Community preceding implementation.

#### [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

Indicates that a submitted issue is actually due to the existing design of the system and is not considered erroneous behaviour. In other words, "it's not a bug, it's a feature!"

#### [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Indicates that a feature request has been implemented, a bug has been fixed, or another type of request has been processed.

#### [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

Indicates that a request (usually a feature request) has been considered, but will not be implemented.

#### [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred)

Indicates that the issue will be reviewed in the future.

#### [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro)

Indicates that a reported erroneous behavior cannot be reproduced by the development team.

#### [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned)

Indicates that a feature request has been considered and received positively enough that its implementation has been placed in the development queue.

#### [status-reproduced](/questions/tagged/status-reproduced)

Indicates that the symptoms of a bug report have been reproduced/confirmed by the development team.

#### [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

Indicates that a feature request or possible solutions to a bug are set to be internally reviewed.