# How it can be possible to have 250k plus reputation but not a single gold badge?

Tags: discussion, reputation, badges

This user https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters having 250,938 (250k+) reputation and still he's don't have a (single) gold badge? How this can be possible? How rare is this?

Also this is confusing from his profile,

[image]

[image]

In first screenshot, it can be seen that the user don't have a gold badge, where in second screenshot its seen that, it has even on meta site too.

Comment: I count 44 gold badges from the visible accounts on the screenshot. Do you mean why none on this Meta? You do realize that the reputation is inherited from the parent site (Stack Overflow in this case), right?

Comment: Yes, I meant why none on this meta? But now I am cleared with that.

Comment: Yeah, if only we had [an article explaining how Meta is different](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta), where all this was explained...

Comment: It might be somewhat ironic if he gets a [reversal badge](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/57/reversal) from this question.

Comment: @PeterJ Definetly he will.

Comment: @PeterJ, Thanks for pointing for reversal badge, Martijn should definitely get it, +1.

Comment: @Oded If only we had more diamonds who could resist their urge to be condescending at every turn...

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Because *on Meta you earn separate badges*. Reputation, however, is [shared between the main site and the child Meta](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta). I simply haven't earned any gold badges on Meta yet, it's still early days, Meta Stack Overflow [has not been around all that long](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/mso-mse-split/info).

I do have a few on Stack Overflow itself, where my 251k reputation comes from.

Note that [Meta Stack **Exchange**](http://meta.stackexchange.com) is a **separate** site, not to be confused with Meta Stack *Overflow*. That site is a 'regular' Stack Exchange site; you get reputation *and* badges there; I indeed have a few gold badges there too.

**Update**: Ironically enough, this answer has now earned me my [first Meta.SO golden badge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/57/reversal?userid=100297).

Comment: You slacker ...

Comment: @Bart, he's not a slacker, see his last question and answer, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/259917/how-does-meta-stack-overflow-work/259918#259918

Comment: @Hemang - this is an attempt at humor. Between friends, so to speak.

Comment: I see a gold badge in someone's future. And since I upvoted, I expect an invite to the party

Comment: @Hemang That comment is a statement which is obviously false, it should be read as ironic; very much so. `I flagged it as rude or offensive` that's actually quite amusing =) (no need to feel bad about it though)

Comment: @AD7six, I don't then. I removed my comment "which feels me bad!" :)

Comment: No worries @Hemang. ;)

Comment: @Hemang: Bart and I go back a ways on Meta, don't worry. Let's just say he's jealous... ;-)

Comment: @codeMagic: Party in the [Python chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python), be there or be.. absent.

Comment: */me polishes his 5 Meta gold stars .... ooh, they're chocolate*

Comment: The irony... oh the sweet irony.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, now its actually party time! Finally you got a gold badge on meta too. :) ;) ***cheers***

Comment: @Hemang: cute arrow, but that doesn't work on all platforms (I use the iOS app, for example). As a general rule of thumb: when someone rolls back your edit *don't apply it again*.

Answer (score 9):

Martijn is a very active Meta user - however most of that activity was prior to the *proper* meta.so and global meta split. You'll see that Martijn has 16 gold badges on the global meta (including a gold in the [support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/support) tag). However, once the split occurred, those badges don't get carried over to the SO meta (the yearling badges did, but nothing else - so it's a kind of start the badge hunt again). I don't expect it'll take him long to get some gold on the SO meta though :)