# This tag has been [pop]ped off the stack

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

*This tag has been burninated. Please do not recreate it. If you need advice on which tag to use, see the answer below. If you see this tag reappearing, it may need to be blacklisted.*

---

The [pop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pop) tag is bit of a mess right now.

Is it even useful, or should we burn it?

Some apply it, as the wiki describes, to questions about the `pop` function of stack-like data structures.

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19696892/java-wont-let-me-use-the-pop-method
- [how to pop multiple list at a time in Redis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23757615/how-to-pop-multiple-list-at-a-time-in-redis)
- [My uinavigationbar doesn't display the name of the right uinavigationcontroller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14811696/my-uinavigationbar-doesnt-display-the-name-of-the-right-uinavigationcontroller) (I am popping to the desired viewcontroller...)

The name of the data structure ([stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stack), [redis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/redis), [uinavigationcontroller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uinavigationcontroller)) is probably more relevant for attracting expert help for your question.

Should we just remove these?

What is the general feeling about devoting a tag to a relatively simple operation on an abstract data type?

Some use it to discuss email and the Post Office Protocol.

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13484056/cant-connect-to-imap-gmail-with-php
- [synchronising folders in thunderbird 14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13045390/synchronising-folders-in-thunderbird-14)
- [Dictionary of email server settings for different companies and sites?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19892465/dictionary-of-email-server-settings-for-different-companies-and-sites)

We already have a [pop3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pop3) tag for email questions. Should we swap the tags over in this case?

Some use it to discuss UI pop-up behavior.

- [HTML pop up on click within WordPress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22365487/html-pop-up-on-click-within-wordpress)
- [submit a form data with in a pop up box and display result with in that popup box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22352287/submit-a-form-data-with-in-a-pop-up-box-and-display-result-with-in-that-popup-bo)
- [jQuery pop dropboxes won't toggle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6209493/jquery-pop-dropboxes-wont-toggle)

We already have a [popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/popup) tag for this. Should we swap them over?

Someone has even used it to coin a new acronym for procedurally oriented programming.

- [Practical Explanation : Can anyone Explain the difference between POPS and OOPS with Example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24360230/practical-explanation-can-anyone-explain-the-difference-between-pops-and-oops)

It's a wee shame this one hasn't caught on; "pop" and "oop" are more fun to say than "programming"...

Comment: It doesn't seem useful to me at all.  If we can remove all of the current instances (except perhaps the ones associated with a stack), any new instances should probably be synonymized to [stack].

Comment: Pop it. Certainly.

Comment: There can be a variety of issues with these data structures you listed. Specifying that the question is about their `pop` method helps with narrowing down the topic.

Comment: Yes to all of the "Should we..." questions.

Comment: @Bergi My understanding is tags exist to help experts find questions they can answer. Who is an expert on just popping? There are experts on stacks and other structures, so those tags are more useful. If the pop method is the problem, say so in the title.

Comment: @ZAD-Man Why yes to *all*  "Should we..." questions?

Comment: Another possible usage that might not have emerged yet is in questions referring to Facebook Pop, the animation framework for iOS.

Comment: I've updated the [tag:pop] wiki to discourage its use, recommending [tag:stack] and [tag:pop3].  (Someone should probably do the same for [tag:push].)  I've also been through questions tagged with [tag:pop] that discuss mail and replaced [tag:pop] with [tag:pop3] or removed it (and done other clean-up as seemed appropriate, most of the time).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I'm doing the same whenever I find a spare minute. I created a new [popfax-api](http://stackoverflow.com/questions]/tagged/pop) tag to replace a question tagged [pop], [fax], and [api]. There are a few other questions about the Popfax API on the site, so it seems worthwhile to tag them together.

Comment: @nicael Because I agree with removing the `pop` tags, with swapping to the `pop3` tags, and with swapping to the `popup` tags.

Comment: For the record, this tag is [still being used](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27952058/revisions) on new questions, so the wiki isn't working.  Can we get on with the burnination, please?

Comment: Stats at the start of featuring: Q: +29/-2. A1 (Saying yes) +2/0. A2 (Saying yes) +3/0.

Comment: Stats at the end of featuring: Q: +90/-5. A1 (Saying yes) +71/-1. A2 (Saying yes) +26/-5. A3 (Saying No) +4/-17 A4 (Saying rename) 0/-13. The community has voted in favor of burnination.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[pop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pop) has been *burninated*.

[image: trogdor]

Thanks to everyone who participated.

## Observations/Retag Guidance:

- Stack-related questions should be tagged with [stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stack).
- Assembly language stack-pointer question can be tagged with [callstack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/callstack), although basic usage of push and pop are pretty fundamental and often don't really warrant leaving anything other than `[assembly] [x86]` for example.   (asm questions are sometimes missing a tag for the ISA, especially when it's [x86](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/x86), so fix that while you're at it.)  Probably also remove the [push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/push) tag if you find it.
- POP3-related questions should be tagged as [pop3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pop3)
- Procedurally Oriented Programming questions should be tagged as [procedural-programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/procedural-programming)..
- Questions related to Facebook Pop, the animation framework for iOS, should be tagged as [facebook-pop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-pop).
- Use [popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/popup) for questions related to pop-up.

## Progress:

The [pop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pop) tag is in the process of being burninated. You can help out by reviewing the questions with this tag, and...

- **editing** questions (to improve the question *and* remove the tag),
- **flagging/closing** questions that are duplicates/off-topic/unclear/too broad/opinion-based,
- filtering on this tag in the [Close Vote Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/?filter-tags=pop),
- **voting** on questions with this tag,
- voting to **delete** the questions with this tag (after they have been closed, and only if the entire Q&A contains nothing of value). However, keep in mind that at the end of the burnination process all closed questions containing this tag will be deleted automatically. Thus, there's rarely a need to vote to delete these questions.

Here are some quick links to get you started:

- [Open](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpop%5D+closed%3Ano)
- [Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpop%5D+closed%3Ayes)
- [Unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpop%5D+answers%3A0+closed%3Ano)
- [No Accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpop%5D+hasaccepted%3A0+closed%3Ano)

## [Track progress of the burnination!](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198117)

[image]

[Dashboard for progress](https://rodgort.sobotics.org/progress?metaQuestionId=261320)

## Remember that burnination is a *clean-up* effort!

#### Salvage whatever possible by editing and re-tagging.

We don't want to destroy value, so salvaging a post should be your first priority. If a question can be saved, please edit it. Your edit should improve *all* problems with the question *and* remove the [pop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pop) tag, possibly replacing it with another tag, as described above in "Observations/Retag Guidance".

#### Unsalvageable questions should just be flagged/voted for closure. They don't need to be retagged.

If the question is not appropriate for this site, then don't worry about removing the [pop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pop) tag — just flag/vote to close the question.

#### Do not downvote questions in order to trigger roomba

At the end of the burnination process, all questions which still have the [pop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pop) tag should have been closed. These will be mass-deleted, which will remove the tag from the system automatically, with minimal disruption.

#### Ask for help if you need it.

If you have any questions about specific questions you come across, or the process in general, please feel free to leave a comment on this post. You can also drop into the [SOCVR chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570) for real-time advice and discussion.

Comment: There is a `pop` function in Python list. I think these questions should be tagged [tag:list], similar to questions about stack.

Comment: There is also [UINavigationController.popViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621886-popviewcontroller) function in UIKit in iOS, also [popToRootViewControllerAnimated](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621855-poptorootviewcontrolleranimated). I saw some questions about it tagged with [tag:pop]. These should be tagged with [tag:uinavigationcontroller] or [tag:uikit] instead.

Comment: For [tag:stack] questions, should we also remove [tag:push] tag or not? There is a [separate request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265796/is-push-really-only-for-git-or-correct-tag-to-use-for-push-services)

Comment: @VadimKotov, feel free to update the post with your observations! and yes, it'd be really great if you could clean up the other tags that are present on the post as well. Thanks for that.

Comment: There's several languages that in some or another way have a pop function related to lists. In addition to `list`, also note some languages use `arrays` or `set`s instead.

Answer (score 81):

My suggestion would be to get rid of [pop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pop) and re-tag questions with more specific options:

- **Stack-related questions** should be tagged as [stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stack). This general tag makes more sense to me than distinguishing between push/pop/peek.
- **POP3-related questions** should be tagged as [pop3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pop3). This seems unambiguous enough to me, unless we suddenly need to refer to the Patriarch of Rome in an unnecessarily 1337 way.
- **Procedurally Oriented Programming questions** should be tagged as [procedural-programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/procedural-programming) or similar. I'm not sure that it needs a tag at all, to be honest, but if we already have [oop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oop) then we should probably have this too.
- **Facebook Pop** (the animation framework for iOS mentioned by Cezar in the comments) should be tagged as [facebook-pop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-pop).
- For pop-up questions, we have [popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/popup).

Comment: All but [tag:popup] and [tag:pop-up] in your last paragraph are gone. And those should be merged by mod-fiat.

Comment: Regarding stack-related questions, there may very well be architectures that name their instructions some flavour of "pop". We might want to separate CPU stacks from the abstract data type "stack". Questions regarding pop instructions on CPU level should rather be re-tagged with the relevant CPU architecture +  the [tag:assembly] tag.

Comment: Maybe in the future, they can invent a name spacing convention for tags. "stack:pop"

Answer (score 22):

Does it refer to popping something off of a stack?  POP3 protocol?  What does it even mean?

Comment: For the ones that don't understand the subtleties of this post: let it burn.

Answer (score -15):

`pop` is a dedicated instruction in many architectures. What do you suggest we replace it with in that case?

For example, a possible question would be about someone using `pop` immediately after the start of a function in x86 assembly and getting a return address instead of the first argument.
An answer to that would be to first `pop` into a temporary register, `pop` all your arguments, and then `push` the temporary register to get the correct return address.

Here's a question using the tag correctly: [Can I pop from the middle of a stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42991537/can-i-pop-from-the-middle-of-a-stack)

In this case, the tag correctly and accurately describes the question, and provides relevant details.

Comment: How about replacing it with nothing? When do you suggest that is needed that the x86 tag isn't enough (as noted on other comment, other may implement stack based operations with other names)? BTW, on your specific example, would the question be worse of if it didn't have the tag?

Comment: Yeah the fact a question is about a particular architecture's assembly language is probably enough detail. Additionally, if it's really relevant, `stack` combined with `x86` is enough.

Comment: This is a non-example, as the question is off-topic, as it is opinion based, by its very nature. It asks why something is bad, which could lead to dozens of (different) answers.

Comment: @Luuklag Huh? Can you explain further?

Comment: @Luuklag I don't see that question as opinion-based. It ultimately asks what is wrong with a seemingly simpler way of doing things, which can be answered objectively, as the existing answers illustrate.

Comment: I fixed the tags on that question.  For asm, [tag:callstack] exists separate from stack data structures.  (So does [tag:stack-pointer], but I don't think we need yet another tag, it should maybe be a synonym for callstack).  Anyway, reading a dword from somewhere above ESP and then restoring ESP isn't a pop operation at all  And the danger comes from moving ESP upwards, not from the `pop` itself.  Thus [tag:abi] and [tag:red-zone] are appropriate (because of the *lack* of a red-zone in any 32-bit x86 ABI that would make this safe).

Comment: @duplode: you recently retagged several asm `pop` questions.  If you're doing any more later, please have a look at what tags are left and make sure it includes an ISA; some posters forget the existence of non-x86 assembly and don't tag [tag:x86] or [tag:x86-64].  Also IMO we should be changing `[stack]` to `[callstack]` for asm questions, unless they're about a stack data structure.  Or removing it when it's a pretty basic question about how the ISA works at all.  (I updated [the community wiki answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/388752/224132) with this guidance for asm.)

Comment: @PeterCordes All [assembly] + [pop] questions have been retagged, and you have caught all of the ISA-less ones. I guess I should have had a look at the [assembly] excerpt before handling those. Replacing [stack] on those questions did cross my mind, though I didn't risk attempting it then. Changing it [callstack] as you describe does makes sense.

Answer (score -17):

Change `pop` to `pop-function` (or `pop-operation`).

And be harder in the restriction of its use, and add a detailed description of how it should & should not be used.

Example description:

**`[Pop-function]`**

```
For questions about the pop-function
in programming languages, usually 
used for poping a value of a stack.
```

When the tag is named like this, new members will start to write:

`pop` and then see the suggestion: `pop-function` and should chose that tag,

especially if the tag has a good description.

Comment: Ok, what's wrong with this suggestion?

Comment: The other answer https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284335/578411 from 2015 already offers to replace pop with stack where appropriate. We tend to not have a tag for every method or function that exists, so even if you call it pop-function it adds not much to the question that can't be obtained from simply searching for it. I doubt many experts would want to watch a pop-function tag.

Comment: I don't think `pop-function` is valuable enough as a separate tag. In 99% of the cases you can use the tag `stack` instead, and for those few where this is not appropriate, you can find a more suitable tag.

Comment: @SebastianNorr Please keep in mind voting is [a bit different on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/259917/how-does-meta-stack-overflow-work/259918#259918) - downvotes often indicate plain disagreement with the opinion presented in the post, and not relate to the post's factual correctness or quality.