# Use pop tag for Protocol oriented programming

Tags: discussion, tags

I recently asked a question that has a lot to do with protocol-oriented-programming, a topic which I heard first about from Apple's WWDC session [Protocol-Oriented Programming in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=408). With the rate that Apple is pushing [swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift) (43,685 questions at the time of writing) and the fact that Swift is going open source, I can see Pop being referred a lot.

*Protocol-oriented-programming* is too long for a tag name. I would like feedback on repurposing the [pop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pop) for Protocol-oriented-programming.

My questions:

- Is this a good idea? Do others think Protocol-oriented programming needs a tag?
- Should a new tag be created? Or should [pop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pop) be used?
- Some questions in the pop tag are about about conceptual pop animations of going back. I do not know for certain whether these should be dissociated with the tag or a new tag should be created for them.

The current description says:

> Please don't use this tag; it doesn't add value to the question. If you must use it, use it only when the question is about stacks. You should, however, use just the stack tag instead.
>
> For the Post Office Protocol, POP, use [pop3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pop3).

TODO before this happens:

- The pop tag needs to be burnated (should I tag this burnate-request?). I have done some of this work already
- The Tag Wiki must be updated

Comment: Who actually reads those descriptions? Whatever you want it to mean, it **will** be used for [stack](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31412905/2564301), [email](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26885509/2564301), and [assembler](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26026174/2564301) questions *anyway*.

Comment: No, you shouldn'ttake that tag. As Jongware says, it would be an exercise in futility anyway.

Comment: I understand your point, but there are only ~300 questions in the tag now. It seems (to me at least) that the tag description is working so far as reducing the amount of questions using the tag.

Comment: As a side-note, what's the difference between a swift protocol and a Java/C# interface resp. C++ abstract class?

Comment: Multiple inheritance without additional state. Providing default implementations for any other protocol (3rd party included) without subclassing. http://www.raywenderlich.com/109156/introducing-protocol-oriented-programming-in-swift-2

Comment: And how does that **differ** from Java/C# interfaces, or what can be achieved with corresponding C++ abstract classes? Buzz-words don't count.

Comment: Related - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261320/the-pop-tag-is-in-the-process-of-being-burninated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I say that we leave [pop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pop) be.

*If* we need a protocol-oriented-programming, I say it gets its own tag.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Do you have any suggestions for the tag name, if not pop?

Comment: I don't have any names for it right now.  Could we wait until there are a lot of questions asking before we know what to call it?

Comment: I asked a relevant question today and had no idea how to tag it (hence this post). Waiting for more posts in valid but I would like some tag (even if it is not perfect)

Comment: protocol oriented programming is getting more and more traction. It is new concept that changes how we think about design, there will be a lot of questions related to it. I think we should introduce a tag for it sooner rather than later. "protocol-oriented-programming" might do for now, but I am for using "pop" instead since it's pretty much crap at the moment