# What should you do if someone starts upvoting your posts as in gratitude?

Tags: discussion, reputation, voting, serial-voting

I'm sure this seems a bit of a silly question to most, but recently I had a situation where I helped someone on chat in relation to a question they'd posted. It took some time to figure out and they were obviously a little over excited afterwards, and after marking my answer as correct, s/he upvoted a few of my other questions and answers.

Now, obviously I'm grateful that someone was very pleased with my help and the additional rep. At this point I'm assuming some of you will be thinking "Why worry about it?". I'm not complaining, and the amount of interest my posts generate is fairly low at present, so I'm not concerned with these specifically. However, it's more the concept of it: bearing in mind that Stack Overflow is an archive of knowledge, is this type of thing perhaps misleading for future users?

As I consider myself as fairly new still to Stack Overflow, is this perhaps a common practice that I've not seen before? Or, as I suspect (but am confirming) is this something to be grateful for and not worry about as people also often do the opposite of downvoting someone's posts  in retaliation for a legitimate downvote on theirs?

Comment: [See the relevant FAQ entry](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me).

Comment: @Servy - thanks for the link. It seems to mention that the fraud script runs every night (well early morning), but this incident happened about 2 or 3 days ago, so is there a minimum of upvotes / downvotes before this is seen a serial upvoting / downvoting?

Comment: Probably, but it is not public information.

Comment: The scripts don't always catch everything.  As the FAQ says, flag suspicious voting patterns you see that don't get caught by the script.

Comment: As far as it being "common practice", no or at least shouldn't be. I've had people tell me in comments on answers or in chat that they are going to upvote some of my answers to show appreciation and I ask them to please not do that. I've also denied access to people from joining chat if I see them mentioning to someone that they are going to be doing this. It certainly isn't proper etiquette and doesn't help the site (unless of course the upvoted answers really are helpful to that person)

Comment: @codeMagic - this occurred initially without my knowledge, as in they just went off an upvoted my questions. I asked them if it was them and they said yes. I wasn't aware of serial voting occurring in this way, though it make sense to me now why it should be corrected. In this case I genuinely think the person was as clueless as I was about serial voting (in a positive way) and was just genuinely happy their issue was finally fixed. However, I certainly understand that it doesn't really help the site, hence the question.

Comment: You downvote them in return

Comment: @sr28 I understand your scenario and realize it's different then the ones I gave. I was just giving you my thoughts on it and ways to handle it when you do know prior that someone is going to do it. And yes, ignorance to how the system works is probably the culprit most of the time. That's why I typically state politely not to do it and why.

Comment: @random - downvote what? Your own questions that they've upvoted? I didn't think you could down vote your own questions!? If you mean their questions, that seems a bit harsh if they were genuinely trying to be nice.

Comment: Wait for 24 hours to see if the script catches it and reverses it. They should place a bounty and award it to your answer. That is the normal way of showing gratitude on SO.

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion - this happened 2 or 3 days ago, so presumably wasn't caught by the script. We're talking 50 additional rep, so not huge amounts for most of you, and may explain why it wasn't caught. However, it's a fair increase for me, which doesn't seem justified. I'm guessing a bounty would have been the way to go, but perhaps like me the user didn't initially think their question would be that tricky for them to get fixed and simply didn't think to add one.

Comment: In that case, you can flag any upvoted post using the others flag, and mention what happened clearly in the custom text. They will investigate and reverse the votes if it's from the same user.

Comment: I believe @random was having fun. [You forgot to bring your sense of humor](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/259917/how-does-meta-stack-overflow-work/259920#259920)

Comment: @codeMagic - thanks for pointing that out. I thought it was a bit harsh and thought I may have understood. Turns out I had...

Comment: It looks like you got 4 upvotes on questions and 3 upvotes on answers within 2 minutes. This happened 2 days ago. I'm somewhat surprised that the script didn't detect this as serial voting, assuming they all came from your "fan" (which seems likely).

Comment: @RetoKoradi - that seems about right. I've flagged 1 of the questions (as suggested by @InfiniteRecursion) for moderation with an explanation, so I'd expect them all to get reversed at some point.

Comment: @codeMagic I'm going to upvote your questions, I like you. What chat are you room owner of again? :)

Comment: Man how are you people attracting all these serial upvoters? Maybe it's an avatar thing....

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Good question: you've come across something known as [serial voting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me).

You touched on it above, but it is generally when *one user* upvotes or downvotes a large number of another *specific user*'s posts in a short amount of time.

The exact definition of serial voting (time/quantity) isn't published to prevent people from gaming the system (i.e. pushing the votes *right* to the limit where it still has an impact but isn't reversed).

There's nothing that you can do about it on your own: the votes (one way or the other) should be reversed when the serial voting reversal script runs every day at 3 AM UTC.

If they aren't, you could flag the user for suspicious voting patterns (flag one of their posts with a custom moderator flag and explain the situation), but I'm assuming you're happy with the extra rep and probably don't want to do that in this case.

Unless it was substantial enough to warrant moderator intervention, I wouldn't worry about it (it's usually more of a problem with serial **downvoting**).

That said, votes should be based on a specific post's merit (or lack thereof) and not who posted them.

Comment: You shouldn't be posting on meta if you suspect voting fraud.  If the script doesn't take care of it, you should be contacting a mod.

Comment: @Servy True: I'm just so used to seeing "User X downvoted all of my posts: what do I do?"

Comment: @AstroCB - good answer. Thanks. In this case I wouldn't really want to flag the user for suspicious voting patterns as ultimately I became aware of it when I asked them and could've asked them to correct it. In hindsight I should've done but wasn't aware of serial upvoting and was simply curious about it (hence the question), so it's as much my fault as theirs.