# Sometimes I reward users by upvoting some of their answers and questions .. should it be discouraged?

Tags: discussion, upvotes, serial-voting

Sometimes I feel that a user was particularly helpful. And I don't want to lose 100 of my own points, which I struggled to earn.

So what I do? I go to their profile, I pick an answer they gave.. and I upvote it. Then I might do that again the next day.

And I think it happened to me once, something similar.

I call it -the  "sneaky bounty"

I was curious - is this behavior to be discouraged?

Comment: Yes, the behaviour is indeed to be discouraged. You are focusing on the user, not the content.

Comment: Well if you do it for only one post per user it isn't a big deal in my opinion, but serially upvoting multiple posts is definitely not the way to go (and will be reversed the next day).

Comment: Doing it once when there is extenuating circumstances is one thing.... doing it repeatedly is definitely serial upvoting, even if it isn't caught by the script.

Comment: ...see also: [Serial upvoting reversed](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252090/839601) and [What should you do if someone starts upvoting your posts as in gratitude?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/268746/839601)

Comment: You upvote sheet content you get the whip

Comment: Also see the definition of serial voting: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me

Comment: I can tell from voting patterns that this is a pretty common practice.  SO users following a favorite or high-rep other SO user and reading the questions they answer.  In effect using them as a filter.  Very inappropriate of course, they should have to dig through the cr*p to find something worthwhile like everybody else ;)

Comment: As others have said, that is strongly discouraged. Do not do that, it defeats the purpose of the voting system.

Answer (score 17):

> is this behavior to be discouraged?

Yes, it should.

Voting should be done against posts, not users.

Our vote fraud detection scripts have a real problem detecting intent.

If you want to reward someone with reputation - give them some of yours, in the form of a bounty - there is even a bounty reason to that effect.

Answer (score 15):

Yes, the behaviour is indeed to be discouraged. You are focusing on the user, not the content.

If you can find another answer by the user that is *actually helpful to you*, then you'd have a better reason to upvote that answer. But you are still only finding that answer because you are focusing on the user. In the long run that'll still introduce bias in the scoring of answers. Better answers by other users are not getting that same attention from you.

Bounties don't create such a bias, you can reward bounties from your own reputation specifically for existing answers.