# What is 'rep for rep'?

Tags: discussion, reputation

I've been using SO for answers for years and just recently am making efforts at contributing by answering questions, so my knowledge of the etiquette is lacking.

I recently answered a question for a member, to which he accepted the answer, and in the comments left a "Thanks for your help. Rep for rep?" type comment.  I am only assuming that the user is asking me to help out with his reputation since he accepted my answer, but honestly I'm unsure how to, or if that's even something that is accepted here?  I really love Stack Overflow and certainly don't want to do anything that's frowned upon.

Comment: Never heard of this before, but just judging by it's nature, I'm fairly confident it's an attempt to make you do something you shouldn't be doing.

Comment: I guess that user means "You up vote me, I upvote you". **Don't do that!**  Voting should be based on the content and quality of a post and not on a person.

Comment: related, but without the invite part: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268746/what-should-you-do-if-someone-starts-upvoting-your-posts-as-in-gratitude?rq=1

Comment: Read: _Quid pro quo_. Not actually _frowned upon_, but doesn't meet the general consensus, that voting should be done for quality of posts solely.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Voting on people's posts in exchange for them voting on yours would actually be voting fraud.  Not only would that be frowned upon, but that'd merit vote reversal and potentially moderation action.

Comment: @Servy Okey. I at least pointed out what's problematic.

Comment: There are times where a commenter solves my problem and I tell them "thanks, I'll see if I find any of your other answers useful" I'll track down an answer they wrote that was informative to me and upvote. This isn't blind rep-for-rep but definitely something I do from time to time.

Comment: I wonder why SE doesn't block this phrase... its only purpose is to break the system, encouraging users to vote for users not for content.

Comment: Perhaps they were only suggesting that since they accepted your answer you might like to upvote their question in return. Which is fair enough, IMHO. If a question if good enough to be worth answering then surely it's good enough to deserve an upvote...

Comment: @PM2Ring [if only that were true](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/41570?m=32387326#32387326)

Comment: @PM2Ring: Not necessarily so. I sometimes come across questions that are so bad, they probably deserve a downvote if anything, but I always try to make a good faith effort to answer if I can. The two things are not related.

Comment: @Braiam Seems valid perl construct for me... I wouldn't ban that as it is...

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire what?

Comment: @Braiam "I wonder why SE doesn't block this phrase..." The sentence "rep for rep" seems like a valid construct syntax (yet incomplete) in several languages. So I don't see why this should be blocked.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire searched for it and guess what I found... many quid pro quo posts.

Comment: @PM2Ring I am mitigated by your comment. "since they accepted your answer you might like to upvote their question in return." <- that is utter nonsense. In fact, this "in return" part is scary. It have nothing to do here. "If a question if good enough to be worth answering then surely it's good enough to deserve an upvote" <- That, however, does sounds about right. /me is confused by how you seem to see things ;)

Comment: This has been very interesting to watch, and I thank everyone for their input.  The commenter in question had a very low rep (below 20, if I recall?) at the time of his comment.  I think that it's probably just ignorance of the rules and etiquette here.  The ironic part about this whole thing is that I did upvote his post before I read that comment, simply because I did think it was an interesting question based on what he was doing in his CSS (it was something I hadn't ran across before).  Then after reading all this I tried to go back and undo the vote, which I failed to figure out how to do

Comment: @ChrisPratt: I try to avoid answering outright bad questions. But if the question looks like it could be improved then I may attempt to get the OP to fix it via comments, &/or by editing it myself. With borderline cases, where the OP's intent is clear but the question needs improvement in grammar & formatting, I may answer it first and then clean it up later.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier: And I'm somewhat confused by your comment. Maybe your definition of the word "mitigated" is different to mine. :)

Comment: @RobertWade: There's a small time window in which you can undo your vote on a post. After that window has expired you can only change your vote if the post is modified.

Comment: @PM2Ring I blame my lacking understanding of the english language! Yeah sorry, maybe I mean something like "ambivalent"? I realize mitigated really is not well used there...

Comment: @Robert: _" Then after reading all this I tried to go back and undo the vote"_ -- if you honestly felt his question was useful, there's no need to go back and undo the vote. Just make sure when you vote, you are voting solely on the quality of the question, good or bad. From your statement, it seems like in this case you had. So the vote is fine.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier: I like to reward good behaviour. So if the OP has tried to do the right thing, has made a genuine attempt at asking a good question, has responded well to comments requesting clarification and sample input & output, and has accepted an answer, I'm more than happy to reward them with an upvote. Sure, it's nice when they've accepted _my_ answer, but if they've accepted another answer that's fine too, assuming the other answer is better than mine. :) And in such cases I'm quite likely to upvote the competing answer too.

Comment: @Peter: Thank you.  Being new to contributing, i'm just a little nervous of doing the wrong thing :)

Comment: @PM2Ring: _"I'm more than happy to reward them with an upvote"_ -- then you are doing the wrong thing. The rest of us who are actually _using_ the site need for votes to be an accurate signal of the quality of the content. Any time you "reward" someone for behavior other than specifically the quality of their content, you are undermining and subverting the whole reason for the voting system.

Comment: @PeterDuniho: As I've tried to explain, I'm not merely rewarding good behaviour, I'm rewarding the good behaviour of someone who has asked what I consider to be a good question. Perhaps I should upvote these questions before I answer them, and let the chips fall where they may... If I see a good question & it already has good answers, so I don't feel like I need to answer it myself, then I upvote it straight away, and vote as I feel appropriate on the answers. But I feel a slightly different tactic on questions that I'm answering is reasonable, if somewhat mercenary. ;)

Comment: To clarify vote reversal mentioned above.. Make sure you do **not** go into a user's profile and start voting on his posts. This would get reversed in most cases.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

From your description I can only assume that it's a form of "scratch my back and I'll scratch yours". The OP has taken an action which has given you additional reputation and now they expect the same.

Long story short: **Vote for content, not for people.** Not only would such a vote exchange be frowned upon, it would most likely classify as fraud. So feel free to ignore the user.

If you find their contribution(s) to be worthy of a vote on their own merit, by all means vote as you see fit. But you should not vote for anyone based on who they are or how much they valued your own contributions.

Comment: and the site has tools to detect such massive upvoting and votes may be reversed if such abuse is detected.

Comment: Hmm ... it seems my sockpuppet is editing my answers now ... this may not be a good sign @codygray

Comment: I would also flag that comment as "not constructive" (or a custom flag if that user has a history of doing this "deals").

Comment: By accepting the answer that user gained +2 rep. So the back is already scratched.

Comment: I'll also add that SO isn't a normal social media. When you upvote something without reason, it goes on the "good quality" page. However, if you vote for it as a quid pro quo, then content that doesn't deserve to rise rises.

Answer (score 51):

Thanks for asking. As several people have written in comments and the other answer, this is not an acceptable type of activity. Please don't do it.

I'm writing an answer just to give a moderator's perspective. From context, "rep for rep?" clearly means, "Vote for me, and I'll vote for you." That is, a *quid pro quo*. Whether that's limited to a particular question and its answers or was meant more broadly, it's voting fraud either way.

Votes should be based on the quality of a post. Period. Any behavior that is not in line with that rule—sockpuppetry, targeted voting for friends and colleagues, quid pro quo voting like you described here, or anything else that's not organic voting based on quality—is almost certainly in violation of one or more site policies. That means people are likely to hear from the moderators and lose any illegitimate reputation. Depending on the circumstances, they may also face a suspension.

So, thanks for asking, but please don't do this kind of thing. A flag is definitely appropriate in such cases. A custom flag highlighting the issue would be most helpful.

Comment: In case I work in a team of 3 people, and after struggling with my team a while to solve one problem, one of us comes to SO and ask a question. Is it fraud if the other 2 people vote up on the question?

Comment: Good answer. Could you perhaps clarify if such comments should be flagged for moderator attention, should I ever be unfortunate enough to stumble upon one?

Comment: @Guedes If they have the same question and happen to see your post, no, of course not. If you are sending people to that question and encouraging them to upvote (even implicitly), yes, that's a problem.

Comment: @Anders yes, a flag is definitely appropriate in such cases. A custom flag highlighting the issue would be most helpful.