# Is it unethical to offer vote trades?

Tags: discussion, voting, upvotes, voting-fraud, ethics

Recently, I provided a helpful comment on an answer. After adding its information to their answer, the author replied with a comment asking if I'd mind upvoting the answer (which I'd already done) and mentioning they were looking through my posts and would upvote a couple. This felt to me like an implication that we would essentially trade upvotes, boosting each other's reputation.

Now, in this case I think it was just a poor choice of phrasing; I replied with a friendly reminder to vote for content, not people, they replied that they indeed intended to do so, and we deleted our back-and-forth comments to clean up the post.

But more generally—were such an offer actually intended, it would be unethical, right? Is there any particular policy or guideline about such matters?

Comment: Related: [What should you do if someone starts upvoting your posts as in gratitude?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/268746/4642212).

Comment: You should report any commentary requesting votes as unnecessary

Comment: That sounds like a very short voting-ring.  I am not sure how anyone might consider a conspiracy to mutually increase rep to be ethical?

Comment: No, it's not appropriate to discuss votes in any way in comments. Please flag any/all such comments as "no longer needed" so that a moderator can remove them. If you suspect that a user is exchanging votes, then you can raise a custom flag for moderator attention on one of the user's posts and use the provided textbox to explain your concerns.