# What does it mean to accept an answer on meta?

Tags: discussion, meta, accepted-answer

I read [How does Meta Stack Overflow work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/259917/how-does-meta-stack-overflow-work), but it doesn't state what it *means* when someone accepts an answer.

So, what is the procedure for an "answered" question that has to do with a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)?

Comment: It is basically up to the OP. For feature-requests I would accept an answer by a developer saying that the feature will be implemented, or an answer explaining why it should NOT be implemented, if it convinced me (as the OP).

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96039/if-votes-works-differently-on-meta-sites-how-does-that-of-accepting-answers-work, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61760/should-discussion-questions-have-an-accepted-answer, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85095/when-do-you-accept-an-answer-on-meta, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33610/meta-of-meta-what-should-we-accept-as-accepted-answers-of-feature-requests

Comment: I always thought that acceptance of an answer means that this is the favored answer by the asker. Nothing more and nothing less and independent of if it is on a regular stackexchange or on a meta stackexchange.

Comment: It doesn't mean a lot and is a totally subjective exercise, nearly just an indication the OP is satisfied with something

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Similar to voting, accepting an answer (or otherwise) is a prerogative of the OP (both on Main and Meta sites). On Meta specifically, there are no guideline or standard behavior. A few reasons due to which OP may accept an answer are:

- A reported [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) was fixed or mod/SE team replies back that the behavior is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)
- A [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) has been implemented or has been marked as [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)
- A [support](/questions/tagged/support) post was answered which helped OP
- A [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) post was answered such that OP got convinced or there seems to be a community consensus around it

---

> what does it mean when someone accepts an answer.

**Actually, nothing much!**

Comment: What does it mean when OP accepts this answer?

Comment: @Jodast read the point for [discussion]:" A discussion post was answered such that OP got convinced or there seems to be a community consensus around it." This question is a discussion, so that's probably the reason the OP accepted this answer.

Comment: In that case, it either means that there is a community consensus, or an "alternative truth".

Answer (score 6):

It is the same as on the main site, so see [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

> Accepting an answer is not meant to be a definitive and final statement indicating that the question has now been answered perfectly. **It simply means that the author received an answer that worked for him or her personally**, but not every user comes back to accept an answer, and of those who do, they may not change the accepted answer if a newer, better answer comes along later.

Answer (score 0):

Original plans for Meta proposed ditching the concept.

> [Kyle Cronin](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/658/nobody) had some ideas about changes to the SO engine to help it adapt from the Q&A; format discussion:
>
> > ...remove accepting an answer...

[~ From an old SO blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/cmon-get-meta/).

---

To answer your question: it means little more than all the meta bounties you might wish for.