# Is there no automatic throttling or banning of users who repeatedly post profane comments?

Tags: feature-request, comments, rude-or-abusive

I recently found myself under a deluge of profane comments by a user who didn't appreciate my negative feedback (and people wonder why users often don't comment when down-voting). There has been at least a dozen or more profanity-filled comments posted by this user, addressing me.

These comments have all been deleted, in most cases nearly immediately. Which I presume happened automatically after multiple users flagged them (I'm assuming multiple users are required, because in a couple of cases, the comment did not disappear immediately after I flagged it, but did a short while later).

I am surprised that this user is (was…they have in fact now been suspended) able to keep posting comments. I would have thought that the system would detect that they had a large number of "rude or abusive" flags on their comments over a short period of time (minutes), and they'd be automatically locked down with a comment ban, or even a temporary suspension of the user entirely.

Is there no such algorithm in place? Should there be?

Related: even if there's no automatic algorithm to comment-ban or suspend a user, is there at least automatic notification to the moderators that such activity is going on? I did flag the comment author's post (i.e. their question under which all the comments were being posted), and am aware that's a mechanism for getting the attention of a moderator. I'm asking here about *automatic* processes that exist, if any.

Comment: Yes I'd agree with this, I can't imagine any reason for using profanity on SO.

Comment: Looks like I was wrong, I thought the system also worked on comments flags -.-

Comment: Currently, You can mod flag one of the user's posts if they are persistently posting such comments and explain the situation

Comment: @SurajRao: yes, done. My question is about an _automatic_ process. Though, I guess I'd also be interested in knowing if there's at least automatic notification to moderators. Question updated.

Comment: _"There's an automatic moderator flag after a user gets a number of Rude/Abusive flags on comments, but nothing that will automatically ban them."_ ([source](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/42372273#42372273)), so that's a "yes" on the "related" you just added :-)

Comment: @yivi, No, the comments were cleared because a normal user casted a "rude or abusive" flag, and the content of the comment was rude enough for it to be automatically deleted.

Comment: @BhargavRao Thanks. I was just speculating on their sudden disappearance and trying to think like a crook, before I saw your answer. :P

Comment: @George : I can see a reason : get banned.

Comment: Are we not allowed to be rude on SO?

Comment: @Steve: https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice

Comment: @PeterDuniho Is this a part of the tour?

Comment: @Steve: sorry, I don't understand your question. Are you asking how to find the tour? If you know how to find the tour, why does posting a comment asking someone else to describe the tour seem more appropriate than just looking at the tour?

Comment: @PeterDuniho Really? The question confuses you? Lemme rephrase this. Why is this not a part of the introduction to SO?

Comment: @Steve I think the easy answer here is that whoever designed the tour didn't add the be nice link to it.... I don't really see what asking a non Stack employee or mod about that is meant to achieve. Is the intent "if it's not presented in the tour then it's not a rule?"

Comment: @Steve: I fail to see how _"Why is this not a part of the introduction to SO?"_  could be considered a simple "rephrasing" of _"Is this a part of the tour?"_. Those are two completely different questions. As for the rephrased one, it's not clear to me why you think I would know. I _do_ know that it takes exactly one click from the tour to get to the general help page, where the "Be Nice" link is prominently displayed. Not being rude is a common standard on many community web sites, and it's a well-documented standard here.

Comment: @PeterDuniho It's not part of the tour. Seems weird considering that this is a pretty essential part of the website. I am actually not part of any other community online where not being rude is a standard part, aside from the other SO communities that I did not know being nice was a part of; this is BIG news to me.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

No, there's no such system for auto throttling users who leave a lot of rude comments.

> These comments have all been deleted, in most cases nearly immediately.

These happened because the comments were sufficiently rude enough for them to be deleted by one flag.

> I would have thought that the system would detect that they had a large number of "rude or abusive" flags on their comments

Yes, this raises an [automatic moderator flag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284053/community-deletion-of-comments-should-raise-a-moderator-flag). In fact there were nearly a dozen of those flags raised, which is why it bumped to the top of the moderator queue within seconds. (While I agree that the situation was handled *a bit* late, it was under control within 10 minutes.). Custom moderator flags would be fine as well, and would help us analyse the situation faster than just the automatic flag.

(In case such a thing occurs again, remember to use the "rude or abusive" flags for these. Multiple r/a comment flags would raise the automatic moderator flag.)

> Should there be?

I agree that some sort of throttling would be great, but given that this occurs very rarely, on Stack Overflow, I feel that using comment flags and the moderator attention flags would be enough. I don't think that there is much to gain from spending more development hours on this, as compared to what is already present.

---

There is a [community project to detect heat in comments](https://stackapps.com/questions/7001/heat-detector-analysing-comments-to-find-heat), which quickly detected that the [conversation was going down south.](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/40882746#40882746).

Comment: _"it was under control within 10 minutes"_ -- to be clear, I didn't consider the response time late at all. I think it would have been better for some automatic logic to step in to fill the gap, but when actual humans have to get involved, a ten minute wait, or even more, is not unreasonable (I might start to question response time after a few hours, or certainly at least after a few days, but otherwise... :) )

Comment: Based on what seems like reasonable guidance [described here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269266/what-does-it-mean-to-accept-an-answer-on-meta), I'm going to assume that the feature request will be approved or declined independently of whatever disposition I make of answers here, and in particular indicating by accepting it the "most helpful" (which notes that it's not likely the feature will be implemented, but doesn't seem to make an official pronouncement one way or the other). Please advise if accepting an answer before the feature request is addressed is the wrong thing to do

Comment: Hmm, I don't think that accepting an answer should cause any issue, @Peter. I've seen a few bugs taken care of, even after a non-official answer was accepted.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware, there isn't a systematic punishment for extra abusive comments as of now, but only an automatic moderator flag informing that there are a lot of comments deleted by flags. In that case, we raise custom flags (aka mod flags) explaining the situation and hope a moderator will manually issue a ban or other kinds of punishment.

I suggest that in addition to flagging the comments, flag one of the user's posts (or your own) for moderator attention. That's because there's currently no red flags on comments, and all flags on a comment will be dismissed upon comment removal, either by its owner, by the accumulation of flags, or by a moderator. This makes flags on comments less noticeable if the comments are removed too quickly.