# Reputation change showing wrong number

Tags: bug, reputation, notifications

Just a few minutes ago, I opened Stack Overflow and saw a green "+3" at the top. It only showed [one of my questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10645339/how-to-detect-when-form-resizing-starts-and-stops) related to this reputation change. However, my reputation actually went up by 5 (someone upvoted that question).

The only reason I can assume is that the prior activity was -2 from someone downvoting another one of my questions days ago. So although my reputation went from 7263 to 7268 (+5), it instead showed +3, even though I acknowledged the -2 days ago. I do understand this reasoning, because since the last notification I literally did get +3, but I would expect this to have been +5, because what if the -2 was from many months ago? It becomes misleading. I think it should show only the total recent increase, not subtracting the recent decrease.

On another note, I'm curious why my reputation here on MSO is suddenly 7263 with only 2 questions???

Comment: Your reputation here is a copy from the main site, synched once an hour. See [How does Meta Stack Overflow work?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/259917)

Comment: @MartijnPieters Then it hasn't updated with my recent +5 yet, but that's another story :-)

Comment: It is synchronised once every hour. It'll update in the next hour to reflect the latest change.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I see, I haven't been here much since the MSO/MSE split

Answer (score 5):

The green number only ever updates when there are *positive* changes. Your last positive change was an upvote for your question on October 22.

The downvote is a *negative* change, so it was never shown in the green achievements counter.

Today you received another upvote, and you are shown the net change since last time you received a positive change. You got a -2 and a +5 since that last positive change, and the net change is thus +3.

It doesn't matter that you opened the achievements dropdown since you received the downvote; that doesn't 'clear' the -2 as it was never shown in the counter.

Comment: Today I've seen three different reputation changes on my profile. There was a raise of 12 points then removed wi no activity on my side! then a drop of two points from 62 with no activity again ( I actually took screenshots of this one) I really don't care about it but was curious and would like it if a moderator could have a look into it in case of a bug.

Comment: @NasrinShirali please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269653/why-did-i-gain-lose-reputation-can-i-audit-my-reputation-history; there is nothing out of the ordinary going on with your account.