# Possibly wrong reputation increment notification

Tags: bug, notifications

Today I log in into my SO account and saw a `+5` rep change (#1 on the image) and in profile `+10` rep change. I know about that [site is notifying only the recent up change](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/275323/2521214) but when I click on the notify to see the pop-up I saw that no new event has been logged only one `+10` change (#2 on image) the rest (#3 on image) was notified yesterday and I am 100% sure I clicked on it (but it was one of the last things I did before going off). Here Screenshot (luckily I spot it before I click anywhere again...):

[image: Screenshot]

This is really minor bug (if bug and not something else I am overlooking) and I do not really care if it is repaired or not I just post this so you **DEV**'s know about it.

My bet is that my previous notify click was not saved (I think it happens few times before I clicked on `+10` change and in a day or so I see the same notify event for the same event without any change in between but that could be done by different cause...)

Or there was some other event in between that I do not see.

**PS** rep change log from profile checks with the notify log except that it is in different order which could hint something.

Comment: Yes, +10 +10 -15 is +5. You got two answer upvotes and one "unaccept" (removing the 15 you got for it before). It sounds like the thing you're 100% sure of either didn't happen after all, or maybe you closed the browser before the request got there. Clearly SO "believes" that all those three events are new, hence the background colour.

Comment: @JonSkeet As I mentioned the `+10 -15+15` was already notified yesterday so only the newest `+10` should be notified. Instead it somehow  forgot it and notify `+10+10-15` again as all new. while only the first `+10` was really new. Sorry I do not have screenshot from yesterday as there was not problem then ... Or it is correct beahvior and it reflect only last positive changes (ignoring previous notifications)? not remembering any clicks ....

Comment: @JonSkeet but it can be accumulation of the day before where I got another -15 unaccept  in such case it would make sense And  I would be `-5` deficit but why to heck it would then notify positive change yesterday?.

Comment: While we are at it, can't we be notified of rep losses?

Comment: No, it looks fairly clearly not to do with the previous day - the "new" notifications are in blue, and add up correctly. So yes, for some reason it didn't "know" that you'd seen the previous notification - but there's really no way of finding out now why that was. The totalling side of things looks fine to me.