# Reputation alert in top bar doesn't match reputation change

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, achievements-dialog

I have noticed this a few times in Firefox and Chrome on my laptop, and today I finally grabbed a screenshot from Chrome on my phone.  The green reputation icon in the top bar does not match the actual change.  I have not had any activity on other SE sites recently.

[image]

I looked at [this meta discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275322/reputation-change-showing-wrong-number?rq=1), and the answer there indicates that the green number only updates with positive changes:

> you are shown the net change since last time you received a positive change

However my last negative was 13 days ago and I have had several other positive changes since.

Comment: I would blame caching but I'm sure this is a dupe but I can't find a proper one

Comment: I would blame caching too - but none of those numbers added together equal 8.  I could see getting, 2, 4, 10, 12, or 14 in a caching situation, but not 8.

Comment: You also lost 6 points due to deleted posts. *Those are reflected in the score*.

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense @MartijnPieters - I can't actually see that anywhere, can I?  And thanks for finding the dup.  I looked but only found some that were pretty old and didn't seem to answer the question.

Comment: @JenR: yes, you can see those posts when you check the 'show removed posts' checkbox on your reputation page. See [Why did I gain/lose reputation? Can I audit my reputation history?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269653)