# How a user can be a mod on per-site meta and not be a mod on main site?

Tags: discussion, moderators

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/31280/alex-warren

He is a mod *there*, but not a mod on the SO. Was it set specifically by devs? Usually employes have diamond *both* on meta and main...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Stack Exchange Employees have their moderator flag set manually per site, as most don't need to have that level of access.

Clearly for Alex it was set just on Meta, presumably so he can set [moderator-only tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/259917/how-does-meta-stack-overflow-work/259970#259970) on posts by himself.

Comment: oh wait, can I get this mod flag? :D

Comment: @nicael - I would very much doubt it.

Comment: @nicael: anyone can get a mod flag. You, me, everybody. We just not going to get it unless you are a) elected, b) appointed pro-tem, or c) employed by Stack Exchange, and even then only if you are a software dev and actually need it set.

Comment: I asked this just because I thought it is a bug after MSO-MSE split.

Comment: @nicael: no accounts were migrated in the split.

Comment: While it would take a mod to confirm, I seem to recall that an elected mod has to accept the mod agreement twice - once for the main site, once for meta.  Or something like that.  The point being is that even for *elected* mods, it works this way.  The moderator bit is not set on both sites automatically.

Answer (score 7):

He's a developer.

They can flick the "moderator" switch on any account as necessary. In this case it will probably be so he can use the moderator only tags.