# Constraint to down-vote comment which lead confusion

Tags: discussion

Up voting comment exploit.

If *X* comment after the question and *Y* up voted it just after that.
*X*  edit back the comment. there are chances that EDITED COMMENT may completely changed for what it was up voted.

My suggestion are

> - Upvoting time must  starts after the editing  time of that comment finished.
> - Owner of comment  have rights to downvote (neutralized state)  during the editing time of comment  ( 5 minutes)
> - SO must send the notification  to the voter  "The comment has been edited which you upvote " .It would be only for 5 Minutes
> - Y have facility to downvote and upvote again during editing timing.
> - *Z*  have rights to down vote the comment.

***EDIT***

@James,  I agree with your answer upto some extent that it's just a comment.

I am not talking about the general comment s like *" place your code"*  or *" what you done so far?"*

Yes, notification are bad idea although but to save the notifications flood can we add constraint on such notifications or show in activity tab. My algorithm is to implement this  is below

```
cmt_X =  X comment is edited more than n times and have ` within 

If(cmt_X ) { 
  - notification sent to Y ( or display in activity tab )
   - Y have rights to down vote their own up vote
   or/and 
  - X can neutralize the up vote for 5 minutes AND notification sent to Y )
}
```

and this should works till the comment editing timing

Comment: I don't think comment upvotes being miscounted because of an edit changing their content is a major issue on SO. I mean, I doubt anyone is seriously considering a 5 minute comment bait and switch.

Comment: it's a major issue. sometimes the edited comments has syntactical errors. and voted guy  seldom comes back to see the changes.

Comment: If the comment is upworthy with syntactical errors, then why would the upvoter remove the vote after the syntactical errors are corrected?

Comment: mainly it's misleading others. many times,  comments have more solution for others and if a wrong upvote is there, on the wrong comment , then it''s misleading.

Comment: Yes it may be worthy. so if one upvoted after the editing timing of that comment then these feature would be more worthy.

Comment: Meh, I don't really see this as an often abused issue. And comments really aren't all that important anyway.

Comment: OR  I am asking for that this feature should be given to `X` during the editing time. after that you can disable this permission (rights to downvote)

Comment: comments are more important. it contains similar solution on different OS or language specific which was not even asked in the real Question.

Comment: I clicked once upvote by accident on totally nonsense comment, so it is another reason why neutralizing vote function would be welcome. +1 for me.

Comment: Yup, this is possible. Is it a *real problem*? No, I don't think so. You are making this into too big a thing.

Comment: @MartijnPieters that's why i tagged with suggestion. but you people just downvote. I may have not enough word to explain the problem.

Comment: @diEcho: see [How does Meta Stack Overflow work?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/259918); voting means something different on Meta.

Comment: Yes. `To promote free discussion, votes have no effect on your reputation.` But I don't think people will even look at the question which has -4 :\ and a high repo person commented under the question, so people leave  the question with "that guy will handle it"

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure this is really that much of an issue. It's only a comment.

### [What are comments?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)

> Comments are **temporary** "Post-It" notes left on a question or answer.
>   They can be up-voted (but not down-voted) and flagged, but do not
>   generate reputation. There's no revision history, and when they are
>   deleted they're gone for good.

There is no rep associated in any way.
And an upvote on a comment simply signifies "this seems good advice".
But they are simply "footnotes".

### **EDIT** for your changes.

I think you are placing way too much importance on comments.
Heck, often comments are not even relevant or contextual in any way to the question or answer they're under, just some side discussion, and so upvotes are just "I agree".

> Upvoting time must starts after the editing time of that comment finished.

*Disabling* comment upvoting for 5 mins to stop the scenario you highlight, introduces the issue that comments will lose a lot of upvotes.
Users often spend **well under** 5 minutes in a question, and so we would lose potentially useful upvotes.
Quick upvotes on comments are good, as they indicate community agree, and negates need for additional comments stating "I agree with James" etc.

---

> Owner of comment have rights to downvote (neutralized state) during the editing time of comment ( 5 minutes)

See here relevant answer here by Jon Skeet:
https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/3620/230506

---

> SO must send the notification to the voter "The comment has been
>   edited which you upvote " .It would be only for 5 Minutes

I comment quite a lot, and I would not like notifications on comments, so can imagine users with more activity than myself will simply be bombarded with notifications of comment changes, along with everything else we notify.
I think the current notifications can sometimes be a little OTT, although fine mostly, any more notifications and they become a nuisance, and lose some of their usefulness.

Also, we'd have to "rush" to action this, given your proposal only gives us a limited time to action our upvote on an edited comment.

All this "pestering" and activity and technical functionality, for comments? It's just not worthwhile.

---

> Y have facility to downvote and upvote again during editing timing.
>   Z have rights to down vote the comment.

Again, these are *just comments*, and I do not think they need to be so complicated, or technical, or have so much "*functionality*".
It's a "simple" comment eg  "I don't think this is a good idea", "You shouldn't do that like that" etc.
They're not answers, and so do not need and shouldn't have anywhere close to the same functionality as answers, which is essentially what you are introducing.

Also, we do not want comments changing to and fro all the time, up and downvotes changing, etc. We won't know where we are with the comments.

They should be and remain "simple", a "*little note*".

---

You can *un-upvote* a comment, within the first 60 seconds (provided you did not navigate away).
As comments can only be changed in the first 5 mins, that's a 4 minute window of your scenario happening.
I don't believe this will happen very much.

In short, (and this is a personal opinion) so what if my upvote on a comment is no longer valid. If happens what, once every 1,000 comments? If that.

Comment: Thanks for clearing out my question.  I have updated my question and gives suggestion.

Comment: please see my suggestion in question. it's long so unable to right comment