# What is the criteria for closing a question?

Tags: discussion

I don't understand why [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27219134/update-a-file-in-java) was closed and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27204792/sort-hashmap-of-arraylist-based-on-arraylist5-size) was not. Can someone explain what's the difference? I think both do not meet the standard for a good question.

---

EDIT: Looks like some people agree about *"There was no effort made on behalf of the OP in one, where the other did show an attempt"*. I see no attempt in either, what attempt you're talking about exactly?

Comment: There was no effort made on behalf of the OP in one, where the other did show an attempt.

Comment: Sorry, first time using meta... Can someone explain why the downvote?

Comment: In the 2nd question there was at least some attempting code given. It's also not completely fitting SO policies, though someone seemed to find an appropriate answer

Comment: @MartijnPieters I see no attempt to solve anything in the question, can you please detail?

Comment: See [How does Meta Stack Overflow work?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/259917); although in this case, there isn't a hell of a lot of information in your question.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Code is part of the question, not of an attempted solution.

Comment: Can you at least detail *in your question* why you have a problem with the two posts?

Comment: @m0skit0  _"Can someone explain why the downvote?"_ Disagreement ...

Comment: @MartijnPieters You mean this is a duplicated question? What more information is needed?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Sorry, I think I made it clear: why one is closed and the other is not? Just trying to understand when a question is a legit one and when it is not.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Disagreement with what? With posing a question? The question itself? Is it wrong? How can I improve it? Sorry, first time asking on meta.

Comment: @m0skit0: and clearly you feel both are not legit. Can you make that *explicit*.

Comment: @m0skit0: your question is devoid of context. You state no discussion points.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ok thanks, I didn't know my personal opinion on the subject I'm asking was actually relevant.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Sorry, what context? Context is StackOverflow rules.

Comment: @MartijnPieters The discussion point is why is one worth closing while the other is not. Isn't that a discussion point? Maybe I tagged it wrong, what tag should I use? Or isn't this a valid question? If so, why?

Comment: @m0skit0: personally, I don't see much of a discussion here. You disagree with one of the questions not being closed. Did you cast a close vote on the one you think should be closed too? I don't see any close votes on it. Why do you feel that that post should be closed? What is lacking, and what is the cost to the site if it remains open?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I can go and cast a close vote, would that solve the problem of no close votes? Would my close vote be correct? If not, why? I've seen questions closed directly by moderators without any need of close votes. My questions are: are close votes needed to close such question? What is the criteria used by moderators for closing such questions? What is the difference between one question and the other? Thanks for your explanation and patience.

Comment: @m0skit0: First criteria a question has to meet to be closed by a moderator: The moderator has to see it.  There aren't enough moderators to read every question.  That's what close votes are for -- so that garbage disappears without waiting for a moderator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question that is open has the following components:

1. A suggestion that the OP had done a search and didn't find results:

   > I realize there are questions similar to this, but they do not answer my question.

   Granted, this doesn't say *much*, but there was an indication of an attempt.
2. A block of code:

   > ```
   > HashMap<String,ArrayList<Integer>> unsortedMap = new
   > HashMap<String,ArrayList<Integer>>();
   > unsortedMap.put("A",new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3)));
   > unsortedMap.put("B",new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(4)));
   > unsortedMap.put("C",new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(2,3,1,4)));
   > ```

   The code appears to be an example of an MCVE where the OP wrote some code that demonstrated the problem without going through and using the code base he or she is working on (and has lots of extraneous noise).
3. An explanation of what the code *should* do:

   > I need to return the keys of my HashMap, based on the size of the corresponding value's ArrayList.
   >   ...
   >   I'd like it to return "C" "A" "B"

While I will not claim that this is a great question, it does however meet the requirements of being a question that is answerable with an explication of what was tried and didn't work.  The answer provided goes into information about the `entrySet()` and builds upon the existing code that the OP provided.

---

The closed question, in its entirety is:

> Does anyone knows how to update a file in java. Say a file is written into, with fields name, sex, age, address. now I want to modify age. What could be the code for this problem?

It lacks all three of the components that the open question has.  As such, it becomes just a request for someone to write some code.  No attempt at writing the code first.  Or demonstrating what was attempted and didn't work.

Without the information of the file format, or the code itself not working it is *very* likely that any answers provided would not be of significant use to the OP or the next person reading the question and the answer.

Comment: Thanks, I see. Finally a useful answer :)