# Syntax highlighting help documentation

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown, syntax-highlighting, editing-help

On the help page for Markdown Editing, in the [Syntax Highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) section, it specifies to use this format for hinting at a language:

> ```
> <!-- language: lang-js -->
>     setTimeout(function () { alert("JavaScript"); }, 1000);
> ```

But this fails to work - you need to include a blank line:

> ```
> <!-- language: lang-js -->
>
>     setTimeout(function () { alert("JavaScript"); }, 1000);
> ```

I was unsure if this was a bug in the Prettify plugin, or a documentation issue, hence raising it here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a documentation bug.

It *used* to be correct, but then someone one day [removed all newlines from the samples in that page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243402/the-examples-on-all-the-markdown-help-pages-are-broken), and when they were put back, they didn't quite manage to put the double newline in those samples back.

Also see [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109) on Meta.SE.

Comment: Thanks.  Not sure of the protocol here on meta - should I mark this as the answer, or does it need to wait until it's actually fixed?

Comment: @JamesThorpe: Marking something as helpful is entirely up to you; if you want to change your mind later that is also fine. The 'accept' mark has little meaning here really.

Comment: Ok.  Wasn't sure if accepting an answer would "hide" the bug report - but after [reading around](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/259917/how-does-meta-stack-overflow-work/259970#259970), it seems like it's based on it not having one of the "official" red tags applied to the OP.

Answer (score 1):

This will be fixed in build rev `2014.12.3.2819` on meta and `2014.12.3.2062` on sites.

Comment: This has not been fixed, I'm afraid, see http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help. Or rather, there is a new issue there with the [code formatting samples](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) in that a few newlines are still missing (the initial line whitespace is marked up but joined to the preceding line).

Comment: @MartijnPieters the particular example from this question is already fixed, [this is what I see](http://i.stack.imgur.com/vNwjd.png). A fix for the 2 samples under code formatting will go live in sites build rev `2015.1.30.2259`

Comment: Yes, I meant the 2 samples under code formatting; sorry if I gave the impression the samples in the question here were b0rken again, they were still correctly spaced. Thanks for fixing those samples!