# Why does StackOverflow not support inline #hashtags for question tagging?

Tags: feature-request, tags

i can ask a question about a subject, and than i can than add some relevant [tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tags) below my question, but why can't i mark relevant keywords in my question with a `#hashtag` and let that become a #tag for the question automatically? Or perhaps can the first #hastags be added to the tags list?

My reasoning would be that it would save some typing, and allow me to let the desired tags be added #automaticly.

I can however see the objections to it as well.

Comment: Why would that be better than the explicit tag box below it? We don't want posts that are talking about Twitter hashtags or URL query fragments to create tags either.

Comment: to the downvoter; you may not like or agree with my idea, but does that make this a 'unclear or not usefull' question? I am interested in finding out hte reasoning behind this, and maybe other users as well..

Comment: Downvotes on meta express disagreement, not "non-usefulness" or "unclearness" http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta

Comment: See the [Meta FAQ](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/259917/how-does-meta-stack-overflow-work/259918#259918); voting on feature requests usually indicates disagreement that the feature should be implemented, although votes can also still indicate that the feature request is lacking in proper motivation or exposition.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I think I understand the reasoning behind that, but that's not what the downvote button label says. Might be that I am not so experienced on Meta.

Comment: @oɔɯǝɹ I agree - it's mostly just a known convention which people discover the first time they're downvoted on meta. No reputation is at stake here though.

Comment: Quite apart from judgements of the feature, this isn't a good feature request. You haven't presented any reasoning why the feature would be useful to add, or why the current behavior is insufficient.

Comment: The voting button title= popups on meta are just mislabeled. For feature requests they're best interpreted as community votes on prioritization. -- Adding extra tags on posts is already supported. Which you know of course ;] since you used `[tag:tags]`. And that's just it. It's only a very *minor syntax hurdle*, so new users don't add tag clouds habitually. Extra tags totally make sense for e.g. referencing other languages, without having to mistag the question itself. But an automated conversion of #lang to a tag, might actually screw e.g. questions about *Twitter* stuff.

Comment: @mario I thought the `[tag:syntax]` was only meant for display purposes, not for indexation?

Comment: Yes, true. They're not included in searches, but are visual only and for *linking to* other tags. Which is also because they're not meant to circumvent the 5 tags maximum.

Comment: @oɔɯǝɹ Indeed, the tooltip on meta is wrong

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The system in place now is designed to ensure questions are tagged thoughtfully and not frivolously (like an Instagram post).  There are limits on the number of tags that can be attached to prevent spamming numerous tags, and more importantly, many of the experienced users who will view a post will ***retag it* almost immediately** if it includes incorrect or superfluous tags.

Allowing hashtags in the post body would potentially "Instagram" our posts, it would be confusing to enforce the existing 5 tag limit if the number of hashtags in the post exceeds the limit allowed in the tag input field, it would be difficult to create tags or know which tags already exist (which is carefully enforced now), and it would become confusing when tags are modified (which again, they *very often are*).

So I don't think this is a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

Because in general you should **not** repeat the [tag] words in your question.  If you, say, picked [c#] then there is no point in repeating that you use C# in the body.  That's just pointless noise that distracts from the subject.  It is already assumed by anybody that reads your question, they selected it based on your tags.  Much the same for the title of your question, you don't put "C#" in that either.

Comment: Mind you, it's also assumed that people read questions before voting - from observation of voting patterns on SO (and I'm not talking about my own questions), it seems that a lot of votes are based on the title alone.

Comment: Not sure how that's relevant.  But sure, you got one chance to make a first impression, don't blow it on a bad title.

Comment: #totally #agree with #this

Comment: Why users should not repeat tag words in the question? Let's say, if I am looking for questions/answers on `scikit-learn` based on tags, if this keyword just appears in the title/text body, then I will not find it -- is this true?

Comment: They will put [scikit-learn] in the search box to narrow down the search.  If they use Google then it is already added to the title.

Answer (score 0):

This would just promote #overuse of #tags like you see on #socialmedia, where almost every noun is tagged just for the heck of it. #yolo

The tag system we have now works just fine. The post body is for the post body. #StackOverflow posts are not single-text-field status updates about that #party you had #lastnight.