# New tag request: [noobie]

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

I'm a noobie and I have a request for a noobie tag.
a noobie can't create a tag and who can don't need it.
when I try to to make that tag it says i have not enoug reputation

Comment: What exactly does the `noobie` tag define?  The fact that you are new to a technology?

Comment: no its a tag noobies can make for a question that show you questions from noobs like my

Comment: This would be really useful.  I'd put it on my ignored tags list and experience a lot less annoyance.

Comment: why the down votes?

Comment: @tijmen Because it's a terrible idea.

Comment: @tijmen: [How does Meta Stack Overflow work?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/259918), plus a dash of *no research effort*, and a soupçon of *did you deliberately misspell the tag name or what?*.

Comment: Read [the help topic on what tags are used for](http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)... maybe you'll get an inkling. Also ready the [ask] topic, because apparently you don't get how to ask a good question either.

Comment: why is it terrible @Servy

Comment: This is a terrible idea because it serves no real purpose.  Tagging a question as [Newbie] would not allow it to be of low quality or protect the poster from DVs.  No one would want to filter to just those questions, except maybe those who like answering *bunny questions*.  More likely it would be used to filter **out** those questions

Comment: One of the criterions for tags is "Can you be an expert in `[tag:x]`?" As such, this tag would be self-defeating.

Comment: Do read the links Mr Pieters posted.  DVs on meta signify agreement/disagreement

Comment: @tijmen Pro tip:  the single best way to encourage more downvotes on your post is to tell people to stop downvoting it.  (With the second place being complaining about the downvotes you're getting.)

Comment: i already did that

Comment: Yes, I know you did.  Perhaps you should re-read my last comment.

Comment: We can tell you're a noobie.  Hell, we can smell you coming a mile away.

Comment: That would earn the respect of fellow developers. "*Yeah, I have 7 gold badges in the **noobie** tag on Stack Overflow*"

Comment: ... but can haz [tag:l33t] plz?

Comment: Great idea, let's have a `GimmeTehCodez` tag too while we're at it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, this doesn't serve as a benefit to anyone.

From the [help center on creating tags](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags):

> A tag is a keyword or label that categorizes your question with other, similar questions. When you choose to create a new tag, you're asking a question in a topic that nobody before you (on this site, at least) ever has.

A [noobie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/noobie) doesn't serve that purpose so there would be no reason for this to be created. No one is going to come to Stack Overflow and search for [noobie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/noobie), they'd search for tags like [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql), [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23), etc.

Comment: okay you are right