# Are the reputation requirements for posting using certain tags visible anywhere?

Tags: discussion, tags, reputation

Apparently, certain tags have reputation requirements above and beyond the normal for asking questions; however, I can't find anything in SO or the Meta about them.  Where are these documented, or are they intentionally undocumented, and if they aren't documented anywhere, why?

Comment: There are no tags that have reputation requirements. Perhaps you got this confused with privileges somewhere?

Comment: Why do you believe specific tags have rep requirements?

Comment: please post the name of a tag with requirements above and beyond standard reputation level, as no one seems to have encountered a similar problem.

Comment: The only tags, AFAIK, that require anything speicial are the [moderator tags](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/259970)

Comment: @codeMagic: which are only used on Meta anyway, and the restriction has nothing to do with reputation.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I understand. Just pointing that out. Besides I don't know that the OP isn't referring to meta. I guess I should have added that in my comment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are no additional reputation requirements for asking questions, on any tag.

Provided your account is in [good standing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th), you can ask questions using any *already existing tag*, whatever reputation you have.

You cannot create *new* tags until you have [1500 reputation points](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags), but again, this doesn't limit you from asking questions with tags that are already available.