# Can some easily misinterpreted tags have a minimum reputation attached for use?

Tags: feature-request, tags

At present there's [no mimumum](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289913/are-the-reputation-requirements-for-posting-using-certain-tags-visible-anywhere) reputation to use any of the site tags.  But some tags are being misinterpreted by new users, and this is annoying for those users who search on tags in order to answer new questions.

In particular, the tag `red` which relates the [red language](https://github.com/red/red) is being misused by new user who think it relates to the color red (we've seen this in questions on how to set colors in JS), or even to [red hat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44137383/change-ip-in-the-http-header-on-the-server-side).  It's even more annoying as it appears in the RSS feed which goes into our [chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/291/rebol).  Sure we could change the tag to `red-lang` in every question but I would guess that there may be other tags that are being similarly misused.  And if this is the case, why not make those tags that are being misused have a reputation requirement eg. 20?

Comment: If you do this then a large portion of the legitimate questions in the tag won't reach the right audience, and there will still be *lots* of people with 20 rep that will use the tag improperly.  Clearly you know the root of the problem, the tag is poorly named and needs to be fixed.  Fix that problem.

Comment: I'm not sure if this would really help in the long term. Tags are comparably well misused even by higher rep users.

Comment: Rep is not an indicator of how well you use tags... Also... Who maintains that "poorly used tag" list? What is the criteria for a tag to get on it? To get off it? Why do you think 20 rep is the right target?

Comment: I used 20 because almost all, if not all of the tag misuse for this particular is by new users with a rep of 1 or close to this.  I've never seen misuse by users over 20.  Different tags could have different thresholds. It could be easily analysed by looking at logs to see which tags are misapplied by which rep users.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280215/locking-bad-tags

Comment: Heh... [red] + [hat] = [redhat]. I like the way he thinks.

Comment: @MrLister I can't find other examples because we normally retag these questions, but it's a task that is best suited for a policy.

Comment: Related: [Display a popup when a low-reputation user tags a question with a frequently-misused tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347903/display-a-popup-when-a-low-reputation-user-tags-a-question-with-a-frequently-mis)

Comment: @EJoshuaS interesting. That question deals with the same problem and gets agreement by upvoting, but no one agrees with my solution which actually stops low rep users from misusing tags. A pop-up doesn't work because these users don't read anything!

Comment: @servy there are 21,000 uses of the [table] rendering it useless. That tag is poorly named as well. Are you suggesting that all tags and questions that are misused/mistagged be renamed and retagged?

Comment: A little pop-up will work with proper explanation! like Professor Samuel Oak  told us :"First, Whats is your tag? >Red >Ash >Jack"

Comment: @GrahamChiu If a tag is poorly named, and is consistently misused as a result, and there's a much better name that would resolve that problem, then yes, it should be renamed.  If the tag is regularly misused but there isn't any good alternative names, then that may not be an option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main problem that I see with this is that some new users might legitimately have questions pertaining to that tag. For example, [the Android-Studio and Visual-Studio tags are heavily misused](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/346150/how-should-we-deal-with-people-misusing-the-visual-studio-and-android-studio) (they're supposed to be for questions about the tools themselves, not for general programming questions), but what do we do in a case where a new user *actually* has a question pertaining to, for example, Android Studio? Do we not allow them to submit the question, or do we force them to use an irrelevant tag?

I have a [proposal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347903/display-a-popup-when-a-low-reputation-user-tags-a-question-with-a-frequently-mis) to show a popup when a low-rep user tags a question with a frequently-misused tag. This is already being done for certain tags (e.g. the burniate-request tag on Meta) so it seems logical to extend this to other tags as well. It actually worked for me - when I went to tag something with that, I realized that I should read the documentation the popup mentioned before I used the tag (which I did).

Comment: I upvoted your answer as I agree something should be done. My suggestion is just a little more draconian. I'm just a little curious also as to how these questions are getting past the review queue with their mistagging intact.

Comment: @GrahamChiu I do agree that something should be done promptly. The abuse of certain tags is widespread enough that it's impractical to have us edit the tags out after the fact (or to try to do it in the review queue). The fact that so many people are misusing them [seems like a "broken window"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258263/does-the-broken-window-theory-apply-to-closing-questions?noredirect=1&lq=1) (i.e. the fact that other people are doing it makes it look like it's ok and that we'll tolerate the behavior).