# Vote retraction statements

Tags: feature-request, voting, retracted-close-votes

I recently encountered an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29716497/2747515) that I thought was off-topic. A small discussion with the author (poster?) showed me that it was, in fact, a good answer.

The problem arose when I tried to upvote the answer, which I found myself unable to do as my downvote had been locked. As a beginner, I frequently find myself in such situations where I am eventually proven otherwise, especially when it comes to conceptual questions.

My proposed solution is to allow the member to retract their vote by manually stating why they have done so. The same as manually explaining why a question should be closed, but applied to vote-retraction instead.

If this statement were viewable to everyone  (like the edit history), I feel that it could help other members dispel their own doubts regarding an answer, and (optimistically) learn something new.

Comment: Um, this seems to be getting a lot of downvotes. Could someone explain why?

Comment: _"Could someone explain why?"_ Low research efforts.

Comment: Votes are different on Meta, see the [FAQ](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/259918).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may overcome this hurdle with +2k rep. You are able to [edit the answer then (without further review acceptance)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit), clarifying it and retract your downvote (and even upvote) afterwards. Otherwise, you'll have to propose such edit, and wait until it's accepted.