# Would a "symbolic link" feature for answers be useful?

Tags: discussion

https://stackoverflow.com/a/31091939/1497139

is an answer that I posted multiple times. One copy of this answer was deleted with a comment that it would be more sensible to flag the question as a duplicate.

I assume the motivation of this is to avoid some redundancy. I think that having something like a "Symbolic link" between answers would be more helpful /useful more often than not.

Sometimes questions are not fully the same and therefore not true duplicates. Still the answer might fit multiple questions. A simple "see ..." is not as useful as showing a symbolic copy of the original answer. That way only one spot needs to be edited and is the official "answer" that can be edited and improved. Multiple questions may have a useful link to such an answer so that stackoverflow users won't have to click to find out how valuable the answer is.

**What do you think?**

Comment: The redundancy is in the *questions*. If you can answer multiple questions with the same answer, chances are very high that the questions should be closed as dupes instead. 'symbolic link' answers would still clutter the site with those duplicate questions.

Comment: I assume the downvotes are "this is a bad idea" responses. This doesn't necessarily mean that this is a bad discussion topic ...

Comment: Yes, see the [Meta FAQ](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/259917/how-does-meta-stack-overflow-work/259918#259918); people are voting on your proposal.

Answer (score 4):

The most interesting scenario here is that involving questions which are not duplicates; that is, multiple *distinct problems* which happen to share an identical *solution.*

In these cases, I prefer answers which clearly explain why an answer to a previous question applies, and *then link to the answer*.

For example: [Answer A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209732/why-am-i-seeing-inconsistent-javascript-logic-behavior-looping-with-an-alert-v/210077#210077) and [Answer B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894696/why-is-the-javascript-regexp-test-method-behaving-as-a-toggle/894715#894715).

The advantage over a "symlink" here is that this allows answers to be tailored to the question. If an answer to a different question requires no introduction or explanation, there is a very good chance that the question *is* a duplicate and should be closed and perhaps even merged.

#### See also: [Create CW answer for every "Vote to close as duplicate" vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198958/create-cw-answer-for-every-vote-to-close-as-duplicate-vote)

Comment: in these cases, an option worth considering is a [meta-tag:canonical] question to cover a whole _class_ of questions that can be addressed by the same answer

Comment: "allows answers to be tailored to the question" I can hear an entire category of users being triggered by this.

Comment: Not every answer that solves 2 or three problems is worth expanding into some lumbering FAQ, @gnat. In fact, I'd argue the latter scenario is exceedingly rare in comparison to the former... But even if it wasn't, there's such an insane difference in work required to write a comprehensive, generic answer and find + close scores of questions vs. writing a paragraph + link that it's a bit naive to expect the latter to actually *happen* on a regular basis. See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198958/create-cw-answer-for-every-dup (an idea I still think wins in practicality).

Comment: agree, that's why I mentioned it only as "an option worth considering"

Comment: Noted - fair point.