# Could the [remove] tag be allowed for all users?

Tags: discussion

I tried to make a question recently that related to removing things from a list in C#. I was able to get an answer, but I found it strange that "remove" was reserved for high rep people. I understand it could be used for deleting/removing unneeded, but it is a relevant tag for some users issues!

Perhaps a change of tag for unwanted questions could be made. What are yall's thoughts?

Comment: That tag doesn't exist, and [only users with 1.5k or more can create new tags.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags) This is why you can't use that tag.

Comment: Related: [When is tag creation appropriate, and how does it work?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252944/when-is-tag-creation-appropriate-and-how-does-it-work)

Comment: Ahh makes sense! Thanks guys.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Tags are not reserved, for any rep level, except for the [red moderator-only tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/259917/how-does-meta-stack-overflow-work/259970#259970) here on Meta.

You are probably told you cannot *create* a tag; that requires a [minimum amount of reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags).

That's because there is no [remove](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/remove) tag, nor should there be; it'd be a meta tag that doesn't cover one specific subject. Tags are used by people to find questions to answer, but no one would follow the [remove](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/remove) tag, as it would be used for a broad range of questions. As such, if someone ever were to create such a tag it'll end up being removed again, a process jokingly referred to as burnination, see [burninate-request](/questions/tagged/burninate-request).

Instead, stick to existing, relevant tags, and use the word *remove* in your question title if it is important to your question.

Comment: Ah ha! Makes sense enough. Thanks for the input!