# Unsynchronized reputation in SO Meta and SO

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, reputation, meta

I have my reputation on SO Meta and SO displayed differently. I have found on the FAQ that it is synchronized. I have tried refreshing many times, but no changes. In my profile also I find the difference. Is it usual that it takes a lot of time to for the reputation to be synchronized (though I have not faced such an issue before).

I have tried searching my best to find if some else had had this problem before.

I cant find how I should be editing it to make you understand that i am not asking about how META SO works. I was asking is there a delay in the synchronization. And it has been commented it takes hours

Comment: "a lot of time", 20 minutes is not a lot of time. The synchronization typically happens on the order of hours.

Comment: OH ok.. I usually have seen it being synchronized just at the same time. So was confused.

Comment: Specifically, [this answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/259917/how-does-meta-stack-overflow-work/272450#272450).

Comment: "synchronized once an hour", and you're complaining about a change of 2 rep from less than twenty minutes ago  when you posted this post.

Comment: whatever the reputation change maybe, i never knew there was a waiting time of more than an hour because i never came across this situation..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Meta reputation is synchronized every hour.

I agree that this delay is badly documented. There is no obviously visible indication that there is an hour's waiting period. Most of the Meta discussion states that "rep is now synchronized".