# Why is the bounty grace period so short?

Tags: support, bounty

When I set a bounty on my questions I usually receive the answer I was looking for about an hour before the bounty elapsed.
That leaves me with only 24 hours to check if the answer was actually what I was looking for.

The thing is, you can't always tell if an answer is correct or helpful just by reading it. Sometimes you need to set up a huge special test environment and do a lot of coding on your own before you can even give it a try.

24 hours simply isn't enough. (Especially if you're the scapegoat that has to work overtime every time something goes wrong at work.)
And I feel ready bad every time I notice that a user posted a great answer, after the bounty was auto-awarded.

A whole week would seem way more reasonable to me.

So why is it the way it is? Am I misunderstanding the system?

EDIT:
Just to mention some things that can happen and make you unvailable for 24 hours or more (and yes I know most of you probably live in the US, but there are other countries where some of these things can happen on a weekly basis):

- being sick
- working overtime
- mourning
- broken PC
- car accident
- flight cancelled
- blackout
- Internet connection down
- severe (thunder)storm alert
- air raid

and yes some of them are more likely to happen than others....

Comment: If 24 hours is too short, that's a strong indicator your question actually was too broad, or concentrated on a too specific, localized problem.

Comment: Another week is not a "grace period". The word definition is `esp. an extended period granted as a special favor`

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ You haven't read my whole question. My boss sometimes decides that I have to work overtime, meaning I have literally no time at all for more than 24 hours. A scenario like this is not a rare thing where I work: Sleep 8h, eat & go to work 1.5h, work 8.5h, work overtime 6h, go home and eat 1.5h, sleep 6.5h, eat & go to work 1.5h, work 8.5h, go home and eat 1.5h... This makes me pretty much unavailable for almost two days.

Comment: Why the down votes this is a legit question to ask.

Comment: @Forivin Downvotes on meta often indicate disagreement, in this case probably with the assertion that the grace period is too short. It can be tough to guess, best just to ignore them and concentrate on the issue

Comment: @Forivin But your working time conditions have nothing to do with bounty grace periods?? How should this coincide?

Comment: @Clive How can you disagree with a question? It's not like I made a feature request.

Comment: Hmm, not that much in asking for help when you don't have the time to actually use it.  The company will gladly help you with that problem as well, [go here](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ My working time conditions are just an example, I can think of a million things that could render you unavailable for 24 hours. My point is: The chance that people aren't available during the 24 hours grace period is not high enough.

Comment: @HansPassant Yeah right, I get a new job so that can award my bounties on SO. I don't think so...

Comment: You're suggesting the grace period is too short, people are possibly disagreeing. I haven't voted either way, just letting you know what happens with votes on meta

Comment: Well, your post supposes that the limit is too short, and is thus an implicit request to make it longer. If you dialed back hard on that, it *might* not have been read as a feature-request. Maybe. No guarantee. Anyway, if you have read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/259917/how-does-meta-stack-overflow-work you should know that there's no reputation here, far less to vote on, and thus much stronger voting.

Comment: So you are voting on my opinion? That's ridiculous. My opinion should have nothing to do with the voting on my question. I barely even mentioned anything that you could call my opinion. I just asked a question and gave half a dozen points for why 24 hour may not be enough.

Comment: The title of this question is *loaded* with opinion. I strongly disagree the grace period is short, let alone "so short"...

Comment: So what you are doing is this: Read the question, interpret my wording to extract my opinion and then use the voting system to vote on my opinion. My opinion should have absolutely nothing to do with the voting system! I have my opinion for a reason and besides the fact that voting on my opinion is nothing more than discrimination, it doesn't help anyone.

Comment: Users are supposed to vote on peoples' opinions, this is meta. You just haven't been around here long enough to know that yet, so it seems weird. You'll get used to it if you spend some time here

Comment: @Clive Where does it say that you should vote on peoples opinions?

Comment: It's just culture, I doubt it's written down anywher official, if that's what you mean. The fact you're so confused and outraged by the voting here makes it obvious you're not familiar with how voting works on meta. I'm just trying to bridge the gap, if you don't believe me that's fine

Comment: And how is that not against the rules??

Comment: Which rules? I'm not going to keep labouring this point, I've explained several times how it is, it's completely up to you whether you take that information on or not. You need to realise you weren't the first person here: this site and its cultures have been around for longer than you've had an issue with bounties. Suck it up or go home is my advice, no good can come of raging against this particular insignificant machine

Comment: There are cultures on earth that dismember women. Something being a part of culture is no excuse at all. People have different opinions and for every opinion there is a logical reason. Voting on someones opinion is a sign of very considerable intolerance and discrimination and is ethically unacceptable if you ask me.

Comment: Wow, you're comparing down votes with dismembering women now? That's the most ridiculous one I've ever heard, even on meta where we get your kind of malcontent fairly often. In case it's not obvious, I'm not going to dignify that sort of drivel with a response. Have fun in your own little world, I'm out

Comment: Cute, do you feel offended or why are you trying to insult me? Feel free to come up with a better way of explaining why culture isn't always right. Maybe by then you have finally realized how stupid it is to quibble about irrelevant details instead of just talking about the actual topic.

Comment: This place is like Nazi Germany...  24 hours IS TOO SHORT.  There shouldn't even be a debate about it.... they are YOUR reputation points..  YOU should be able to award the bounty when YOU see fit!

Comment: I agree. 24 hours is way too short. What if the bounty expires over the weekend? What if I have a personal emergency? Or an unexpected business trip? I think that one week would be a better time period.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple matter of setting priorities.  Programmers normally measure by dollars or hours, neither tends to be important factors when you ask for help at SO.  Questioners rarely spend more than an hour on a question and of course an answer from a professional programmer who normally costs a hundred+ dollars per hours doesn't cost you anything.

So somewhat inevitably, following up an answer tends to be rated as a low priority task.  That's fine, nobody can force you to bump it up and the community is quite capable of rating answers by themselves without your help.  The bounty is auto-awarded if necessary.  That happens quite often.

Increasing the grace period merely lowers the priority you'll assign to the task.  Nice for you perhaps, it does absolutely nothing positive for everybody else that's involved in the Q+A.

The only lasting consequence of not awarding bounties yourself is that the *next* time you ask a question, the same programmer that helped you before might be less inclined to invest his free time.  You tend to notice in general by the number of responses to your questions trailing off over time, both in volume and quality.  If you see it happen then you'll know why it happened.  I have seen it happen.  The only ways to compensate by then is to invest more hours in asking a good question or spending more time helping other programmers so you can spend the earned rep on bounties.  Finding the balance is up to you, you set your own priorities.

Comment: I don't understand your priority talk. What has this to do with setting priorities? I mentioned quite a few things that simply render you unable to award the bounty no matter how high you would set the priority to do so. The auto awarding system just doesn't work at all, after other answers already got a few up-votes, when the correct answer gets posted in the last second. Let's say you created a bounty because the answers were outdated, how is the system supposed to auto-award correctly? I mean most users just don't even bother to scroll down to vote on new answers.

Comment: Increasing the period will do way more than changing some priority. How it the priority thing even relevant? I mean the worst case really is that people will award the bounty in the last second and I don't see how that would be bad? Seriously I see way more advantages to it. It gives me more time to think about which answer is best. I don't have to award the bounty under pressure (I hear people tend to do almost anything worse under pressure). The chances that auto-award will award the bounty to the wrong person will be way lower and thus the number of people getting disappointed decreases.

Answer (score -1):

As already mentioned in my comment, if some Q&A cannot be easily validated within 24(!)hours, that's a strong indicator that either something's seriously wrong with the question, or the answer isn't clear enough.

I'm used to decide such within a few minutes, when viewing a question and answers that fit my field of expertise.

I can't imagine any case where such Q&A could be helpful for any future research, but just to solve your very particular, personal problem.

Comment: Again, what if you are simply unavailable for more than 24 hours? If you want I can add even more examples to the question.

Comment: @Forivin Well, not all of the answers to a bounty come streaming in within the last 24 hours it was running? At least the majority won't.

Comment: It probably depends on the kind of question you ask and how high you set the bounty. For my bounties I'd say it happened 50% of the time.