# StackExchange Drop-Down is giving me more Reputation than I actually got

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, stack-exchange

Today I noticed that the StackExchange drop-down is showing more reputation for my StackOverflow account than I actually got. This bug is also observable in the Stack Exchange iPhone app.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/259917/how-does-meta-stack-overflow-work), especially [this answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/259917/how-does-meta-stack-overflow-work/272450#272450).

Comment: As mentioned the drop-down was showing a higher score for Stack Overflow (230) than I actually got on Stack Overflow (215 - upper right corner). I did neither gain nor loose any reputation in the meantime...

Answer (score 5):

Give it 10 or so minutes. Your Meta reputation is identical to your main site reputation, with latency given due to caching.

Given that your main site reputation now lists 215 as well, I would presume that you lost about 15 rep, which didn't make its way over to Meta due to the latency in its cache.

Comment: Actually the screenshot is showing the StackOverflow reputation on the top right. I did not loose or gain any reputation above 215 (till now). However drop-down and phone app are **now** showing 215 reputation again. Maybe there has been a hiccup this morning...