# How to make >2K users make better edits

Tags: discussion, edits

Let me start off by saying I do not know an answer to this question and that is why I have tagged it as discussion.

A lot of the time I come across an edit made by a >2k user that just makes one simple change to a badly formatted post. The post will then be edited multiple times by different >2k users only changing minor things in the post. This issue only ever gets fixed when a <2k user comes a long, and because their edit gets reviewed, they change everything that is needed with the post.

I'll also say this is not always the case. It is just something I happen to see quite a lot.

Without calling the meta effect please, the latest example of this is here:

[I want to show a hidden object on form 1 from form 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38326473/i-want-to-show-a-hidden-object-on-form-1-from-form-2)

The edits in order:

1. Formatted the code
2. Added a new line for readability reasons
3. Edited tags, but didn't change all of the tags appropriately

At the time of writing I have suggested an edit. This one changes the language tag correctly, asks the actual question needed and formats some grammar and code inline. I realise I probably should have edited the title to be a bit clearer, but if I'm honest I just forgot to do that.

NOTE: I know this question is a duplicate and poor quality, but I am editing it mainly as a good example for this question.

Is there a way we can police or restrict edits by >2k users when they continually make minimal changes to a post while leaving a lot of stuff, that needs to be, unchanged?

**EDIT**

The general consensus on whether or not minor edits are good seems to fall into two main categories:

1. Users >2k rep. Would prefer full edits from <2k users, but any edit no matter how small from a >2k user
2. Users <2k rep. Would prefer everyone to make full and complete edits. Just because your edit doesn't go into a queue doesn't mean you shouldn't do a complete edit.

The wasting reviewers time argument doesn't float with me. If a reviewer is happy to reject an edit that doesn't fix everything in the post then they shouldn't make minor edits. This is because it then wastes other users' time to fix everything else wrong with the post.

An idea that just came to me could be leaving peoples' edits to be reviewed when they have <N number of edits approved and ignore the rep threshold completely.

Comment: I am guilty of this.  By way of explanation I tend to quickly edit things that I see that annoy me, I wouldn't sit and try to make the whole thing perfect.

Comment: @McNab But that's the main point why force people to learn to do one thing, change everything, when as soon as they get >2k its completely fine not to. It should be one rule for everyone, and >2k users should be showing <2k users how to edit properly, not the other way around.

Comment: Every minor change to a post is good and shouldn't be discouraged in my opinion. I often just edit to add some missing tags or do minor edits for the worst formatting problems. I can't be arsed to fix an entire post just because the asker was too lazy to do it :-)

Comment: @AlexanderDerck Then why force <2k users to do that? Whenever a disputed suggested edit comes up a main opinion is because it didn't fix the entire post. Then why is it completely reasonable for a >2k user to only do minor edits. This consensus seems backward and only that way because >2k users are usually more active on meta.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder As Glorfindel says in his answer, it would take up too much review time (+ they get reputation from it, it would be too easy to farm by just adding tags etc.)

Comment: ... You'll see when you become a >2k rep user. :) nice initiative though.

Comment: @AlexanderDerck You can only get 1000 rep from edits, I believe, and taking up too much review time is the wrong opinion. We shouldn't be arguing against <2k users making minor edits, we should be arguing for >2k users to make complete edits

Comment: @AlexanderDerck It should be not be allowed for anyone to make one word edits. The users should be asked to format code/question in comments if needed very badly. Its waste of time for multiple people otherwise

Comment: @TheLethalCoder Forcing 2k+ users to make good edits won't make them improve their edits, it would probably just stop many of them doing any edits at all.

Comment: @AlexanderDerck exactly. I'd actually stop me from doing the occasional code formatting.

Comment: @Shark Having many people doing minor edits takes up more time, if you make grammar changes in five posts, and then five other people come a long and each fix a different aspect of the post then each of you could have done a proper edit to begin with in the same amount of time. Your editing ideals is pure laziness and shows <2k users that this is how it should be when they are >2k

Comment: But on the other hand, talking about 10 people fixing each other's grammar is also a waste of time... I'm glad you people enjoy doing it but guiltblaming me that I don't inspire <2k users to be perfect lectors/editors is a moot point. You like and enjoy editing? Fine. I like running into interesting problems and helping people out (aka solving them before I run into them). But to get back on point - I really could care less how your editing habits will change when you reach >2k imaginary internet points.

Comment: Could this issue not be solved by lowering the 2k bar to 1k? I feel a little uneasy suggesting this as I don't even have 1k reputation.
Also, @AkshanshThakur, I would be slow to not allow one-word edits, as sometimes that word may be the most pivotal word in the whole post, for example, the difference between "Generating a list of lists in Haskell" and "Generating a list of lists in Haksell".

Comment: @gkubed A better guideline would be on number of accepted suggested edits and not rep at all

Comment: @TheLethalCoder I think *some* incentive is necessary, else we may see edits disappear altogether. I wouldn't be against the reputation being decreased to +1 though. Why would you limit number of accepted suggested edits?

Comment: You are aware >2k users no longer get reputation for making edits @gkubed ?

Comment: @Draken, *that* makes more sense, thank you. I just thought >2k users' edits didn't require approval. I would imagine most low reputation users are unaware of this - also meaning that low reputation users don't look to high reputation users' edits as examples (which I never have, personally).

Comment: Lol, this is what I don't understand... why would this question get so many downvotes? Do people downvote when they are angry or when question is bad? I don't feel that this question is bad at all

Comment: @AkshanshThakur As another user told me before, when I posted in meta, "And before you say anything about the downvotes here: welcome to Meta..."

Comment: @AkshanshThakur http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/259917/how-does-meta-stack-overflow-work/259918#259918

Comment: @LisaMM thank you, I was just having a laugh :)  I have seen this down-vote pattern on meta a lot.

Answer (score 33):

Well, the consensus seems to be that [minor edits are good](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253326/too-minor-edits-better-to-leave-poor-quality-on-the-site). However, the main problem with minor edits by <2k-users is that they take up too much reviewers' time - that's why they are (sometimes) rejected. Five minor edits by <2k-users take at least 15 reviews, the time which could be spent improving other posts. (Granted, reviewing an edit takes less time than editing itself, and a lot of reviewers blindly approve everything which is not spam – but that's another discussion.) It *could* be – but this is speculation on my side – that reviewers think they should be doing more for the +2 reputation they get from an approved edit. Heck, a couple of weeks ago we had a user who searched for question titles containing the word `andoid` (sic), corrected the spelling and left all other easy-to-spot spelling mistakes alone. Such an edit spree is *not* the way to earn trust from the community (because that is what reputation really is).

Note that when you edit a post as a <2k-user, you're explicitly warned about making too minor edits (emphasis mine):

> We welcome all constructive edits, **but please make them substantial.** Avoid trivial edits unless absolutely necessary.

This message is *not* shown to >2k-users; in fact, I almost forgot about its existence. It is not shown (probably on purpose) to >2k-users, who have in-page editing capabilities, so we can't enforce them to make substantial edits. Sometimes, fixing the formatting already improves the question enough to make it answerable, even though it contains grammatical mistakes. The user fixing the formatting might not be proficient enough in English to fix the grammar as well.

I don't do much edits (on Stack Overflow) myself anymore, but sometimes I see an answer/question and I don't have enough time to make a thorough edit. There's nothing wrong if I just remove the 'Thanks' at the bottom of the post. Maybe if it is a very old post that doesn't deserve bumping to the front page, but it will be gone soon with the current amount of new questions.

Comment: "minor edits by <2k-users is that they take up too much reviewers' time" This statement is vague and opinionated. I would rather have one good edit approved rather than 5 one word edits. Rules must be same for everyone. Higher reputation should not give you a privilege to make edits recklessly, edits must only be valuable.

Comment: @AkshanshThakur Completely agree >2k users should be setting an example not being lazy

Comment: Regarding the edit I'd rather no one got any rep if everyone had to edit properly, we should all be striving to make complete edits, not four or five lazy people making minor edits until the post looks okay.

Comment: Regarding the new update, that just seems even more backward now. We should not have one rule for one and another for others, and judging by the comments on the OP it is because people are just too lazy to do a complete edit when they know it won't be checked.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder It's not a matter of laziness. Minor edits are good. It's just that the review process takes time. And it's a waste of time to have three reviewers for a retag.

Comment: @Blackus But then those three reviewers are okay that others have to come back to, to fix the post. The wasting reviewers time argument doesn't float with me. If a reviewer will not accept a suggested edit that doesn't fix the post then why do a minor edit that others have to come back to, to fix?

Comment: @TheLethalCoder I guess it's kind of *educational*: "Do not make minor edits when you're <2k". Rejecting minor edits is here to discourage this behavior, because reviewer time is precious to evaluate edits by "inexperienced" - not the best word to illustrate my thought - users that make edits.

Comment: @Blackus I think that's the main point, inexperienced, a >2k user might have made no edits before yet the are blindly allowed to make edits without review

Comment: **The user fixing the formatting might not be proficient enough in English to fix the grammar as well.** => As a non-native speaker, I regularly refrain from modifying a sentence because I am not sure whether what I perceive as weird is actually idiomatic or not. I prefer to make only "obvious" changes and avoid more subjective ones (it also diminishes the chances of the edit being roll backed).

Comment: @TheLethalCoder Yeah but by reaching 2k, you *know* what is a correct edit and what is not. And if a bad edit is made, there's a way to reverse it.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder: Agreed on experience; and I'll also add "changes" to the mix. The rules for what is a good post have changed many times over since I started.

Comment: @Blackus: No, you don't. I reached 2k in 2008/2009, and the rules were quite different (much more informal) by then.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Yes, and? I don't see a lot of bad edits from >2k users. Even if they reached 2k 8 years ago. The system seems to works quite good. Even if the improvements are minor, are we really going to blame editors because they improved something?

Comment: @Blackus a user on another thread about edits said he specifically waited with edits until he was >2k because he didn't agree with anyone reviewing his. There are several ways of gaining rep, most have nothing to do with editing.

Comment: *Rules must be same for everyone.* That's incorrect. The entire rep system here is built around the idea that being deemed trustworthy means you get privileges other users don't.

Comment: @BSMP Not really. many 2k+ users on SO never edited a single answer and got this privilege by giving a couple good answers... That doesnt seem to be very fair.

Comment: @AkshanshThakur How is it unfair that some people who came and gave good answers got some reputation? Isn't that the whole idea of the site, to show who has the knowledge and can provide information as and when required? As long as we're providing good information, I don't see an issue

Comment: @Draken Nope. you are putting words in my mouth. I am making a point that getting 2k rep ins't an indicator of your editing skills. Please refrain from manipulating logic :) I don't appreciate that.

Comment: @AkshanshThakur Ah, that makes it clearer. So it sounds like you want a separate control if people haven't edited before, going on previous track record. E.g. If a user has had a positive editing record, they can do more edits in a day? Interesting. Work quite similar to the flag raising, however that would increase the edit queue quite a lot, as it requires further moderation of a lot of users. Not sure on other people's ideas on that though

Comment: *That doesnt seem to be very fair.* Why not? Everyone gets the same amount of rep from up voted answers. If you want to get edit privileges without making edits you can do that too.

Comment: @BSMP you didn't get my point. Please read carefully above

Comment: @AkshanshThakur Disagreement is not the same thing as misunderstanding.

Comment: @BSMP cool (y).

Comment: @AkshanshThakur: *That doesnt seem to be very fair* => who said reputation was about fairness? Reputation is about trust; high-reputation users are supposed to know how things work and are trusted accordingly (and empowered accordingly). In this case, they are simply expected to have seen a sufficiently high number of posts, and contributed a sufficiently high number of posts themselves, to know what to aim for.

Comment: @MatthieuM. okay, thanks! I understand.

Comment: One more argument in favor of minor edits: at 10k, you get the [inline tag editing](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) privilege, which lets you make quick tag edits *even faster*.

Answer (score 2):

**Minor edits are good**

Any change that improves a post is good:

- they help ensuring that the post is more easily understandable
- they help ensuring that the question is more easily answered
- ...

Of course, if the editor could fix *all* issues at once it would be *better*, but let's not make *better the enemy of good*. Much like the Agile movement in software development, much like the Blank Page syndrome authors face, we should favor tiny progress over immobility (due to indecision).

**Minor edits are necessary**

It should be noted that getting *all* the fixes done in one edit is infeasible.

Improvements are generally *less and less* important, with the bigger gains coming from earlier edits and subsequent edits addressing things that were missed, are subjective and required discussion, etc...

The capacity to make small edits to polish a post is necessary to get polished posts.

Additionally, it is also necessary for all non-native/poor English speakers to be able to help: they can easily indent code and re-format a post, but cannot fix the grammar/spelling.

---

So, why are >2K users not held to the same standard as the <2K users?

Education with minimal costs.

<2K users are held to high standard so as to teach them good habits at a minimal cost for the community.

Minor edits are not a problem in themselves, the problem is teaching at a premium, and allowing minor edits from those users being taught is both:

- a lost opportunity for teaching (showing early what to edit and what not to, what to aim for, ...)
- a cost to the community (reviewers)

The idea of having a restricted set of permissions to start with, and increasingly more permissions as you gain trust from others is at the heart of SO (and a lot of social groups); I see minor edits in the same vein as tags creation, etc... in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

> This is because it then wastes other users time to fix everything else wrong with the post.

That's not exactly true, at least not in the same way that it wastes reviewers time to look at minor suggested edits.

Suggested edits *have* to get reviewed or they never get applied to the post. If the folks in the review queue all decided they didn't feel like reviewing any more it would effectively be impossible to suggest edits. A similar problem would occur if they were flooded by minor edits.

However, nothing actually *has* to happen after an edit that isn't reviewed first. No one has to step in and take action unless the edit defaces the post. It does not break the system in any way.

You do not have to edit a post that was edited, but not completely fixed, by a high rep user. If you feel that it is a waste of your time, you are free to skip it. Maybe the OP fixes it themselves, maybe they get down view instead. But the system doesn't come to a screeching halt.

To put it another way, consider all the users who vote on answers but not questions (or vice versa, out on some answers but not all). They are not doing a thorough job moderating the quality of the posts. But we don't require people to vote on all the posts on the page. *Some* moderation is still better than none.