# Rep loss due to deletion of a year old post I edited

Tags: discussion, edits, reputation, deleted-questions, reputation-history

**I thought old rep (> 60 days) was supposed to be exempt** from being deducted when old posts are deleted.  Is this incorrect?  Where can I find documentation for this?

Details:

On 3rd September I incurred a loss of 8 reputation due to removal of posts, see [this screenshot of my reputation changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELUoV.png). Since I have been above 2,000 reputation for months, these must have been old posts.

Someone dug up the [cordova post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32268689/cordova-callback-to-orientationlock) for me, I edited it on 28th August 2015, it was indeed deleted on 3rd September 2016 by community as `RemoveAbandonedQuestions`. So far so good.

The problem is that I lost reputation due to the removal of this post. I thought that shouldn't happen when a post is more than 60 days old when it is deleted (or deleted more than 60 days after the edit), but I can't find anything on that in the help centre.

Comment: Yes, this is supposed to work like this.

Comment: Remember to upvote good questions so this doesn't happen ;)

Comment: Sorry, but you asked this question because of 8 rep points?  That's not even one upvote.

Comment: @JK. I couldn't care less about 8 reputation. I was in the understanding that all rep was exempt from loss after 60 days, hence the question.

Comment: @JK., obviously the OP is asking about how the system works - not the couple of points per se.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The post has a score of lower than 3, so the loss of reputation is [as designed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7238/295232):

> Deleting and undeleting posts may reverse reputation effects as well, if these posts have votes. Actions previously taken on deleted posts cease to affect reputation within five minutes ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/recent-reputation-history-changes)), unless the post meets both the following criteria (in which case the reputation effects will be permanent) ([source](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/reputation-and-historical-archives/)):
>
> - The post had a score of at least +3
> - The post has been visible on the site for at least 60 days

Comment: Why would the score of a question affect whether the reputation earned from editing it will be permanent or not?

Comment: @ayhan it's in the linked blog: *if you've contributed something worthwhile to the site, you should keep the reputation for that even if it eventually gets deleted.*

Comment: So an edit is *more worthwhile* if the question has a higher score?

Comment: @ayhan I (and maybe the SE devs) hadn't thought of edits; I think this exception was primarily targeted at reputation earned by upvotes.

Comment: @ayhan if a post does not earn a proper score (chosen to be +3) and didn't get an answer in a year, apparently it's not content that's worthwhile to keep around, hence the deletion. Whether an edit on such a post was worthwhile though, is difficult to determine. My edit was accepted, so I assume I did something useful. I couldn't of course foresee that the question would be deleted, so whether or not I *should* incur a rep loss for that is a different discussion I'd say.

Comment: If a post however gets deleted within 60 days, it did not uphold the SO standard for a good question. The potential editor should see this and take appropriate action (e.g. flag it). If (s)he does edit, it's seen as a not worthwhile contribution, since the post is deleted very soon afterwards. In that case the "punishment" of loosing the 2 rep gained through editing is perfectly justified in my opinion. For the `RemovedAbandonedQuestions`, I'm not sure. Might open a new meta about that.

Comment: One could argue that a post that doesn't reach +3 over a year might be more likely to be a 'turd', and the edit was *more likely to be* 'polishing a turd'.  Certainly not certainly, but with a greater probability.  And given the really really small scale of the "punishment", does it matter that much?

Comment: @Yakk, That *really* depends on the traffic in the tags attached to the question. While it might be more likely at <+3, it is not certain.

Comment: Does this rule and standard apply to all the exchange sites? Because some of the sites are very worthwhile, have decent traffic, and will never have a lot of posts that are 3 or above.

Comment: @ouflak yes, it does. Stack Overflow does have a certain number of special rules, being the largest SE site by far, but this isn't one of them.

Answer (score 12):

The mechanism of not losing reputation when a post is deleted only accounts for answers, specifically answers that are older then 60 days and have a score of +3 or higher.

> First, if you've contributed something worthwhile to the site, you
> should keep the reputation for that even if it eventually gets
> deleted. "Worthwhile" here is defined as,
>
> - A score of 3 or greater
> - Visible on the site for at least 60 days

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/reputation-and-historical-archives/

Failing that, the normal rules apply, specifically

> You lose reputation when:
>
> [...]
>
> - a post where you had successfully suggested an edit has been deleted (reputation page shows the cause as "removed"): -2

https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7238

Comment: Only answers? Citation needed.

Comment: Now, I feel insulted by that blog post (not your post @Magisch). > 90% of my answers are not considered "Worthwhile" (due to primarily being on low traffic tags). Sounds like I should stop providing any content which is not "Worthwhile" to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score -6):

As a new user, I tend to edit posts for grammar and spelling (which I am very good at) rather than contribute to answers (I am still very inexperienced as a Developer). It appears a little harsh to lose reputation when the edit was in good faith, and was peer reviewed and allowed - indicating it was a useful contribution.

Comment: This is a comment about rep loss, not an answer to the question (which is asking why it happened)

Comment: The idea is, if a post is deleted, your edit is no longer useful, so you don't get to keep the rep you earned from it, except under special circumstances. Why should different rules apply to editors than apply to the posters themselves? One way to minimize the potential rep loss is only to edit posts that are likely to stick around. You'll see this colloquially referred to as not "editing turds". A bit crude, perhaps, but apt.

Comment: It's quite harsh that this got 5 down votes. It was an innocent observation couched in soft language. I appreciate the clarification but smacking me with negativity is not that friendly a way to handle a new user still trying to find their way around.

Comment: See [What do votes mean on Meta?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/259918/5764553). You have not lost any reputation. Soft language is nice (please keep that up), but people may still disagree with what you say or may think your answer isn't useful to the question, and that's when you get downvotes. Try not to see it as "smacking you with negativity". Five people disagreed, and two people left comments that can help you see things differently. That's _constructive_ criticism.