# What is the motivation to edit posts that are likely to be flagged/removed?

Tags: discussion, edits, reputation

I've edited many posts that were subsequently removed resulting in a loss of reputation attributed to those edits.

In general I'm now much more hesitant to even bother editing posts that I suspect will eventually be removed but it seems like insult to injury when you lose reputation gained from a useful edit after the post is removed (sometimes months afterwards). On smaller edits, it's not a big deal, but lengthier edits take a bit of time.

If we can't at least retain the reputation points (however trivial) for the approved edit if the post is removed, I don't see much motivation for doing so, the content won't be around so at best it's *temporarily* improving the quality. Maybe this is by design to discourage turd polishing.

Should I even bother editing posts that I have a more than minimal chance of being removed either by the community or user?

What is the reasoning behind taking back reputation gained through approved edits if the post is removed by the user?

Comment: The reason is to not reward turd polishing.  I can see an argument for locking in the edit rep after 60 days like we do for other posts, though; if it stuck around that long it probably wasn't a turd.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom Good point, if a post is removed within a short period of time then it likely wasn't worth editing in the first place. I feel as though in the case of posts that are deleted by the user (for whatever reason not necessarily downvotes) much later, reputation should be retained.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Reputation reflects *lasting* impact on the site. Deleted posts are not generally visible on the site and hence all reputation associated with such posts (downvotes, upvotes, points for edits) is removed*.

The only motivation to edit posts that in they current state are on track to be removed is to make post clearly on-topic and of reasonable quality. If you can't make such edit it is better to let OP to improve post first to the point it meets site's quality bar and then improve more if needed. To see more discussions search for [turd polish](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=turd+polish).

---

<sub>* reputation from votes on old (60+ days) posts with positive (3+ score) is preserved when post is deleted. I don't know if there is a similar rule for edits.</sub>

Comment: *"The only motivation to edit posts that in they current state are on track to be removed is to make post clearly on-topic and of reasonable quality."* - In other words, to find the gem buried in the turd.  (Sorry)

Comment: The rule is you keep the points for a post scored more than 3 and older than 60 days. Not sure if that applies to suggested edits, either.

Comment: I think it applies to edits as well. It was [discussed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334519/2285236) before.