# Should curators be allowed to save questions with mostly code?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Here's my issue. I've been on Stack Overflow answering and editing questions. I stumbled upon a question that was not very well formatted. The user posted the stack trace as normal text.

So I got to work fixing grammar, wording and most importantly putting the trace into code blocks. Though when I tried to save my edits they got rejected because the post was now mostly code.

What probably happened was that the user tried putting the error and code into code blocks, as the code was correctly formatted to begin with. But when they tried to post the question they couldn't because the system found too much code in it.

I don't think this is a bad system. It encourages people to be more explanatory in their question, but if that doesn't work and they take the easy way out, posting a confusingly formatted question with code as text, curators have a hard time improving the question. We don't know what the user tried or what their intentions are. All we have to work with is the contents of the question. In cases like this, we can't fix the formatting and have to either flag the question or ask the poster for more details in the comments.

My proposal for solving this issue would be to remove the system that checks for too much code in questions, if it's someone other than the poster editing the question.

Comment: @RobertLongson this is a good point. Altough sometimes it is not too much work to fix the formatting of such questions. I think that fixing the formatting and nudging the user in the right direction in the comments can be more encouraging than just saying the question needs more details. I imaging that the user is also frustrated becuase they could not post the question as they wanted.

Comment: "My proposal for solving this issue would be to remove the system that checks for too much code in questions, if it's someone other than the poster editing the question." This is already in place in case the editor has expanded editing privileges, i.e. >2k rep. Adding something similar for <2k rep users would only encouraging "polishing turds", see [Robert Longson's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/425103/5211833) below.

Comment: As a side note, editing posts which are likely to be closed when you are below 2k rep may lead to [unexpected reputation loss down the line](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334518/5211833), as the 2+ you gain for an accepted edit is lost when the post is deleted.

Comment: Rather then putting tracing into code blocks, it is sometime better to format them as quotes, using >, as that will word wrap them, and code blocks won't, which would then require lots of right & left scrolling to read.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I ran into a similar question just yesterday.  There was code followed by an error message.  The error message was wrapped in backticks, so they obviously knew it needed to be specially formatted, but essential line breaks were lost so the message was unclear.

I considered editing the question, but I couldn't be 100% sure I would be formatting it correctly myself.  I also considered leaving a comment to get them to clean it up themselves, but it didn't occur to me that the system made that *impossible*, so in retrospect I'm glad I didn't.

The nanny-bots were put into place to make the site content better.  When it demonstrably does the opposite, it's time to dump it - full stop.

Answer (score 22):

I would recommend not editing questions at all that fail the limited quality checks we have once you've edited them. What you're doing isn't really improving the situation because the question should probably be closed until the question asker provides the missing details.

Flag or vote to close questions that need to be salvaged by the question asker and only edit those that, post editing, are good enough to stay open and be answered.

If you do edit closable questions then you're simply going to cause any potential answerers to be frustrated because they will have to vote to close the question instead and they've wasted their time looking at an unanswerable question instead of spending it usefully answering one that can be answered. Think of those many answerers and viewers you're helping rather than that one question asker.

Comment: Maybe I've misunderstood, but can you clarify the "If you do edit closable questions then you're simply going to cause any potential answerers to be frustrated" part of your answer? What does editing a post have to do with anyone else spending time on the post? Why would potential answerers, e.g. readers, now be forced/compelled to VTC or be frustrated? Wouldn't potential answers/readers need to spend some time looking anyway to even assess the post's answerability and then answer or vote accordingly?

Comment: If a question is closed you know you can't answer it so you can move on and answer something else straight away if you want to. If it's not closed but also such poor quality it can't be answered then you have to read it yourself to make that determination.

Comment: And how do posts get to the closed state so they are clearly unanswerable and you don't waste time?  I think I understand your point now though. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than editing the post, vote to close and comment about how to improve the formating.

That teaches the original poster how to post proper questions, and doesn't cause you frustration when it inevitably gets locked and deleted anyway.

Comment: "vote to close", they cannot. Close voting requires 3k reputation. They could *flag* it for closure though (pushing it into the CV queue without adding a close *vote*)

Comment: I think the point was that "improve the formatting" was impossible because of automated rules put in place by S.O.  Commenting isn't going to help.

Comment: @MarkRansom yes it will because the problem should go away when more explanation text is added.