# I have a question about Stack Overflow. How do I find the appropriate place to ask?

Tags: discussion

It is clear that Meta is not the appropriate place to ask all questions about Stack Overflow due to how many questions have a net number of negative votes, and the same could probably be said about many of the other Meta websites for other Stack Exchange communities. Where do those questions belong, and where should I go to ask my question if I suspect that it will be received negatively within the Stack Exchange network?

Comment: You misunderstand what negative votes mean on meta. 
They don't necessarily mean that a question here is *bad* but more likely that a voter disagrees with the poster's views. This is as it should be.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels They very often mean that a question is just bad, for example, this question here is getting downvotes for precisely that reason.  This question isn't proposing something that people disagree with, it's just very poorly researched, and phrased unconstructively.

Comment: Unfortunately I am looking for the same, and you are very right one gets attacked asking a question about SO :( They claim it gets downvoted because it is bad, which is entirely wrong. It is not bad at all and right to the point. I have been searching a place to ask and from this thread, what I understand is you are banned if you ask a question about Stackoverflow. I wish there were also a way to downvote comments.

Answer (score 22):

The various Meta sites are the best places to ask about their respective sites. Before you do so, I highly recommend reading ["How do I participate in Meta and not die trying?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44188/how-do-i-participate-in-meta-and-not-die-trying)

Voting is a bit different here than on the main site, because it can be used both to indicate problems with a question (lack of research, tone) and whether or not people agree with what the question proposes. Downvotes can even be cast on well-written posts if the Meta community feels a particular proposal would be a bad idea.

Voting like this is a great way to gauge community sentiment, and shouldn't be perceived as an attack on an individual. I have a few highly downvoted posts, and I'm not upset about them. The votes showed how the community felt about my proposals or opinions, and know I know.

If you have a genuine question to ask about the sites, it hasn't been asked many times before, and you present it in a polite and constructive manner, I think you'll be surprised at the quality of responses you get.

Answer (score 20):

Meta Stack Overflow *is* the place to ask questions about Stack Overflow. Use the [support](/questions/tagged/support) tag to mark your question as something about how the site or its features work. You can even ask questions about how Stack Overflow is built and maintained, if you want, though those tend to be fewer and farther between in my experience. (I would use the [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) for that one.)

While it is true that a number of questions here are downvoted, it's *also* true that those questions fall into one of a few categories:

1. A feature request that others disagree with.

   Some of the guidance for Meta is to downvote feature requests you find not useful or actively harmful for the community, or that you disagree with as a summary. These will usually have the [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) tag, but will occasionally be mistagged as a discussion instead.
2. Rants

   If you come to Meta and just rant, not looking for any input or constructive feedback/discussion, you're gonna have a bad time. It would be similar to a new person in town coming and knocking on your door to yell and rant about a bad experience in town. Try to phrase your post to invite feedback, and try to keep an open mind.
3. Programming questions

   Granted, you probably aren't seeing many of these, but programming questions asked on Meta are never well-received. They are off-topic here. These tend to get deleted quickly, however.
4. No research duplicates

   There are a number of questions that are asked *repeatedly* on Meta. To the point that a new question about the topic is likely to be downvoted very quickly, since they are also likely not to have anything new or constructive to add to the conversation. This is easy to avoid: Research to the best of your abilities on Meta before you ask a question. Your question here falls short of this point.
5. Low quality/unclear questions

   As with the main site, questions that are extremely low quality and unclear will be downvoted, and likely closed. Your post here does appears to be decent quality.

Keep in mind that downvotes here do not cost you reputation, and downvotes are also more freely given. Also remember that the userbase on Meta is much smaller than Stack Overflow itself, so you're likely to get a smaller group of very dedicated users visiting and acting on your post.

Related Reading: [What is "meta"? How does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) in the Help Center and [How does Meta Stack Overflow work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/259917/how-does-meta-stack-overflow-work) in the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq)