# Tag conflict in Stack Overflow Meta

Tags: support, tags, stack-exchange

When posting a question to Stack Overflow Meta, in which I was looking for site recommendation about a question (), I could not simply add the tags `stack-exchange` and `site-recommendation`.  A notice appeared at under the tag that says:

> At least one of these tags is required - 'bug feature-request
>   discussion support'.

It appears immediately after I enter `stack-exchange` tag.  It seems to imply that I must add the tag `bug feature-request discussion support`.  If I add the tag`discussion` it goes away.  So you can see I had to add `discussion` to this post.

Is this a bug?  Otherwise, what does it mean?

Comment: It means what it says, you must have one of the 4 mandatory tags. I'm not sure I understand why you are confused. If you're asking about a site recommendation that's a support question and should be tagged as such.

Comment: Ok.  I see why I have misunderstanding.  It's because the quotes wrapped all the tags, I was thinking it was only one big tag.  I didn't see that it was actually pointing to several tags.

Comment: See the duplicate, specifically [this answer there](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/259917/how-does-meta-stack-overflow-work/259919#259919).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta):

> #### Meta has required tags.
>
> On the main site, we ask that you avoid using [meta-tags](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/).
>
> Because meta-discussion sites are different and serve multiple purposes, some meta-tags are okay, and even required. Each meta question is required to have one of the following tags:
>
> - [support](/questions/tagged/support), which indicates a request for assistance with one of the site's features.
> - [bug](/questions/tagged/bug), denoting a reproducible problem on the site that you believe is due to a mistake, malfunction, or programming error
> - [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request), for a proposal for a new feature on the site, or requests a change to an existing feature.
> - [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion), for posts that may not have a clear-cut right or wrong answer and are often subjective. If it's not a bug or feature request, it is probably a discussion.

That doesn't tell you *why* this is the case, but it's working well so far. One example is that [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)s and [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)s are monitored by Stack Overflow developers; they get notified whenever somebody posts a question with these tags *network-wide*.