# Why is it hard for the question author to upvote the answers?

Tags: discussion

This is a complaint, as well as a question I'm curious about.

I have recently started writing answers on Stack Overflow. I have written several answers over these past 2 months. One thing that really bother me is that often the author of the answer don't reply to the answers. I have seen several cases where there were working answers and yet none of them had a single comment from the author, much less a green tick. With that said all the hard work put in answering the questions goes right down the drain.

Sometimes I have even written a comment addressing the author to state if the answer was helpful or not but even then I didn't get any reply.

With that said, I really want that there should be some sort of penalty for the author if they don't reply or do something else to the posted answers which were posted say within a few hours of the question, after say a time period of 2-3 days.

EDIT:

I mean to say that let's say the user posted a questions today. Now someone answered that question within 12 hours. That means that most likely the author is still actively looking for the answer.

Now What I want is that the author should have a look on the answer within say 2-3 days. As much as he wants answers on his post I too at least need replies on my answer which I posted for his help.

I agree that he might not accept someone's answer as it might not work for him but the answer poster posted that answer assuming that it will work so basically if that answer is not working than only the OP will know that it's not and hence that knowledge will also remain only to the OP which again isn't correct as the information on the question should belong to all.

Comment: Please don't ask downvoters to explain their downvotes; explanations are not required when downvoting. Don't worry, users will comment when they have something to say. I do have a question: what if the OP doesn't receive any answers that are worth responding to? Who should decide, other than the OP, whether an answer should be accepted, for that matter?

Comment: "One thing that really bothers me is that often the author of the answer doesn't reply to the answers." - The author shouldn't be "replying" to your answers.  If the answer is helpful they should upvote it.  If they determine your answer solved their problem they should accept it.  What they shouldn't be doing is submitting temporary commentary under your answer.  "Sometimes I have even written a comment addressing the author to state if the answer was helpful or not but even then I didn't get any reply." - If you are asking users to accept your answer you should stop doing that.

Comment: @SecurityHound You are mistaken. When I write answer I have the intent to cooperate with the OP and help him solve the problem. That is done through Communication. If he don't response back how am I supposed to communicate on what went wrong.

Comment: Please note that downvotes on meta work differently and often mean disagreement. You don't lose reputation from downvotes here.

Comment: @ModusTollens ohh. Thanks for the clarification. I didn't knew that. I sincerely apologize in that case. I though it works the same as the general SO but just not the reputation effects. I didn't knew it meant disagreement.

Comment: Also see [*How does Meta work*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/259917/how-does-meta-stack-overflow-work).

Comment: Technical note: Stack Overflow's not the best place for communication and a collaborative answer. The perfect question is complete and supplies enough information from the get-go, so all you have to do is answer it. It rarely is, so you often have to pry more information out of the asker with comments.

Comment: Workaround: Only answer questions from users who have a history of providing (useful) feedback. The first filter could be a reputation points threshold of, say, 300 (to save opening a lot of pages to check). Most questions are hit and run (incl. paid assignment of homework commissioned through [Fiverr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiverr)).

Comment: *"With that said all the hard work put in answering the questions goes right down the drain"* - no it doesn't. You're not helping the person who posted the question, you're helping everyone that finds the answer because they had the same problem. Stack Overflow is not a helpdesk, you write answers for the greater good and the long run. At least that *should* be your intention.

Comment: @Abhishek - Stack Exchange communities are not discussion forums. The author can ask for you to clarify your answer but that’s about it.  You shouldn’t clarify your answer with a comment.  The answer is for everyone that has the problem.

Comment: Why do you care that *"often the author of the answer don't reply to the answers"*. Do you mean the author of the *question*?

Comment: *"all the hard work put in answering the questions goes right down the drain"* Answer questions that you enjoy answering, that give you practice in writing code and in writing explanations, and that may be helpful to the potentially thousands of future readers, not just the OP. IME, the most satisfying answers are the ones where *I* learn something new in the process of creating the answer.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The only barrier to upvoting is the 15 rep requirement. IIRC, the author [cannot accept an answer until 15 minutes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) after posting the question (if they didn't answer it themselves) (thanks to [Larnu](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/410878/why-is-it-hard-for-the-question-author-to-upvote-the-answers/410879?noredirect=1#comment861227_410879) for the link) but there otherwise are no barriers to accepting an answer.

I suspect that you're mostly seeing this happen on questions from new users who aren't familiar with how the site works (and at 1 rep can't upvote anyway).

It might be accidental:

- They intended to accept an early answer once the system let them but they forgot to come back.
- They asked anonymously and lost access to the question.
- They know from experience that they can't comment elsewhere without 50 rep and don't realize they can comment on their own questions.

It might be deliberate:

- They intentionally never came back.
- They don't think the answers are correct.
- They don't think the answers are useful, even if the code works.
- They're giving it more time to get more answers.
- They are upset the question didn't get any upvotes.
- They are upset the question is getting downvotes.
- They are worried that any negative feedback on the answers will result in downvotes.
- They don't think any of the comments are worth replying to.
  (I've had this one happen several times: I'll comment asking for additional information, someone else will guess at what the issue is, OP will respond to the guess but not my request for info.)

It might be something I didn't think of here.

> With that said, I really want that there should be some sort of penalty for the author...

I disagree with this. We have been very adamant that [feedback is not required for downvotes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/why-isnt-providing-feedback-mandatory-on-downvotes-and-why-are-ideas-suggestin). It therefore doesn't make sense to require feedback for a *lack* of votes. Why someone votes they way they do, including the choice not to vote at all, is their own business. As long as they aren't engaged in vote fraud, serial voting, or any other unethical behavior, we shouldn't require their reasoning.

Comment: the `feedback` I desire is from the `poster`. I don't care if my answer don't get upvote. But I do care that when I post an answer the poster should at least have a look at it and as he expects the replies from others on his question I too expect replies from him on my answer. If it doesn't work for him then I want to know why it doesn't. I don't want the time of the person who answer to just go down the drain.

Comment: It won't go down the drain. Think about it: on Stack Overflow, we don't answer only for the OP. We aim to create a knowledge base for many people facing the same questions. Most reputation points will come from users other than the OP stumbling upon your answer.

Comment: *the feedback I desire is from the poster.* @AbhishekPrajapat I understand that but it's still hypocritical to require feedback from the person who posted the question when we don't require feedback from other people voting on the question. At the very least, it's inconsistent.

Comment: _"IIRC, the author cannot accept an answer within a couple of hours of posting the question (if they didn't answer it themselves)"_ This is probably mentioned somewhere in the help pages but I'm pretty sure it's only 15 minutes.

Comment: It's in the FAQ on [se], @mediocrevegetable1 : [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/397219) But yes, you are correct, the user must wait at least 15 minutes before accepting an answer. At least that's one metric that attempts to stop FGITW.

Comment: no i see that all the tiome also with users which have over hundred rep

Comment: I really believe that my statement on hours has been misinterpreted. I have made an edit explaining it further.

Comment: Sounds like you should focus on questions where you need less feedback from the author.

Comment: "the feedback I desire is from the poster" -- you're entitled to this, but I'm betting that the longer you spend answering questions, the less you'll care about the poster. A nontrivial number of them appear to immediately quit the site after asking. If you get a comment, vote, checkmark or edit/clarification from them it's a minor miracle/accident. Often, the checkmark goes to the worst answer in the thread. OP is there to create prompts for answers that function as search targets for common programming problems. If they're helped, I'm glad, but it's incidental.