# Can we separate Stack Overflow by experience level?

Tags: feature-request, split-stack-overflow

I've noticed an overwhelming trend of "punking" new users. This can take many forms:

- Insulting the intelligence of the user.
- Calling the user offensive names.
- Spiteful downvoting of the user's questions and answers.
- Avoiding answering the question out of spite.
- Providing intentionally flawed answers out of spite.
- Trolling the user.
- Toying with the user, by commenting negatively in attempt to elicit emotional response from the user.

Is it just reverse psychology designed to weed out the bad apples? I know I probably never would have RTFM or learned anything if it wasn't for the harsh lectures I received here...

**BUT—**

I still think it's off-putting, and a better solution would be to create a noob wiki.

A simple skills test in a handful of selected languages would be required to ask questions on the main site, while everyone else would be confined to posting on the noob wiki. I think this would be helpful in many ways:

1. **Less Moderation**: After completing the steps to get into a more exclusive Stack Overflow, a user would have a greater incentive to make positive contributions. One slip could get you back in the newbie wiki.
2. **Avoiding the culture clash between newbies and advanced users**: we all know that feeling you get when someone asks a question that is so stupid relative to your experience level that it physically hurts your brain. More positive vibes ya'll, newbies can ask without fear of ridicule, and advanced users can assist other advanced users in solving real challenges! `:D`
3. **Easier communication**: It is easier to explain a multi dimensional object implementing array access to people on, near, or above your skill level than it is to explain the most basic of concepts at a basic level to someone who decided to start programming php 10 minutes ago. For beginners who have recently knocked the basics down off of their list, it might be a little easier to explain to another beginner, and vice versa, saving everyone the most valuable resource in the universe—TIME.

It just makes so much sense. I can't think of a good argument against it, other than more work for Stack Exchange's devs, which may be the kicker.

Comment: Just so you know and so you don't feel like you're being bullied, [votes on Meta are different](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254108/109702). You're not down voted necessarily because it's a bad question, but possible because people disagree with your suggestion or statements.

Comment: We don't have anything against new users. The real problem are the ton of bad questions every day. That can get on your nerves.

Comment: *Providing intentionally flawed answers out of spite* this would hurt the poster rep wise in dnvotes far more than the new person.  *Avoiding answering the question out of spite* not spite - there is little to gain from answering bad questions, which are likely to be deleted or are simply uninteresting or based on false assumptions or have already been asked and answered.

Comment: the question come up - in less virulent form - about weekly. more interesting is the thread on *are expert users answering less* I'd post a link, but I can never find anything on meta

Comment: "*I've noticed an overwhelming trend of 'punking' new users. This can take many forms: Insulting the intelligence of the user, Calling the user offensive names, Toying with the user, by commenting negatively in attempt to elicit emotional response from the user.*" All of that behavior that you described ***is not allowed***, and if you experience it, **you should flag such comments for moderator attention.**

Comment: @Plutonix I think you're looking for [Are high-reputation users answering fewer questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252756/456814).

Comment: Just to put a cap on this: If someone is being rude, offensive, or just plain non-constructive, *flag a moderator*. We do take action, and reputation has **zero** effect on what we do.

Comment: For the most part, something like this would create an incredible culture shock from newbie land to professional.  It's one of the reasons I fight so hard against treating newbies any easier than regulars; doing so essentially creates a double standard.  One which, when removed, comes as a massive shock to the user, as previously acceptable behaviour is now no longer acceptable.  It sends the wrong message.

Answer (score 7):

**NB:** The text below was a response to the initial version of the question and is not entirely appropriate to the current questions text. But I'm leaving it as is.

---

Frankly, since you are so sure you know how to build a better site, why don't you give it a try?

Seriously.

Stack Overflow started from an idea. To build a site that was *much* better than the existing help forums. A place to get good answers to good questions. A site that would add value to the internet and be good enough to attract and keep truly expert users.

All the things that you are complaining about are there to advance that mission and this site is not going to change its *modus operandi* at this point, so if you want the site you are describing you are going to have to build it for yourself.

But that *does* leave you with the problem: *"Who is going to provide the answers if we don't build the site to attract and keep expert users?"* But I figure you'll think of something.

Comment: fair enough, i just thought it might be a helpful suggestion. The majority disagrees. I can live with that.

Comment: One cannot give it a try. SE currently blocks all such attempts in area51. [We can't actually create an "alternative" Stack Overflow. If you are having an issue with that community, please try to help improve the site rather than segregating folks](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/72403/coding-for-noobs)

Comment: @Trilarion You can't give it a try as another Stack Exchange site, which is not surprising because it goes against the grain here. You can set up a separate site--there are even a variety of open source Q&A scaffolds that appeared after Stack Overflow started to take off. There is already a site trying to compete with Physics SE, where they have done exactly that.

Comment: @dmckee I don't understand why it would go against the grain here. It seems like people here are feed up with beginners questions and so another SE site might be the optimal solution unless you want to deny beginners a site on SE at all. Of course you could start completely independent but I think also an SE site should be possible. The proposed SOs in regional languages are more ridiculous in my eyes but they are allowed.