# Would a "graveyard" for bad questions make sense?

Tags: discussion

It's more black-and-white (to me, anyway) if they ask a question with either no details, no attempts, or no actual question. But in cases like this it's harder. It's not a "bad" question - it just doesn't fit the site.

Would it be feasible or practical to migrate questions like this to some sort of graveyard separate from Stack Overflow? It would have almost the same effect as deleting the question. The only difference would be a slight improvement in perception, especially for new users who just don't seem to get it. Instead of negative numbers, the feedback is, "We've moved your question to this other forum (where quite likely it will never get answered.)"

That could also provide a lower-risk forum for newer users to try answering questions.

I doubt that I'm the first person to think of this, so there's probably a duplicate question that I didn't find when I searched. (Maybe I'm about to get schooled on asking a bad question.) It likely also means that there's some really obvious reason why such a feature wouldn't make sense, and I just don't know what it is.

I didn't tag this with "feature request" because I'm more interested in understanding what does or doesn't make sense and why.

It's more black-and-white (to me, anyway) if they ask a question with either no details, no attempts, or no actual question. But in cases like this it's harder. It's not a "bad" question - it just doesn't fit the site.

Would it be feasible or practical to migrate questions like this to some sort of graveyard separate from Stack Overflow? It would have almost the same effect as deleting the question. The only difference would be a *slight* improvement in perception, especially for new users who just don't seem to get it. Instead of negative numbers, the feedback is, "We've moved your question to this other forum (where quite likely it will never get answered.)"

That could also provide a lower-risk forum for newer users to try answering questions.

Comment: If we create a place for junk questions to go...who's going to answer them?  Or even try to improve them?

Comment: Presumably no one. It's the same thing as downvoting or deleting a question. The only difference is in perception.

Comment: Pretty sure there are couple of feature requests regarding the creation of some sort of "SO for noobs".

Comment: Why exactly do we want to move questions to a place for them to die?  How does that differ from just closing and deleting them, other than prolong the hope that help might be forthcoming?

Comment: The example you give is a deleted question which a huge majority of the site can't see anyways, what difference in perception would there be? Unless you mean the perception of the asker, in which case, we don't want to make askers think that questions that don't belong here are okay to post anyways. Regarding _We've moved your question to this other forum (where quite likely it will never get answered.)_, SO is _NOT_ a forum, and it seems equivalent to just deleting the post (as it will not get an answer regardless), so I don't see how that would be a more positive experience to the asker eith

Comment: Some parts of your suggestion resemble a fairly common request titled something along the lines of "newbie section", usually rejected as it would be a blind leading the blind kind of thing. And if no one answers questions there, I'm sure it would gain the infamy of deletion and follow the typical accusations associated with it.

Comment: @Servy, my question made it clear why I did not tag this as a feature request. My question is about understanding the perspective, not asking for a feature. First you edit my question in a way that makes my intent unclear, and then you change the tag so that it doesn't reflect the original question. Please don't do that.

Comment: I agree @ScottHannen, I don't get a "feature request" vibe from your question; you are explicit asking if it's _feasible or practical_, not if it should be implemented.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. As indicated in the part of the question that someone kept editing out, I didn't think it was a novel idea. I suspected that it had been thought of a gazillion times and there was a specific reason. I was just interested in understanding it.

Comment: SOCVR [invented this in 2013](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90230/socvr-request-graveyard). Just saying...

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261956/can-we-separate-stack-overflow-by-experience-level

Comment: slightly related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255551/how-to-encourage-newbie-programmers-without-enabling-hold-my-hand-comment-stre

Comment: Perhaps "graveyard" was the wrong word, and a better metaphor would have been "nursing home where almost no one visits except occasionally a clown or some dude with dogs, because it seems more humane then putting the patient down, even though keeping them alive with tubes might not be all that kind anyway." But I didn't think of that.

Comment: @ScottHannen If you're going to post a question requesting a new feature, then it needs to be tagged [meta-tag:feature-request].  Requesting a feature in a question but refusing to tag it as such makes as much sense as asking a C++ question and demanding it be tagged Java.  That you want to mistag the question is irrelevant.  The question needs to be tagged to reflect what it's actually asking.  Tagging exists to help others find questions based on their topic.  Intentionally mistagging questions only makes it harder for people to find the questions they're actually looking for.

Comment: @Servy, if I'm going to post a question requesting a feature I will be sure to do that. Thanks.

Comment: @Servy It's not a feature request. Where in the question is it requesting a feature?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Where in the question is it not?  What is the question doing, if not discussing a proposed new feature?

Comment: @Servy "_explicit(ly) asking if it's feasible or practical, not if it should be implemented_" as in, it's seeking discussion about whether the proposed idea is feasible/practical, it's not a request for implementation. The OP said "_I didn't tag this with "feature request" because I'm more interested in understanding what does or doesn't make sense and why._" - It's literally for the discussion of the idea, not a request at all.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton That's literally what feature requests are.  It's a discussion of a proposed idea to see if it's feasible/practical.  ** You literally just defined what a feature request is**.  The OP saying they didn't want to tag their question as feature request doesn't mean it's not a feature request.  If I tag my C++ question with Java saying I don't want it tagged as C++ *that doesn't mean it's not a C++ question, or that it shouldn't be tagged as such*.  Discussions of a possible new feature request *are what the feature request tag is for*.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton If discussing a proposed new feature for appropriateness wasn't a feature request *then nothing would be*.  Because that's the *only* type of question where it  *is* appropriate to tag it as a feature request.

Comment: @Servy If the _discussion_ tag is not for having a _discussion_ about an idea, then what _is_ it for? The tag wiki says "_that may not necessarily have a clear-cut right or wrong answer and often subjective_", which seems like this question imo. The feature request one says "_This tag is for proposals of new features on the site, or requests for a change to an existing feature._" which this is _NOT_ doing, because it's not requesting any changes, it's trying to have a discussion about an idea.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton For discussions of things that *aren't* possible new (or changed) features, or bugs.  It's it's an "other" tag for questions where no other primary tag is appropriate.

Comment: @Servy Maybe we have different definitions of the word "request".

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton So how do you define a feature request, if you don't consider proposing a new feature and asking if it would be a good idea to implement it a feature request?  What *is* a feature request then?

Comment: @Servy I consider a feature request to have a lot more fleshed out details rather than a _very_ rough idea. The difference in my mind would be "This idea, with this implementation, and these features to fill in the gaps" vs "here is an idea, what do you think?". To me, this question is more a discussion because you can't implement this feature without a lot more details about how it would work, and these features would come from discussion within the community. To me, it's not a feature requests because OP is very vocal about the fact that they want details about why it _wouldn't work_

Comment: It may be a fine line between discussing how certain proposed features are viewed and requesting a new feature. There are a million ways to respond to that, including nothing at all. For example, one could say, "It sounds like you are requesting a feature. If not, please clarify." Near the bottom of that list would be deleting the part of the question that *explicitly* states the intent while stating *explicitly* that they are *not* requesting a feature, and then calling it a feature request.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton So you don't consider a request for a proposed new feature a feature request because it's lacking in details?  That doesn't mean it's not a feature request, it just means it's a feature request that's lacking in details.  Feature requests can be specific or vague with their details, both can be appropriate, but it doesn't make it not a feature request.

Comment: @Servy No, not because it's lacking in detail, because it's _specifically requesting details about the idea_, it's not saying _here, let's implement this_. OP is obviously trying to have a discussion about the idea (If it would work or not, and why), not trying to get someone to start making pull requests for it.

Comment: @ScottHannen So if someone asks a question about a bunch of C++ code, and asks for a C++ solution to the problem, but tags the question Java and includes in the question that they're not tagging the question as C++ because they don't think their question is a C++ question then people should just leave it mistagged and not remove the statement that it's not a C++ question?  No.  Your question is a feature request.  You want feedback on the what people think of your proposed new feature.  The way to do that is the feature request tag.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton That's literally all feature requests.  A feature request does not require every single minute detail be spelled out and not up for discussion at all to be a feature request.  If it did, then literally no question would merit that tag on here.  Feature requests are for *any* posts about possible new features, regardless of how much detail they have, so that they can be discussed, iterated on, and feedback given on how useful they might be.

Comment: @Servy I think that not using the `discussion` tag for a discussion, and instead using a tag which implies the feature is well thought out and is ready for implementation is a recipe for disaster and not very intuitive at all. Regardless, I'm done spending time talking about it, so enjoy the rest of your day. :)

Comment: @Servy, this is a logical fallacy called "begging the question." In other words, asserting that this question was mistagged by comparing it to a mistagged question. The comparison only applies if the second question was mistagged. You're using your assertion as evidence of itself. Why are you so obsessed with micromanaging this? I'm moving on as well. This is not a productive use of my time.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Where does the [meta-tag:feature-request] tag say that it is only for questions that are ready for implementation?  Why do you think it's intuitive that a question requesting a new feature not be tagged as a feature request?  Making the feature request tag not actually be used on any of the feature requests on the site because *none* of them are "finished" and ready for implementation is just confusing and unintuitive.

Comment: @ScottHannen Your argument for why the question shouldn't be a feature question is that you said it's not a feature request, despite the fact that the question is requesting a new feature.  Thus I compared it to another situation of someone saying their question isn't about a topic that it's about.  If you want to explain why your question isn't discussing a proposed new feature other than by asserting that it's not in the question, then I'd be happy to address it.

Comment: @ScottHannen By the way, "begging the question" is not the term for an analogy that you think isn't applicable.  Begging the question is providing an answer to the question that provides no more information than the question itself already contained, and it's not a logical fallacy (because it's not wrong, just uninformative because it's tautologically true).

Comment: @Servy, If I argue that meat is murder, and then use as an analogy that it's just like putting a gun to someone's head and pulling the trigger, that *is* begging the question. I'm rephrasing my assertion as evidence to support my assertion. Anyway, I will delete the question. I don't visit this site to pick arguments, shout people down, and tirelessly vindicate how right I think I am on hair-splitting details.

Comment: @ScottHannen That would be a false equivalency, not begging the question.  Asserting it as a false equivalency would also require further explanation, in this case one might argue that murder is defined as killing of a human, not any animal, and hence the two are not equivalent.  " I'm rephrasing my assertion as evidence to support my assertion." Yes, I know.  Repeating your own assertion isn't evidence supporting said assertion.  It's just repetition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There already is such "graveyard": the question being put on hold/closed.

Comment: And maybe later deleted, but still visible for high rep users.

Comment: That’s not at all what OP was asking for. You can’t even answer questions that are on hold/closed. No clue why he accepted it

Comment: @alec_a _"The only difference would be a slight improvement in perception, especially for new users who just don't seem to get it. ... the feedback is, "We've moved your question to this other forum (where quite likely it will never get answered.)""_ -- the key perception effect of putting on hold is this. The question is still there but "in limbo".