# Is it OK to flag my own question because I want someone to answer it?

Tags: discussion, flags, questions, moderators

My question has a low view count and I want it to be answered by someone. I learned that you can flag your own post so it can be seen by moderators, but in this case I'm not reporting it as spam or to state it's not a constructive question.

So before I do that is it OK and valid?

Comment: Absolutely not.

Comment: No, don't flag a moderator just because you want someone to answer your question. Moderators break up fights, they don't get your question answered for you. Put a bounty on your question, or perhaps edit it to make it clearer for potential answerers.

Comment: Finally, you are **not guaranteed to get an answer**, so if no one answers your question, then sometimes you just have to accept that, and move on.

Comment: Non-trivial questions which have a limited target audience can indeed have a hard time finding the few experts that could answer it. Putting a bounty on it often helps, I can confirm that anecdotally. This takes a little time though, don't expect to always get an answer immediately. If you don't have enough spare rep to offer as bounty, perhaps you can find a benefactor to do so for you. If the question is of great quality and deserves it I'd be happy to jump in.

Comment: Thanks for the comment and answer. I think bounty would not be good to me because I have low reputation. 
@deceze here is my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644579/rainbow-table-unable-to-get-last-reduction-c-code

Comment: @Cupcake that is the saddest part " accept and move on".

Comment: @reggie_jimac **you posted your question 4 hours ago**. Sometimes it can take a day or two, or maybe a week for an answer. Answers **are not guaranteed to be immediate** either. Stack Overflow gets 7000 to 8000 questions ***per day***, so sometimes (actually, a lot of the time) you just need to wait.

Comment: Turns out I actually knew [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24647906/476) to this one myself (or so I believe).

Comment: A question may stay unanswered for days, but if the title is okay(ish) and it is tagged correctly, it can still draw the attention of field experts a while later. That said: I agree with Cupcake. No need for "4 hours and still no answer! **Panic!** Alert the community!")

Comment: You could put up a bounty to attract more views/answers. Of course you would have to wait 2 days for that.

Comment: This would actually make a fantastic flagging FAQ if not for 1) the extremely controversial votes and 2) the fact that not many people would even think twice before flagging their own questions for moderator attention, and so will probably never even find this question (undermining the whole "FAQ" label).

Comment: This is what bounties are for!

Comment: Kudos to the OP for asking here, and not just doing it.

Comment: Why the downvotes?  This is a user asking whether they should do something. In the right place.  Before doing it wrong! I'd get "disagreement downvotes" if it said, "I should be able to..." but it's a legitimate question from someone working hard to respect the system,which should be encouraged, no?

Comment: Up voting! This is a legitimate question, and the purpose of flagging can be easily misunderstood. If I could put a bounty on MSO questions, I would!

Comment: @Jaydles: Do you think it's worth making this an [meta-tag:faq]? (That would probably require a serious comment cleanup, of course.) Or not, for the reasons I gave earlier?

Comment: @jaydles Here on meta upvotes and downvotes are not statements about the usefulness of the post but agreements/disagreements. This is what many people have said in the last time.

Comment: I also want my questions answered. If it would so simple and flagging it would help anything I would have...

Comment: @trilarion, I know, but my point was that downvoting for disagreement should be limited to cases when the OP is *proposing something specific*.  If we down vote everyone who asks whether it's allowed to do a thing, we're not going to do a very good job reinforcing that behavior (asking first.

Comment: @Jaydles I thought it was well-established that a downvote on Meta means "no, this should not be so" regardless of whether it's a question or a proposal. As Trilarion mentioned, it is *not* an indication of a well- or poorly-asked question.

Comment: @TylerH In that case, the message you temporarily see when you click the downvote button here "Please consider adding a comment if you think this post can be improved" needs changing. There's nothing to improve; annoying moderators is just wrong. It should say "thank your for your opinion".

Comment: @Poldie Yes; I think that is because the current accepted use of voting on MSO is not the original/intended way to use it, but rather a way that has evolved out of user consensus. Not what the creators intended, but what was, in effect, realized by the community.

Comment: @TylerH, voting to indicate support/dislike of proposals *was* an evolution.  Downvoting someone who just asks how to behave here is a *devolution* - it's incompatible with a desire to have people ask here.  It's not even clear what the heck it means:  If they reframed it in the negative "You're not supposed to flag for an answer, right?" would that suggest you should vote the opposite way??  Disagreement down voting should be reserved for feature requests, or discussions that explicitly propose some new behavior or guideline, unless we don't want user questions about how to behave asked here.

Comment: @Jaydles so I actually had a comment here earlier (you can probably see the deleted version, since you have a diamond) in response to your original comment, that basically explained the initial votes on this question. Some of those explanations actually make a lot of sense, if you can read between the lines and understand what I'm talking about. Not saying that those explanations are acceptable reasons, only pointing them out. I deleted the comment soon after I posted it because I didn't think it was that important to point out, but after all this discussion, I kind of wish I had just left it.

Comment: @Jaydles If he rephrased it in the negative as you suggest, then following protocol you would still downvote to say "no". Downvotes are "no" answers/responses and upvotes are "yes" answers/responses. It's that simple, from my understanding. It just so happens that the majority of things posted here are proposals with which people can agree or disagree. I'm not arguing whether this is a good behavior or what we should aspire to, only observing how I have interpreted the function.

Comment: @Jaydles also, I'm sure you're already familiar about voting tendencies on MSO, but in case you find this helpful anyways: [Downvotes on Meta are confusing: do they *really* mean poor-post quality, or just disagreement?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254108/456814).

Comment: The way I see it - votes are being used to express agreement/disagreement, no doubt about that, that's exactly what is happening. Jay is simply saying (and I think many of us agree) it shouldn't work that way because then you're forced to only ask agreeable questions and make popular opinions if you don't want to see your post downvoted to oblivion. Makes you wonder too if things would have been different if I were the one posting this instead and I framed it as an [faq-proposed].

Comment: @BoltClock I agree on this sentiment but I think it requires a behind-the-curtain change for Meta *away from* the otherwise-ubiquitous up- and down-vote arrows. Perhaps (larger) buttons/arrows that say "Agree" and "Disagree". Since there's no reputation gain from Meta, there's no need to use the up and down arrows for voting. People who would vote for poor quality can leave a comment or revise the post, instead.

Comment: @BoltClock I dont know  that I can proposed something here. Its like a support center ( like customer service on call centers ) for me before.

Comment: @Cupcake "if no one answers your question, then sometimes you just have to accept that" *I see what you did there*

Comment: @BoltClock: If your faq-proposed question is *"Should I flag my post as spam to get more people looking at it?"*, then the answer is still *"WTF, how did you get that idea, can you seriously not figure out the answer to that yourself?"*

Answer (score 333, accepted):

No, please do not use moderator flags for this reason. Doing so is a sure-fire way to get yourself into trouble with the very people who will see your flag.

#### Why not to do this

Moderators are people who deal with problems in the community, such as inappropriate posts (as you've correctly pointed out) or misbehaving users. Answering questions, on the other hand, is not one of a moderator's roles. At best, flagging your question for our attention in hopes of getting an answer is counter-productive, and at worst, it distracts us from other, potentially more severe issues that do warrant our attention, because they have to be manually handled like every other moderator flag. Either way, this simply results in a waste of time for both us and yourself.

#### What to do instead

First of all, *be patient*. Not all questions get answered in the first few hours of the time they're asked, particularly those that have a limited audience or are extremely complex. Stack Overflow is flooded with a staggering [7000-8000 *new questions **per day***](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#questionsperday), which takes time for people to process. Keep in mind also that SO is a global site, and there are time zone differences in effect as well. It may take a few hours (or sometimes even a few *days*) for someone who can answer your question to even see it.

If your question is not getting answers, consider editing it to add more information or progress, and/or placing a bounty on it if enough time has passed and it still has not been adequately resolved. These are much more effective ways of getting more eyeballs on your question, plus it ensures you receive input from the right people (i.e. people with the appropriate domain-specific knowledge).

All that said, **thank you** for asking this beforehand. You may not realize it, but users flagging their questions inappropriately is an actual problem we deal with on a regular basis, so I personally really appreciate that you chose to ask first.

Comment: Now I get it don't worry I didnt click the **"flag question"** button.

Comment: I would add that adding relevant tags can be an effective alternative to the OP's suggestion.

Comment: By the way what is the meaning of OP? people keep saying OP.

Comment: @reggie_jimac OP stands for "original poster," which can refer to the author of either a question or an answer. In this case, that is you for the question and BoltClock for the answer.

Comment: @AstroCB: Although most people only take it to mean the author of a question, but really we should just stop using the term OP altogether.

Comment: Ding ding ding! Another Great Answer badge for BoltClock! `:D`

Comment: @Cupcake: Number of "please answer me" flags I've declined since posting this answer: 6.

Comment: @BoltClock is that up or down from before?

Comment: @Cupcake: I think it varies actually. I didn't keep track of the numbers before though.

Comment: Number of "please answer me" flags I've declined on programming questions on meta since posting this answer: 1. Just to give you an idea of why as much as I want this to be an FAQ, I don't think it's going to happen.

Comment: Supposing *this* question hadn't been answered, then would it be valid to flag it for moderator attention? ;-)

Comment: @BoltClock not sure if this is worth it, but do you think it would be useful to mention [why questions might not receive answers right away](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/263070/is-it-ok-to-flag-my-own-question-because-i-want-someone-to-answer-it#comment55719_263070), if at all?

Comment: @BoltClock: I'd like to suggest you add a paragraph to your "What to do instead" section that says something along the lines of "First of all, **be patient**. Not all questions get answered in the first few hours of the time they're asked, particularly those that have a limited audience or are extremely complex.".

Comment: @Ken White: Feel free to edit my answer!

Comment: Is it worth mentioning the Bounty system and its "this question has not received enough attention" reason?

Comment: @Niet the Dark Absol: Probably. At this rate I think I'm going to have to expand my answer into a full-blown FAQ post and open it to wiki edits :P

Comment: @Cupcake: Actually, I have a feeling the number of flags has *increased* despite this question being prominently featured on the bulletin. It's almost as if people are seeing the link and *deliberately ignoring it* and choosing to flag anyway. I think I'm going to respond a little more harshly to such flags for as long as this question remains on the bulletin.

Comment: Why is it even possible to flag your own question?

Comment: @Daniel Darabos: Things can happen to any question, including your own, and we don't want to prevent users from being able to flag their own questions for legitimate reasons. For example, if there is an edit war on the question, or the question is one of a few that have been serially downvoted.

Comment: @BC: Done. Please feel free to edit or roll it back if you feel it's appropriate. :-)

Comment: @DanielDarabos Sometimes it happens that we flag a question because it was a meta and posted on SO/vice versa. Happened to me with Puzzling.SE yesterday.

Comment: @BoltClock Do question/answer up votes, best answers on any Meta site increase reputation?

Comment: 7-8000?! Is that for real? I think I've only asked like max 4 questions ever and I regretted even those. Wow. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592 is what I usually refer back to

Answer (score -13):

Consider offering a bounty instead.

Comment: Maybe explain why, since this is a new user? Or remove this since BoltClock already covered this over 20 hours ago...

Comment: I upvote this answer since it's an alternative. People just watching for downvote, which is really bad!

Comment: @totten: Like jmort253 said, I've already mentioned bounties in my answer. This answer does not need to exist. I'm not sure why Seva felt a need to repeat something that was already mentioned a day ago.

Comment: I'm sure it can be exist for users who thinks tl;dr for your answer. And I'm sure question is related and gives an answer. Anyway, I'm not the lawyer @Seva.

Comment: @Totten if you think the currently accepted answer needs a tl;dr; you haven't seen awesome meta-posts.. A few answers on meta are in the format of this one here. usually they are useful only to experienced users. others are around the currently accepted answer, and others break the resolution of your monitor in vertical layout with fontsize 5. These are usually the **important answers** that explain the thoughts behind a conclusion, and I personally really love reading such answers.