# Is it OK to flag a question because there are no accepted answers?

Tags: discussion, flags, answers, accepted-answer

I was wondering how to prevent people for not accepting answers that seems to be working for them.

For example:

- [Drupal different theme for ip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23037568/drupal-different-theme-for-ip/23037584#23037584)
- [How can I remove quotes in rss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24635967/how-can-i-remove-quotes-in-rss/24637071#24637071)

You can see there is my answer that seems to be good for the OP, but the answer was not accepted.  Is it flagging OK for that? If not, is there something you can do?

Comment: What would you flag it for exactly? The flag tooltip says: "flag this post for serious problems or moderator attention" - so, what exactly is the "serious problem" here that requires moderator attention?

Comment: You can flag not for just serious problems but there is in the line "or moderator attention". I was curious if thats fit in moderators attention, but seems like not.

Comment: +1 for asking instead of just flagging away. I hope more people search and find the answer to this question. We decline flags for this reason every day.

Comment: Related: [Is it OK to flag my own question because I want someone to answer it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/263070/456814).

Comment: @Bill the Lizard: Sadly, all we *can* do is hope.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

No, it's not OK to flag a post because there are no accepted answers.

The only person that can accept an answer is the poster of the question and they don't get to see the flag. Also, leaving a comment asking the OP to accept an answer is not acceptable either and will result in that comment being deleted.

By flagging you are making more work for the moderators and all they'll do is decline your flag. Do this enough and you won't be able to flag *anything*.

Comment: And what else you can do?

Comment: @balintpekker - there's nothing you can or should do beyond upvoting the correct answer(s) and downvoting the incorrect ones.

Comment: I have to wait 5 more mins to accept it. Maybe I should ask it in meta why is that?:)

Comment: @balintpekker the delay in being able to accept is to give time for other people to answer. There are times when it can be annoying, but mostly you do want to wait before accepting.

Comment: I post reminders for OP like these: "_Hello, following up on this - Have you solved your problem? Would you like to accept an answer?_" Is this OK? I find that questioners may forget, so I thought I should remind the OP for going through and select a most useful solution to check his question as "answered", or leave a solution himself for future readers. Plus, OP gets to earn 2 rep points...

Comment: @Unihedron - No it's not OK. It's badgering the OP. Stop it.

Comment: @ChrisF - interesting, [even if it's a newer user](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14994/do-you-feel-dirty-if-you-nudge-new-users-to-accept-your-answer-when-they-indicat)? Should we flag _all_ comments asking for acceptance of an answer for deletion?

Comment: @esqew - Even if it's a new user.

Comment: @ChrisF [There seems to be a significant amount of disagreement with that position](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251288/dealing-with-an-answer-that-wasnt-accepted-maybe-because-a-user-is-a-newbie-in).

Comment: @KevinReid - the problem is that if people see comments like that somewhere they think they can apply it everywhere. Unfortunately.

Comment: When the op writes a comment saying "Thanks! Works like a charm! Exactly what I was looking for!" and then doesn't accept the answer, that means OP is a new user who doesn't understand the concept of accepting, so it's OK to explain it in a comment. This is not badgering the OP, it's helping them learn how to use the site.

Comment: @ChrisF: *"leaving a comment asking the OP to accept an answer is not acceptable either and will result in that comment being deleted"* - Why is that? It seems to be leaving dangling questions kind of breaks the site (its a Q&A site, not a Q site). I've asked folks to accept an answer in the past. I asked because I was not familiar with the technology, and wanted to know what worked and what did not before I moved forward. I even cite [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: @jww because a) it's badgering the OP (or certainly comes across like that) and b) it's noise. Yes I can see why you think it leaves "dangling" questions, but it's really not necessary. We see lots of flags from people complaining that people have accepted the "wrong" answer, so having an accepted answer is not wholly beneficial

Comment: @ChrisF: *"it's badgering the OP..."* - well, it could come across that way if the approach is wrong. But it a) educates the user about how to use the site, and b) helps future visitors who come to Stack Overflow for answers. I guess I feel its better to hurt their feelings a little rather than have them damage the site (perhaps repeatedly).

Comment: Just a point of info:  I regularly downvote answers which include a request to accept or are followed by a comment to that effect.

Comment: @ChrisF I wholeheartedly disagree, especially (but not only) with new users. I frequently leave an answer to the question as asked, only to have the OP ask for clarification in the comments. If they've thanked me and told me the solution works, I'll leave a comment saying "If this solution was helpful to you, please consider [accepting it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)". That seems like the furthest thing from "badgering the OP" as you malignantly termed it. It's always going to be a gray area between trying to influence the OP and trying to inform the OP

Comment: It should also be kept in mind that the SO engine will itself remind posters if they have a question with answers and haven't accepted one.  So there's no need to comment as a reminder to the OP, that will happen by itself.

Comment: So conclusion: even if it's a new user you can't just flag questions for get the - working - answers accepted. Thanks everybody for this discussion.

Comment: @ChrisF might need a snickers.