# How to deal with popular questions with no accepted answer?

Tags: discussion

I'm looking at this question: [Converting String array to java.util.List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6026813/converting-string-array-to-java-util-list)

There are two answers with 7 upvotes, and one with 79 in between them. However, none of them are accepted. It looks like the user who asked the question is inactive.

Should something be done to accept an answer?

Comment: Side-stepping the issue, the OP was last seen 11 hours ago. And didn't respond to a comment posted more than a year ago about the accept. Maybe the OP doesn't want to accept an answer.

Comment: this comes up more often than you think. We had this question once... just not much to do here

Comment: There are lots of dupes for "let the community decide on the accepted answer" and for "force the OP to select an answer". It always boils down to: "the accept-mark is for the OP, and only him, to decide about. And it only means the OP liked that one best for whatever arcane reasons."

Comment: related (maybe a dup) https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266661/is-it-ok-to-flag-a-question-because-there-are-no-accepted-answers , related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251288/dealing-with-an-answer-that-wasnt-accepted-maybe-because-a-user-is-a-newbie-in

Answer (score 8):

No.  Accepted answer doesn't mean anything, other than the OP thought at one point it might be right.  It doesn't mean its a good answer, the best answer, or that it even works.  There's been plenty of times an accepted answer was dead wrong, or that it was a bad idea even if it did "work".  There's plenty of times an accepted answer became obsolete, or a better one came later.  Acceptance doesn't really mean anything.  If you have a better answer than the posted ones add your own.  Otherwise move to the next question.

Answer (score -2):

Echoing Mysticial, it may very well be that OP doesn't really *know* which answer is best.

Well, that is OK I think. Maybe OP will learn it later.

Maybe OP happens to know one answerer, and doesn't want to bias his judgement(ie if my friend is among the people answering , I do not feel comfortable to select best answer).

Maybe OP has *such* high standards! Nobody met the standards!

Who knows ! Mysteries are part of life :-)