# Notification of flag results

Tags: discussion, support, flags

I just flagged a post for some edits that I couldn't do myself and I can't manage to find its status. So I don't really know if a moderator has handled it yet (or if they won't).

Do we get notified when a mod handles the flagged post?

Comment: It's rare to find you dont seem to have done any research on it :P

Comment: @mehow didn't find anything, and still don't understand how it works

Comment: What's wrong about downvotes ?

Comment: @Pierre It might have been a bit unclear: I've fixed it up for you, but feel free to rollback my edits if they changed the meaning of your question.

Comment: @AstroCB thanks for the edit, as English is not my mother tongue my question was surely unclear.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can look back through your flag history, which you can get to from your profile (note the number is a hyperlink):

[image: Image highlighting the link to your flagging history from your profile]

That page lists all of your past flags and shows each one as either "helpful", "active", "declined" or "disputed". Each entry links back to the post or comment that you flagged, so you can [try to] get back to it (note that you'll need 10k reputation to view a deleted post) and see if any action has been taken. If the flag's still active then nobody has looked at it yet.

To answer the question

> Do we get notified when a mod handles the flagged post?

No, the only way to know is by checking your flagging history - and that will only tell you *if* it was handled, not what action was taken or who handled it.

If you don't yet have any flags marked helpful, you can still access the flag summary via `https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/<your user id>`, so you should be able to see your flag history [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/3845124).

Comment: I just have profile views under stats, nothing about flags helpful or not. I guess it was not helpful, and we don't have access to not helpful flags.

Comment: @Pierre There's a link you can go to. `http://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/userid` where userid is your own userid. Once you have 1 or more flags marked helpful, you'll get the helpful flags link JonK has in his image.

Comment: @Kendra ok thanks, I see JonK edited, that's clear now. We get downvoted quite easily down here in meta.

Comment: @Pierre Voting on the meta sites is different to the main site. See [this post for more information](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254108/downvotes-on-meta-are-confusing-do-they-really-mean-poor-post-quality-or-jus?lq=1). You also don't lose or gain reputation on per-site metas.

Comment: mm I see, curious way to behave: "I don't agree with you but you won't know why". Anyway thanks to you and @Kendra for taking the time.

Comment: @Pierre Not a problem. I had to find that link myself at one point. Difference was, I had helpful flags on another site, so I could figure the link out myself. :)

Comment: +1 for Freehand Red Circles! They don't have drop shadows, though.

Comment: Now, I don't find an entry in page, have to type the url .