# A better way to deal with bad questions and bad answers

Tags: discussion, downvotes

I understand any user should actually read through the guidelines to post a question and answer a question before doing it for the first time, however just for the sake of argument (sometimes really happen), there are many, for various reasons, don't understand everything for the very first time, otherwise if everyone is so good understanding something why should even Stack Overflow exist?

Therefore, why not allow a **minimum number of times before a user's question or answer can be down voted** so that the new users don't get a bad feeling about Stack Overflow and start using it more often and better?

I understand that the question is getting downvoted immediately; could someone please explain why? I have a very genuine question; I searched it thoroughly if there was any similar questions, and I put up words in the best possible grammar I know. This will help me understand how this really works, thanks.

Also, I think people already are forgetting and ignoring the point I am making, people who really do not understand English the very first time very clearly, or do not understand what is being written there very precisely for any other reason; they need some way of being notified.

I understand downvoting is one way, but there is a negative psychological aspect attached to it, driving new users away. I also understand more new users is not important to Stack Overflow, only quality users are, but there is still every possibility that a quality one is missed. I am asking: Isn't there any other solution to this problem? Really?

Comment: see [Downvotes on Meta are confusing: do they *really* mean poor-post quality, or just disagreement?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254108/downvotes-on-meta-are-confusing-do-they-really-mean-poor-post-quality-or-jus)

Comment: Your premise is flawed, doing something "so that the new users don't get a bad feeling about SO" should never be our goal. We should only care about users who are willing _and_ able to provide good questions and answers. SO does not have a popularity problem, there is no need to care about driving new users away until it's proven these users would be a very valuable addition to SO; and experience says this is not the case. Thus we don't even _want_ these people to use SO "more often", and that they use it "better" when their first question are not downvoted is a completely baseless assumption.

Comment: @gnat , thanks for the comments, but I have a very specific case and idea here, they dont have my exact case, nobody talks about minimum number of questions to new users before their question being downvoted

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/194495/165773

Comment: @SrivathsaHarishVenkataramana Your proposal may differ from earlier proposals but *the response to your proposal is essentially the same* as the dozens of other proposals that have been submitted to Meta before. Examine the earlier proposals (and gnat's link is just one among *very many such proposals*), examine the problems that they cause and explain in your proposal how your idea avoids these problems. Good luck!

Comment: @Louis : Thanks, How will I know what the response would be even before I post a question? Why would I even post if I knew what the response would be?

Comment: @SrivathsaHarishVenkataramana Here are a couple of ways to know ahead of time: 1. Read Meta posts for a while. Suggestions like yours come every week and get the same reception: downvoted and closed as duplicate. 2. Use the search box at the top right of the page. But the issue I was addressing (perhaps not clearly enough) is whether or not the differences between your proposals and the earlier one somehow preclude closing yours as duplicate. They don't.

Comment: @Louis The search box returned me more than 100 pages, so you're advising me to go through each and every question one by one, before posting mine? Is it really what people do on SO? I thought people go through the first few, say 2 or 3 and then use the auto suggestions provided by SO, the duplicate question as pointed out by gnat did not appear in any of these

Comment: @SrivathsaHarishVenkataramana If I search for questions having at least one answer and the tag [tag:down-vote], I get 161 questions, much less than 100 *pages*. And this could be refined further with the phrase "new user". Anyway, at some point you'll start to see some themes repeating themselves in the proposals and in the problems that community raises in the answers. So you don't need to read *all* of them.

Comment: @Louis I understand that you can filter to narrow down, but it is wrong to assume all situations are going to drastically bring down the number

Comment: Adding something like this would divide every site that had it.  Think about it; if a new user's first few questions are immune to downvotes, then we have two sections: Real SO, and new user SO.  New users are all happy and fluffy and feel good, and then they flip over into real SO, where their previous levels of effort are no longer good enough.  It sends the wrong message.

Comment: The secret to success on Meta is understanding the fundamentals of the site. Like the use of voting. Proposals to change that way it works are guaranteed not to go over big, especially when your justification is "new users might not like downvotes". Related: [How to participate on Meta and not die trying?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44188/how-do-i-participate-in-meta-and-not-die-trying)

Answer (score 13):

I strongly disagree. Downvoting is an important quality control mechanism, it's a very visible indicator of the community's assessment of the value of that question or answer. Preventing that assessment from taking place ultimately does more harm than good - after all, if you ask a terrible question and don't get downvoted for it, where is the incentive to improve how you ask?

Comment: I understand that, could you please give me reasons why was this question got downvoted, I have a very genuine doubt, I searched it thoroughly if there was any similar questions, I put up words in the best possible grammar I know. This will help me understand how this really works, thanks

Comment: @SrivathsaHarishVenkataramana [Voting is different on meta](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta)

Comment: @SrivathsaHarishVenkataramana As a quick summary of the link that Yannis provided - on Meta, a downvote on a question tagged as a Feature Request or a Discussion simply indicates that people don't agree with it. Here you can interpret them as "I don't agree with this feature request".

Comment: And how does dowb voting improve a users' subsequent questions?, I think it will only improve if it is combined with some quality comments why it is being down voted

Comment: Either they'll take the downvotes as an indication they should actually read the help material they were presented before being allowed to ask their first question, or they'll keep asking poorly researched questions that get downvoted and get question banned, or they'll get a bad feeling and leave. In the first case, everyone wins because SO gets good questions and the OP gets answers, and in the other 2 cases SO wins because a person who doesn't care about quality is gone.

Comment: @Wooble Please allow my to clarify, I am not talking about the users who don't care about quality, I am talking about who don't understand what quality is, or not able to express the required quality because they did not understand the ground rules and a simple down vote button you are going to click is not going to do anything good for the poor user

Comment: The downvote isn't about the user, it's about the post. And it will do something for the user, as a member of the collective group of people using the site, by making a tiny dent in the amount of crap that shows up on the front page, driving away answerers who are fed up.